# É sensato implementar funções que apenas chamem outras funções?

Tags: python

Eu aprendi que funções devem ser pequenas e concisas. Essa regra também se aplicaria a funções como esta?

```
def run_game(self):
    process_input()
    update_state()
    render()
```

O que eu quero dizer é: `run_game` aparenta estar tentando fazer mais de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo, porém me parece que ela está sendo usada como uma unidade de organização, executando as funções que comporiam o processo rotulado `run_game`.

Isso invalida o princípio de *"do one thing well"*? É normal usar funções como unidades de organização e reunir funções relacionadas em uma função principal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, essa forma de organização é normal. Sua função `run_game` não está tentando "fazer mais de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo", ela simplesmente está operando num **nível de abstração mais alto**.

Por exemplo, uma função que lê um arquivo e guarda seu conteúdo numa estrutura de dados faria algo como:

```
def foo(arquivo):
    with open(arquivo, 'r') as f:
        conjunto = set([x.strp() for x in f.readlines() if x.strip()])
    return conjunto
```

Essa função está fazendo uso da biblioteca de manipulação de arquivos e da de criação de conjuntos. Cada uma delas "faz apenas uma coisa e faz bem", mas é preciso **combinar** a funcionalidade delas para se implementar algo mais complexo (obter o conjunto de linhas não vazias do arquivo).

Se uma outra função `bar` precisa de um conjunto de linhas armazenada num arquivo, ela vai **fazer uso** da função `foo` como se a mesma fosse um comando simples como `x + y`: já que no nível de abstração de `bar` coisas como "obter um conjunto de um arquivo" são uma operação simples - não um conjunto de operações. Da mesma forma que, no nível de abstração de `foo`, coisas como "ler todas as linhas de um arquivo" são uma operação só, ainda que na realidade isso envolva uma série de operações de mais baixo nível.