# Diferenças entre forma declarativa e imperativa do LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

- O que uma forma pode fazer que a outra não pode?
- Existe diferença de performance?
- Há vantagem de uma sobre o outra?

*Exemplo:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public int? Cpf { get; set; }

    public Pessoa(string nome, DateTime? dataNascimento = null, int? cpf = null){
        Nome = nome;
        DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
        Cpf = cpf;
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var pessoas = new List<Pessoa>() { 
                new Pessoa("João"), 
                new Pessoa("Maria"),
                new Pessoa("Jorge"),
                new Pessoa("Tiago") };

        // Seleciona pessoas que cujo o nome possue a letra 'a'
        // LINQ na forma declarativa
        var resultado1 = from pessoa in pessoas
               where pessoa.Nome.Contains('a')
               select pessoa;
        // LINQ usando sintaxe tradicional
        var resultado2 = pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains('a'));

        Console.WriteLine(resultado1.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(resultado2.Count());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Performance

Vou colocar uma outra forma do programa que mede a performance:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public int? Cpf { get; set; }

    public Pessoa(string nome, DateTime? dataNascimento = null, int? cpf = null){
        Nome = nome;
        DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
        Cpf = cpf;
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var limiteDeItens = 1_000_000;
        var pessoas = new List<Pessoa>(limiteDeItens);
        var tempo = new Stopwatch();
        tempo.Start();
        //preenche a lista
        for(var i = 0; i < limiteDeItens; i++) {
            pessoas.Add(new Pessoa("Pessoa" + i.ToString()));
        }
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine($"Preencher a lista em ms: {tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        // LINQ na forma declarativa
        tempo.Restart();
        var resultado1 = from pessoa in pessoas
               where pessoa.Nome.Contains('9')
               select pessoa;
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine($"Montar o LINQ declarativo em Ticks: {tempo.ElapsedTicks}");
        // LINQ usando sintaxe tradicional
        tempo.Restart();
        var resultado2 = pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains('9'));
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine($"Montar o LINQ imperativo em Ticks: {tempo.ElapsedTicks}");

        // transferir todo resultado para uma lista apenas para efeito de comparação
        var lista1 = new List<Pessoa>(limiteDeItens);
        tempo.Restart();
        foreach(var pessoa in resultado1) {
            lista1.Add(pessoa);
        }
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine($"Transferir uma lista para outra com a primeira expressão em ms: {tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        var lista2 = new List<Pessoa>(limiteDeItens);
        tempo.Restart();
        foreach(var pessoa in resultado2) {
            lista2.Add(pessoa);
        }
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine($"Transferir uma lista para outra com a segunda expressão em ms: {tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RGUyuQ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W4ebm5) (na verdade com tantos itens estoura o limite de tempo/memória). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/BenchmarkImperativeXDeclarative.cs).

Execute o programa pelo menos 2 ou 3 vezes para fazer um aquecimento. Veja os resultados por conta própria na sua máquina.

#### Medindo a criação da expressão

Note que `resultado1` e `resultado2`, a grosso modo, guardam apenas a expressão do LINQ e não uma lista com os resultados, como muitas pessoas podem imaginar. Por isso o tempo medido é o gasto para montar a expressão. É algo tão rápido que é melhor medir em *ticks* do sistema operacional.

Uma expressão declarativa do LINQ custa bem mais (chega ser ordens de magnitude) que a forma mais próxima do imperativo. Mas quem se importa?! Vai ser executado apenas uma vez. É tão complicado medir isso que mesmo medindo em *ticks* os resultados mudam bastante em cada execução.

#### Executando as expressões

Depois existe a execução das duas expressões que devem produzir o mesmo resultado. Ainda que execute 1 milhão de adições na lista a diferença é pequena.

Fiz um código que demonstra milhões de transferências do resultado. Pode não ser a forma mais eficiente mas é a que demonstra com clareza a transferência ocorrendo. Você sempre terá a execução de outras operações interferindo no resultado. Este exemplo não está medindo de forma pura a execução das expressões LINQ.

#### Melhorando a medição

Talvez até existam algumas falhas nesta medição. Certamente existem maneiras de analisar variações possíveis, por exemplo, se o filtro encontra muitos ou poucos elementos que satisfaça as condições, mas dá uma ideia geral da diferença.

Você também poderia fazer uma comparação filtrando os elementos verificando um por um através de um `for` para ver a diferença. Muito provavelmente o uso do `for` seria mais rápido. Mas é uma diferença que justifique seu uso? Pode ser que sim. Pode ser que outras nuances existam.

Também deve-se perguntar o quanto precisa de abstração. Em [outra pergunta que respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14275/101) já disse que em muitos casos programadores não compreendem essas abstrações criadas, eles não entendem bem o LINQ. Então tem que analisar quem vai mexer neste código antes de pensar na performance. Performance só deve ser uma preocupação depois que você mediu e viu que não atende uma necessidade.

A conclusão é que a **performance não importa tanto** a não ser que você tenha uma quantidade absurda de operações a serem feitas. E mesmo que tenha uma quantidade tão absurda, será que o problema não é no algoritmo escolhido que exige tantas operações?

## Como o LINQ funciona

Algumas pessoas vão olhar isso e não vão entender porque nas linhas onde se monta as expressões a execução é tão rápida. Como pode 1 milhão de elementos serem analisados em alguns *ticks*?

Simples, eles não são analisados. A **execução** efetiva da *query* só ocorrerá quando ela for necessária. Toda ela, não importa o quão complexa seja, será executada elemento por elemento sob demanda. Ou seja, só quando você precisa efetivamente do resultado é que a *query* será executada. E não será executada **até** que seja relevante.

Existem *queries* que não precisam analisar todos os elementos. Existem utilizações destas *queries* que apenas uma avaliação parcial é necessária. O sistema funciona muito bem. Tem algoritmos eficientes, que é o mais importante.

*Lazy evaluation* faz com que uma execução só ocorra quando ela é invocada. Então se você pedir apenas **um** elemento que tenha a letra "a", e o primeiro elemento tem a letra "a", ele não precisará analisar 1 milhão de elementos. Claro, isso ocorrerá se usar o método correto. Em um `Where` a verificação ocorrerá em todos os elementos. Você tem que usar a "pergunta" correta para obter a resposta correta. Se deseja só o primeiro, provavelmente vai usar o método `Fisrt` ou `FirstOrDefault`.

Os métodos usados em LINQ usam *continuations* que manipulam as coleções. Através do comando [`yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/101) cada elemento vai sendo analisado em cada iteração.

Veja como é uma implementação simplificada do `Where`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (T element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

## Existe diferença entre as duas formas?

Visualmente é claro que existe. A forma declarativa foi feita para dar uma fluidez na linguagem. Esta forma costuma ser chamada de ***query syntax*** e a outra forma costuma ser chamada de ***method syntax***.

Declarativo ou *query syntax*

```
var resultado1 = from pessoa in pessoas
               where pessoa.Nome.Contains('a')
               select pessoa;
```

Imperativo ou *method syntax*

```
var resultado2 = pessoas.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains('a'));
```

Note que a primeira forma **poderia** ser escrita da seguinte maneira:

```
var resultado1 = from pessoa in pessoas
               .Where(x => x.Nome.Contains('a')
               .Select(x => x);
```

Analisando ambas, elas executam a mesma coisa. No segundo caso tem um `select` implícito. Vamos ver por partes.

#### Entendendo uma expressão

O `from` é fundamental para estabelecer que você está criando uma expressão declarativa do LINQ e nele sempre será declarado o elemento a ser analisado na *query* que virá em seguida.

O que vem logo após o `in` é a coleção que a *query* será aplicada. Na segunda forma você usa a coleção para indicar onde a operação será realizada. O elemento é passado implicitamente para os métodos que virão a seguir.

A cláusula `where` na prática não existe na linguagem. Isso é um *syntax sugar* para o método `Where`. Sendo que este método é um "método de extensão" para qualquer tipo que implemente uma *interface* `IEnumerable`. Internamente o método sabe que ele deve pegar um elemento da coleção em questão e mandar para uma *lambda* que o método recebe como parâmetro (veja a implementação exemplo acima).

O mesmo vale para o `select`. Note que tanto o `where` quanto o `select` são executados em sequência elemento por elemento, conforme a necessidade de um elemento. O *loop* não é executado todo no `where` e depois outro *loop* é executado no `select`. No LINQ é como você tivesse um único *loop* executando todas as operações declaradas nele em sequência em cada elemento individualmente. Você pode entender que o `from` e `in` definem o *loop* e todo o resto da declaração são o corpo deste *loop*.

## Lambda

Perceba que o que vai como parâmetro da cláusula/método em qualquer das formas é uma *lambda*. Mesmo que na primeira forma não pareça ser assim. Nesta forma o recebimento do parâmetro está implícito e o nome que o elemento terá dentro da *lambda* é o mesmo do `from`. Visto desta forma fica mais fácil entender a semelhança:

```
var resultado1 = from pessoa in pessoas
               .Where(pessoa => pessoa.Nome.Contains('a'))
               .Select(pessoa => pessoa);
```

Neste caso `pessoa` é um parâmetro, uma variável interna/local do método *lambda*. Em LINQ declarativo ou *query syntax* existe muita *syntax sugar* ([açúcar sintático](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)), ou seja, tem muita manipulação do código encontrado pelo compilador que toma outra forma que se integre com a forma concreta que a linguagem irá manipular isso.

Se você considerar que uma *lambda* também é *syntax sugar*, você já deve imaginar que no fundo está passando um [`delegate`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) que será executado dentro do método em questão.

*Lambdas* costumam ser simples mas nada impede que exista um algoritmo complexo a ser executado em cada iteração do elemento da coleção.

#### O que é *lambda*

Se alguém ainda não foi apresentado para uma *lambda*, veja os exemplos:

```
pessoa => pessoa.Nome.Contains('a')) //lambda que recebe um parâmetro chamado pessoa (o tipo é inferido)
() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World") //lambda sem parâmetro
(int x, int y) => x * y //recebendo dois parâmetros de tipos específicos e fazendo uma operação
delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); } //usando a sintaxe de delegate
```

No *link* acima tem mais informações.

## Legibilidade

Existe (?!?!) uma clara vantagem de legibilidade na sintaxe em forma de consulta. E os testes acima mostram uma piora da performance. Algumas tarefas são mais fáceis ou em alguns casos é mais fácil identificar quando há efeito colateral (algum estado é modificado no processo) desta forma.

Claro que em alguns casos simples essa legibilidade não é tão grande assim. Até pelo tamanho a segunda forma (*method syntax*) parece mais legível. Há quem questione isso, mas parece mais limpo, já que é mais curto. De novo, vai de quem está lendo.

## Outras diferenças

Nem todos os métodos que podem ser usados na forma imperativa podem ser usados na forma declarativa. Exemplo: [`ToLookup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#overloads). Então há limitação maior na forma declarativa.

Uma *lambda expression* pode ser criada de forma dinâmica na aplicação. Você pode inclusive montar uma árvore de expressão na mão via código.

Existem mais algumas flexibilidades em uma expressão *lambda* que ajudam em diversas situações mais complexas que uma expressão declarativa teria dificuldade.

Particularmente vejo a forma declarativa como algo mais "bonito", e isso é bom. Não há dúvida disso. Mas fora este ponto, a forma mais imperativa tem mais vantagens. Quando você precisa dessas vantagens, paradoxalmente sua vida fica mais fácil, não há escolha.

## Conclusão

Não importa a forma, LINQ são códigos representando dados.

Na forma original da pergunta o AP fazia alguma confusão com LINQ e *lambda* e muitos não conhecem os termos *query expression* e *lambda expression*. Quando entendi que era isso que ele queria, resolvi salvar a pergunta.

Entenda que LINQ engloba as duas formas de expressão e ambas se utilizam de *lambda* apesar de apenas uma levar isto no nome, afinal as *query expressions* usam *lambdas* apenas de forma disfarçada.

[Coloquei todos exemplos no **GitHub**](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Examples.cs).

Comment: Boa, explicação...

Comment: No seu código os benchmarks de "Transferir uma lista para outra" fazem a mesma coisa. Isso era esperado ou você tava querendo que no segundo loop a lista usada fosse o `resultado2`?

Comment: @Francisco você tem razão, foi um lapso, obrigado.