# Como fazer "OR" entre SubQuerys utilizando LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, expressões-lambda

Gostaria de implementar com **LINQ** C# (Utilizando [**NHibernate**](http://nhforge.org/) como **[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)**), a seguinte *query*:

```cs
return (from t1 in Session.Query<Tabela1>()
        join t2 in Session.Query<Tabela2>()
        on t1 equals t2.T1
        where (from t3 in Session.Query<Tabela3>()
               where
               t3.Tabela == 1 && t3.Atualizacao >= dataAtualizacao
               select t3.Chave).Contains(t1.Id)
        /* aqui teria que ser um 'or' (||) ao invés de um 'and' (&&), como é feito por default */
        where (from t3 in Session.Query<Tabela3>()
               where
               t3.Tabela == 2 && t3.Atualizacao >= dataAtualizacao
               select t3.Chave).Contains(t2.Id)
        select t1).Distinct().ToList();
```

A *query* equivalente em **SQL** que quero gerar seria similar a está:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABELA1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABELA2 AS T2 ON T2.T1 = T1.ID
WHERE 
(T1.ID IN (SELECT T3.CHAVE FROM TABELA3 
WHERE T3.CODIGOTABELA = 1 AND T3.ATUALIZACAO >= '10/25/2000 13:05:00')
OR /* Esse OR é que não consigo implementar com LINQ, da maneira que está a expressão LINQ nessa linha gera um AND */
T2.ID IN (SELECT T3.CHAVE FROM TABELA3 
WHERE T3.CODIGOTABELA = 2 AND T3.ATUALIZACAO >= '10/25/2000 13:05:00'))
```

O problema é que não achei nenhuma forma de fazer a expressão **"OR"** entre as 2 `subquerys`, e por default em LINQ a expressão gerada é um **"AND"**.
Há alguma forma de fazer a expressão **"OR"**, entre as duas *subquerys*?

> Obs: Poderia também utilizar [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397687.aspx), ao invés de LINQ.

Comment: Lambda Expression é uma forma usar o LINQ. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14212/diferencas-entre-forma-declarativa-e-imperativa-do-linq/15142#15142

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um encadeamento de `where`s é um **AND**. Se queres um **OR**, coloca um **OR**:

```
return (from t1 in Session.Query<Tabela1>()
        join t2 in Session.Query<Tabela2>()
        on t1 equals t2.T1
        where (from t3 in Session.Query<Tabela3>()
               where
               t3.Tabela == 1 && t3.Atualizacao >= dataAtualizacao
               select t3.Chave).Contains(t1.Id)
        || (from t3 in Session.Query<Tabela3>()
               where
               t3.Tabela == 2 && t3.Atualizacao >= dataAtualizacao
               select t3.Chave).Contains(t2.Id)
        select t1).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Perfeito, como não pensei nessa maneira, tinha tentado `|| where`, `where ||`, só não pensei sem o `where`, sabia que deveria haver uma maneira simples (mas não tanto). Muito obrigado.