# Qual a diferença entre "lambda" e LINQ? Como diferenciá-los em uma sentença?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda, terminologia

Frequentemente vejo termos como consulta LINQ e expressões *lambda*.

Então surgiu a questão, O que estou fazendo é uma consulta LINQ, uma expressão *lambda* ou ambos?

#### Ex1:

```
var query = Produtos.Where(p => p.Descr.StartsWith("A")).Take(10);
```

#### Ex2:

```
var query = from produto in Produtos.Take(10)
where produto.Descr.StartsWith("A")
select new Produto 
{ Id = produto.Id, Descr = produto.Descr};
```

Comment: Apenas uma curiosidade uma expressão Linq usando query syntax é convertida pelo compilador para uma Method syntax, desta forma uma Query Syntax sempre tem uma forma equivalente em Method Syntax, porém o inverso não ocorre, também existem diferenças entre Query Syntax do C# e VB.NET, este segundo tem uma implantação mais ampla, como por exemplo permitindo skip, take, while, etc... Enquanto no C# é possível apenas com Method Syntax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

LINQ é uma coisa só e possui duas sintaxes diferentes:

- uma é a sintaxe de consulta ou forma **declarativa** e que muitas pessoas acham que apenas isto é LINQ (seu segundo exemplo)
- outra é a sintaxe de método ou forma **imperativa** que muitas pessoas acham que é uma *lambda* (seu primeiro exemplo)

Já fica claro que as duas formas são LINQ, uma em linguagem mais natural e outra mais parecido com o que programamos normalmente. A segunda forma costuma usar *lambdas*, para representar os códigos necessários para execução da expressão. Embora dê para entender, não podemos chamar isto simplesmente de *lambda* já que isto é apenas um mecanismo usado para formar toda a expressão do LINQ. Vale lembrar que a forma mais declarativa também usa *lambda*, mas de um jeito mais disfarçado sendo o código passado por cláusula ao invés de argumento de método como na forma imperativa.

A diferenciação ocorre pela forma como é escrita. A forma declarativa se parece com a linguagem de programação, é um leitura mais natural. Na forma imperativa são usados os métodos brutos cheio de pontos, parênteses e notação de recebimento de parâmetros da *lambda*.

Para saber mais, entender as vantagens de cada forma, [já respondi sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

- [Documentação sobre *lambda expressions*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Documentação sobre LINQ em geral](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Comparação entre as duas formas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

LINQ usa *lambdas*, mas *lambdas* podem ser usados sem LINQ também. Exemplo:

```cs
//declara uma função que retorna um bool, para ver se um int tem todos os mesmos números
public static bool TodosIguais( this int num, Func<T,bool> igual ) {
  return igual(num);
}

//usa essa função, mas posso mandar qualquer função que retorna um bool
int numero = 55;

//Usando um lambda mais complexo:
bool todosIguais = numero.TodosIguais( i => {
    char comparar = num.ToString()[0];
    foreach( var n in num.ToString() ) {
      if ( comparar != n ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
  } );

//Usando um lambda um pouco mais simples
todosIguais = numero.TodosIguais( 
  i => i.ToString().All(c=>c.Equals(i.ToString().First())) );

//Usando um lambda super simples, mas que possa retornar algo errado
todosIguais = numero.TodosIguais( i => i == i );
```

Em outras palavras, a *lambda* é uma mandeira succinta de declarar uma função, sendo os parámetros da função antes do `=>`, e o conteúdo da função depois.

Comment: Se pudesse colocar um exemplo com utilização prática ficaria melhor.