# Filtrar por grupo e valor mínimo

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
*********************************
* IdPessoa *  DataVen  * Observ *
* 10000000 *  01/01/15 * Teste1 *
* 10000001 *  01/01/15 * Teste2 *
* 10000000 *  01/01/12 * Teste3 *
* 10000001 *  01/01/13 * Teste4 *
* 10000001 *  01/01/11 * Teste5 *
* 10000000 *  01/01/14 * Teste6 *
* 10000001 *  01/01/14 * Teste7 *
*********************************
```

Gostaria de retornar os registros `IdPessoas` com seus menores valores de `DataVen`. Exemplo:

```
* 10000000 *  01/01/12 * Teste3 *
* 10000001 *  01/01/11 * Teste5 *
```

Gostaria de fazer isto utilizando Linq. Estou usando Entity Framework.

Comment: você quer agrupar pelos menores valores do DataVen ? ou ordenar pelo menor valor ?

Comment: É , está confuso, do jeito que está fica difícil responder, tente deixar mais claro o que deseja, se possível mostrar melhores exemplos ou o que fez. Aproveite aprenda o usar os termos corretos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79894/101

Comment: Agrupar por IdPessoa e DataVen.

Comment: Quantos "menores valores" você quer retornar? Você está usando Entity Framework?

Comment: Posso ter n IdPessoas e n DataVen para esses ids. Gostaria de filtrar somente os menores valores de DataVen por IdPessoa.

Estou usando Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, não sei o nome da entidade. Vou supor que é `Registro`, então o `DbSet` se chama `Registros` por convenção.

Isto pega a data de vencimento mais antiga de cada pessoa:

```
var registros = contexto.Registros
                .OrderBy(r => r.IdPessoa)
                .ThenBy(r => r.DataVen)
                .GroupBy(r => r.IdPessoa)
                .SelectMany(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```