# Fazer um "join" deixa a busca mais rápida?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda, linq-to-entities

Tenho duas tabelas, uma de pacientes e outra de consultas. Resumindo, as tabelas tem a seguinte estrutura:

#### Pacientes

```
int id;
string nome;
string cartaoSus;
```

#### Consultas

```
int id;
int idPaciente;
dateTime data;
```

Quando quero um relatório dos pacientes com consultas agendadas, eu faço assim:

```
//Crio uma classe que engloba as duas tabelas:
private class consultaCompleta
{
    int idConsulta;
    int idPaciente;
    dateTime data;
    string nome;
    string cartaoSus;
}

//Crio as listas referentes à cada uma das tabelas:
private void montaConsulta(int idConsulta)
{
    List<pacientes> listaPaciente = model.pacientes.ToList(); //pego tudo da tabela
    List<consultas> listaConsulta = model.consultas.ToList(); //pego tudo da tabela
    List<consultaCompleta> listaConsultaCompleta = (from c in listaConsulta
                                                    join p in listaPaciente on c.idPaciente equals p.id
                                                    select new consultaCompleta()
                                                    {
                                                        idConsulta = c.id,
                                                        idPaciente = p.id,
                                                        data = c.data,
                                                        nome = p.nome,
                                                        cartaoSus = p.cartaoSus
                                                    })
                                                    .Where(p => p.id.Equals(idConsulta)) 
                                                    .ToList();
}
```

A questão maior é essa: Sempre eu pego todos os dados das tabelas e faço o `join` depois. Existe uma outra forma de fazer isso, pegando primeiro da tabela (como me respondeu o Maniero)? Como fazer então?

Desculpem eu ter praticamente refeito toda a pergunta, mas preciso saber bem sobre essa questão de lentidão nas consultas, pois meu banco ficará bem grande no futuro

Comment: Essas listas são de dados já em memória, ou são preenchidas a partir de base de dados?

Comment: O que está utilizando para retornar os dados de model.pacientes e do model.consultas?

Comment: São informações pegos no banco de dados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente ficará mais rápido, o banco de dados poderá otimizar, e trazer menos informações. Só testando para saber. Mas é preciso fazer testes corretos. Mas sempre que pegar várias informações e tentar filtrar no lado do cliente tende ser mais lento.

Acredito que trará resultados mais consistentes. Entre pegar a informação de uma tabela e depois pegar de outra algo pode mudar e ficar inconsistente. Pegar tudo de uma vez na mesma consulta garante a consistência. Só não garanto porque não sei se é gerado tudo na mesma transação, e como está a configuração do banco de dados.

Só daria para dizer como fazer se tivesse informações na pergunta sobre o modelo, como está usando.

Para concluir até entendo o que quer dizer, mas provavelmente [o termo *lambda* está sendo usado erroneamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79894/101). Veja [o que é uma *lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Comment: Refiz minha pergunta, se puder, me dê uma nova explicação. Abraço.

Comment: Agora virou outra pergunta, você já tá aqui faz tempo pra saber que isso não é adequado, depois eu dou uma olhada, mas não sei se cabe. De cara já não entendo o uso do `Equals()`.

Comment: Desculpe pelo incoveniente, é que a pergunta anterior ia ficar sem sentido. O comando `p.id.Equals(idConsulta)` quer dizer `where p.id = idConsulta`