# Utilizar Contains em um campo inteiro em C# com lambda ou LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
 query = query.Where(x => x.MeuCampoInteiro.ToString().Contains(filter));
```

Porem esta ocorrendo uma exceção:

```
 System.NotSupportedException: 'The expression [10008].MeuCampoInteiro.ToString() is not supported.'
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer o `ToString()` ou `Contains()` em um campo inteiro na expressão *lambda*?

Comment: Relacionada em inglês: [C# linq expression in lambda with contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919695/c-sharp-linq-expression-in-lambda-with-contains)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimenta:

```
query = query.Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.MeuCampoInteiro).Contains(filter));
```

Se não der, use:

```
query = query.Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x.MeuCampoInteiro).Contains(filter));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/SqlFunctions.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8).

[A pergunta título não faz muito sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79894/101).

Comment: SqlFunctions não aparece para mim. Tenho que importar alguma coisa?

Comment: Sim, editei com a documentação.

Answer (score -2):

query.Where(x => x.campoInteiro.ToString().Contains(campoPesquisa))