# Paradigma Imperativo e Declarativo

Tags: terminologia, programação-funcional, paradigma-de-programação, programação-imperativa

Quais as diferenças dos paradigmas de programação imperativa e declarativa? Vantagens e desvantagens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resumidamente o imperativo diz como fazer e o declarativo diz o que fazer.

## Imperativo

Este paradigma se preocupa com os detalhes do funcionamento do algoritmo e o declarativo apenas com a semântica correta do que se quer alcançar. Fica claro que é muito difícil programar de forma apenas declarativa. O declarativo deverá ter algum suporte de outros [paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), como o imperativo, mesmo que de forma bastante transparente.

Grande parte das linguagens de programação *mainstream* são mais imperativas. Mesmo algumas que tentam se vender como sendo de outros paradigmas, elas apenas possuem certas características destes paradigmas. Praticamente não existe linguagem orientada a objeto de fato, puramente falando, mesmo que o marketing delas digam que sim. Hoje algumas linguagens procuram ter formas mais declarativas em adição à forma imperativa.

Com ele você comunica melhor com o computador, diz extamenet como fazer.

Exemplo de código C#:

```cs
var lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var pares = new List<int>();
foreach (var num in lista) if (num % 2 == 0) pares.Add(num);
```

## Declarativo

Esta forma pode usar uma sintaxe mais fluente. Mas nem sempre. É possível usar uma sintaxe imperativa e programar de forma declarativa. Muitas vezes a programação funcional é considerada uma forma declarativa já que ela se preocupa mais com a execução geral do que os detalhes específicos.

A forma declarativa pode ser mais expressiva em alguns cenários mas é muito difícil expressar detalhes. A não ser que exista uma limitação do que se deve fazer é comum ter formas de escapar da forma declarativa, talvez até estendendo de alguma forma o estilo declarativo de codificar.

Neste paradigma temos melhores abstrações e a linguagem é considerada de mais alto nível.

Eficiência não é algo que se espera neste paradigma. Não que ele não possa executar algo rápido, em alguns casos pode até obter melhores resultados mas em códigos comparáveis, onde se obteve o máximo de otimização possível em cada paradigma, o declarativo será mais lento, mesmo que a diferença não seja importante.

É claro que pode-se obter até mais eficiência nos casos não otimizados. A forma declarativa permite que um bom *backend* otimize o código de uma forma que o programador tem dificuldade, justamente por não dar muitos detalhes, ele pode escolher o melhor caminho. É muito difícil melhorar código imperativo. Existem algumas coisas que podem ser feitas mas não se pode mudar completamente o jeito de fazer sob pena de mudar o resultado. Há detalhes demais.

Para funcionar, estas linguagens normalmente precisam de um *backend* que interpretará ou compilará o código. Provavelmente escrito de forma imperativa.

Muitas vezes as linguagens declarativas não são linguagens de programação. Elas costumam ter limitações para armazenar estados, principalmente intermediários, e em estruturas de controle de fluxo, já que este não é o objetivo deste tipo de linguagem. Sem essas características fica difícil ou impossível reproduzir a [máquina de Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine). É possível ter neste paradigma as características necessárias para classificar a linguagem como de programação.

O SQL é uma linguagem bastante declarativa. Você especifica como quer o resultado, mas exatamente como o banco de dados irá achar o resultado desejado é problema dele. SQL padrão não é uma linguagem de programação. Com algumas extensões pode ser.

O C# adotou o LINQ que é uma forma mais declarativa de programar, tendo inclusive uma [sintaxe mais imperativa e outra mais puramente declarativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

Outros exemplos são as linguagens de declaração de GUI onde você diz como quer que monte os elementos de telas, com alguma forma de XML ou formato semelhante, mas não informa como isto deve ser executado. Outros exemplos são o HTML, CSS, RegEx.

Linguagens de programação podem ser mais declarativas, mas não totalmente.

Com o declarativo você comunica melhor com humanos.

Exemplo de código C#:

```cs
var lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var pares = from num in lista
                where num % 2 == 0
                select num;
pares = pares.ToList();
```

Forma declarativa com sintaxe imperativa:

```cs
var lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var pares = lista.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ImperativeVsDeclarative.cs).

O `ToList()` pode ser omitido em certas circunstâncias, mas para ser igual ao exemplo de cima ele tem que ser colocado.

Comment: mesmo a linguagem de máquina é "compilada" de maneiras diferentes dentro de um chip... isso torna essa classificação de imperativo vs declarativo um tanto variada conforme a perspectiva de quem vê ou do contexto que se aplica. Dizer "a linguagem C é declarativa/imperativa" significa: "a linguagem C é declarativa/imperativa" em relação a que?

Answer (score 8):

### Programação Imperativa

> A Programação Imperativa é um conceito baseado em estados, definidos
> por variáveis, e ações que são manipuladoras de estado, procedimentos.
> Pelo fato de permitir o uso de procedimentos como estruturação, também
> é conhecido como, Programação Procedural.

**Exemplos de linguagens:** Pascal,C,Cobol,Python

**Vantagens**

- Eficiência
- Modelagem natural dos problemas do mundo real
- Dominância de mercado
- Bem estabelecido

**Desvantagens**

- Focaliza o "COMO" e não o "QUE" precisa ser feito
- Difícil legilibilidade

**Explicação:** Em uma linguagem imperativa, o programador diz com detalhes as operações que o programa realiza, incluindo manipulação de memória e interface direta com a entrada/saída do programa.

---

### Programação Declarativa

> A Programação Declarativa, ao contrário da Programação Imperativa que
> informa ao computador "COMO" as instruções devem ser executadas,
> preocupa-se em apenas dizer ao computador "O QUE" precisa ser feito,
> cabendo ao computador decidir qual a melhor solução para essa
> solicitação.As linguagens definidas por este paradigma não podem ser
> consideradas como linguagens de programação, e sim, como
> sub-linguagens.

**Exemplos de linguagens:** SQL, XML

**Vantagens**

- Facilidade de acesso a banco de dados(SQL)
- Conversão de objetos complexos(Pessoa, Empregado) por Binding para trafegar pela rede(XML)

**Desvantagens**

- Ilegilidade do código(Quando usada de forma funcional)

**Explicação:** Quando diz aqui `usada de forma funcional`, está se referindo a linguagens de marcação, como `XML` e `HTML` por exemplo, na qual pode ser difícil entender o seu conteúdo devido às marcações.

---

Fonte: [Programação Imperativa vs Programação Declarativa](http://informacaocomdiversao.blogspot.com.br/2006/01/programao-imperativa-versus-programao.html)

Comment: Oi @Pedro, porquê o "Focaliza o "COMO" e não o "QUE" precisa ser feito" é tido como uma desvantagem para o PI(paradigma imperativo)?

E o que significa usar de forma funcional o P.D?

Comment: desculpe a demora, veja as explicações na resposta se esclarescem sua dúvida