# Quais as vantagens de se trabalhar com Interface Fluente com o LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

Quais as vantagens de se trabalhar com interface fluente com o LINQ?

Tenho esse código:

**Empregados.cs**

```
namespace LinqConsulta
{
    class Empregados : List<Empregado>
    {
      public Empregados Lista()
      {
          this.Add(new Empregado(1, "Maria", "maria@site.com.br", "11 1111 1111")); 
          this.Add(new Empregado(2, "João", "joao@site.com.br", "22 2222 2222"));
          this.Add(new Empregado(3, "José", "jose@site.com.br", "33 3333 3333")); 
          return this;
      }
    }
}
```

**Empregado.cs**

```
namespace LinqConsulta
{
   class Empregado
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Nome { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public string Telefone { get; set; }

      public Empregado() { }

      public Empregado(int id, string nome, string email, string telefone)
      {
         this.Id = id;
         this.Nome = nome;
         this.Email = email;
         this.Telefone = telefone;
      }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace LinqConsulta
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_load(object sender, EventsArgs e) 
      {
         Empregados lista = new Empregados().Lista(); 

         var consulta = from empregado in lista
                    orderby empregado.Nome
                    select empregado;

         dataGridView1.DataSource = consulta.ToList();
      }
   }
}
```

Estou trabalhando com a consulta(`var consulta = from`) no formato de SQL e gostaria de saber como deixar essa consulta mais enxuta, com interface fluente?

Comment: Parece que tem duas perguntas aí, qual das duas realmente quer saber?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "deixar a consulta mais enxulta?"

Comment: Não sei como está o seu método `Lista()`, mas tenho quase certeza que é possível colocar o `.OrderBy()` nele, não necessitando assim da variável consulta (`var consulta = ...`).

Comment: Então, você não precisa da variável consulta, pode colocar o `.OrderBy()` diretamente na lista, ficando assim: `Empregados lista = new Empregados().Lista().OrderBy(n => n.Nome);`.

Comment: Essa forma é apenas para estudo? Pois existem formas melhores para fazer isso.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira Então nem irei colocar uma resposta. Mas meu comentário acima deixará o código em "uma linha", se é isso que quer dizer como limpo.

Answer (score 4):

Essa consulta pode ser escrita de forma mais simples usando a [forma mais imperativa conhecida por *method syntax*, em oposição à *query syntax*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

```
var consulta = lista.OrderBy(e => e.Nome);
```

Veja [funcionando de forma simplificada no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GghkgK). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m64SKq). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Fluent.cs).

Algumas pessoas acham uma mais fácil de ler do que a outra. Isto varia de quem está lendo e do tipo de consulta. A sintaxe de consulta costuma ser mais adequada para expressões mais complexas, com mais de uma fonte de dados ([*from*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) principalmente fazendo algum tipo de união de dados ([*join*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Além disto esta forma permite o uso de variáveis auxiliares ([*let*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Answer (score 3):

Da uma olhada assim.

```
private void Form1_load(object sender, EventsArgs e) 
{
    Empregados lista = new Empregados().Lista(); 

    var consulta = lista.OrderBy(p => p.Nome).ToList();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = consulta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Consulta no formato SQL:**

```
var consulta = from empregado in lista
               orderby empregado.Nome
               select empregado;
```

**Consulta no formato Interface Fluente:**

```
var consulta = lista.OrderBy(n => n.Nome);
```

**Consulta no formato Interface Fluente, com Ordem Inversa:**

```
var consulta = lista.OrderByDescending(n => n.Nome);
```

**Consulta no formato Interface Fluente, com Ordem Inversa e com busca onde Nome contém a letra "J" :**

```
var consulta = lista.OrderByDescending(n => n.Nome);
        .where(n => n.Nome.To.Lower().Contains("j"));
```

Comment: Dica: Where antes de OrderByDescending.