# Qual a diferença entre as duas sintaxes com LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<string> esportes = new List<string> { "Futebol", "Voleibol", "Basquetebol", "Natação", "Rugby", "Handebol" };
List<string> resultado = new List<string>();

resultado = (from esp in esportes where esp.EndsWith(criterio) select esp).ToList();

resultado = esportes.Where(esp => esp.EndsWith(criterio))
                    .Select(esp => esp).ToList();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diferenças entre forma declarativa e imperativa do LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14212/diferen%c3%a7as-entre-forma-declarativa-e-imperativa-do-linq)

Comment: @Renan responde sim, muito obrigado!