# O que define uma boa lógica?

Tags: algoritmo

Estava pensando sobre algumas questões de códigos que alterei e me lembrei do que o meu professor do curso de desenvolvimento `android` falava e fazia: "Uma boa lógica tem poucas linhas de código". Perguntei para algumas pessoas que me disseram que isso depende. Mas depende do que? Claro que quanto menos código, mais rápido o processamento. Alguém pensa o contrario disso e tem um exemplo concreto disto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que o seu professor comentou está certo, de um modo geral.
Um problema que ocorre é alguns entendem de forma errada o trecho "quanto menos código melhor".
Então fazem "códigos espagueti" para justificar menor quantidade de linhas.

Ter uma menor quantidade de códigos não quer dizer melhor performance em determinados casos.

Depende dos recursos da linguagem com a qual está trabalhando e qual o objetivo.

Um exemplo simples com JavaScript:

Com Jquery, podemos selecionar um elemento dessa forma

```
elemento = $('#id_do_elemento');
```

Simples, não ?

Vamos ver como fica sem JQuery

```
elemento = getElementByID('id_do_elemento');
```

Simples, porém, usa maior quantidade de caracteres.
Então isso quer dizer que usando JQuery é mais performático?

Não, pois foi necessário carregar uma library de 400kb para poder ter esse tipo de recurso.

Logicamente, se o uso da library for necessário para tarefas mais complexas ou mesmo um uso relativamente grande mesmo de funções muito pequenas, recomenda-se o uso da library.

Aí que entra a lógica em determinar, ter bom senso de discernir o que pode ser melhor empregado.

Comment: +1 pelo exemplo bem conseguido.

Comment: Muito bom o exemplo, muitas vezes isso aconteceu comigo e passou despercebido. Boa dica!

Answer (score 4):

Vamos assumir que sua lógica ou algoritmo é *quasi*-ótima (i.e. matematicamente falando, não existe um procedimento ou prova diferente que chegue ao mesmo resultado com um número substancialmente menor de passos). Ou seja, sua lógica **conceitual** está bem definida. Resta então realizar essa lógica através de código - um problema de engenharia, vamos dizer - o que demanda um tipo diferente de estratégia. É nesse contexto, acredito, que se enquadra a afirmação do seu professor.

Um código não existe no vácuo. Ele está inserido em um ambiente que possui suas próprias rotinas, bibliotecas *built-in* ou externas, além de código que você mesmo escreveu. Tudo isso são **recursos** que você pode ou não utilizar a seu favor ao planejar uma solução.

#### Reutilização de Código

Em geral, se você pode reutilizar um código já pronto sua solução será mais simples/concisa. Nem sempre isso é verdade (ex.: se o código pronto exige uma infinidade de parâmetros e configuração, e você só pretende usar um subconjunto ínfimo de sua funcionalidade), mas via de regra será. E embora a solução completa tenha mais código, há uma **separação de responsabilidades** entre sua lógica e cada uma de suas **dependências**.

Portanto, para se conseguir uma lógica simples, o primeiro passo é conhecer bem seu ambiente, saber quais recursos estão à disposição e se eles se aplicam ou não ou seu caso.

#### Performance

Contrário ao senso comum, menos código não significa necessariamente melhor performance. Mesmo quando bibliotecas externas não estão envolvidas. Um exemplo clássico são os algoritmos de ordenação, em que os mais simples normalmente são os menos eficientes. Para se atingir a melhor performance muitas vezes é preciso complicar, explorar peculiaridades do seu domínio, e abandonar a "pureza" do seu modelo conceitual em prol da solução mais adequada ao contexto.

A pergunta é: isso é mesmo necessário? Na grande maioria dos casos, a resposta é **não** - você não precisa que a performance do seu programa seja a melhor possível. Citando o [exemplo do Daniel Omine](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23039/215), ok, carregar uma biblioteca de 400kB para salvar uns poucos caracteres *parece* uma má ideia, mas será que é? Em primeiro lugar, o código jQuery é mais limpo, mais fácil de escrever, e com menos problema de incompatibilidade entre browsers. Em segundo lugar, o código JavaScript costuma ser pequeno, e ser ativado em resposta a uma ação do usuário, de modo que a performance não é crítica. Em terceiro, com *caching* você pode carregar essa biblioteca uma vez e usar em diversos pontos diferentes do seu sistema.

Ou seja, se* sacrificando um pouco a performance pode-se ter um código mais simples e conciso, é bom considerar essa possibilidade.

* *se e somente se* - quando seu código for servir de base para diversos outros sistemas (ex.: você está desenvolvendo uma biblioteca que poderá ser usada em cálculos pesados), vale a pena sacrificar a simplicidade em nome da performance.

#### Nível de Abstração

Por fim, para se ter um código conciso é necessário se programar no nível de abstração certo. Se você precisa ler uma estrutura de dados de um arquivo, fazer alguma coisa com ela, e salvar os resultados em outro arquivo, não é bom misturar no mesmo código responsabilidades diferentes (ex.: abrir o arquivo e ler seus bytes; interpretar esses bytes como tipos de dados da linguagem; colocar esses dados na estrutura que você vai usar; usar a estrutura).

Muitas vezes isso significa reutilizar código pronto, como abordado anteriormente. Em outras, é questão de quebrar seu problema em problemas menores (i.e. "dividir para conquistar", como [mencionado por Zanoldor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23030/215)), resolver cada um deles e então compor a solução final **fazendo uso** das soluções individuais.

Em outras palavras, o código total que você escreve pode até ser grande, mas cada função ou módulo individual deve preferencialmente ser conciso.

#### Conclusão

Uma boa lógica não precisa necessariamente ter poucas linhas de código, mas um código extenso pode ser **sinal** de que há problemas com sua lógica (onde há fumaça, *pode ter* fogo). Pode ser caso de reinventar a roda, ter otimização prematura, não estar no nível correto de abstração. Em uma outra pergunta eu dei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14264/215) detalhando um pouco mais a questão da concisão do código. E com a ressalva que há muitos casos em que um bom algoritmo demanda sim código extenso.

Comment: Sim, entendo. É um contraste com o pensamento de alguns desenvolvedores. Sinceramente, considero a minha lógica um pouco amadora, mas a experiência e conhecimento durante os períodos de desenvolvimento, me ajudaram a entender melhor esta questão. Talvez não completamente, mas é através de outras pessoas que eu vou somar, para obter um bom resultado.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a velha máxima dividir para conquistar é uma boa prática. Fazer códigos com tamanho razoável, bem modularizado, bem orientado a objetos ajuda no gerencialmente de memória, mas acima de tudo, ajuda na manutenção do código. Quando a aplicação se torna grande e com muitas pessoas usando, os problemas e/ou novas implementações surgem e é neste momento que você descobrirá se vai ficar louco ou se simplesmente adicionará um módulo.

Comment: +1 pelo ficar louco...:P