# Uma função grande ou muitas pequenas?

Tags: funções, estilo-de-codificação

Por que criar uma função ou método grande com muitas linhas de código é considerado uma "má prática"? Quais as desvantagens disto?

O que eu ganho em dividir em funções ou métodos menores?

Quais fatores devo levar em conta para determinar quando subdividir uma função?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31485/o-tamanho-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-afeta-a-performance-e-consumo-de-mem%c3%b3ria

Comment: A má prática não está na quantidade de linhas mas sim na quantidade de responsabilidades; cada função deveria ter uma única responsabilidade. A quantidade de linhas é apenas um alerta de que o método pode estar com responsabilidades demais, que poderiam ser movidas para outras funções. Um dos principais motivos de ser má prática é que nosso cérebro tem um limite de coisas nas quais ele consegue focar de uma vez. Quando olhamos para um bloco de código geralmente estamos interessados em apenas uma de suas funções, então as demais funções que estão ali tiram o nosso foco, dificultando o trabalho.

Answer (score 19):

Desde que comecei desenvolver softwares (faz muito tempo) vejo pessoas falando de formas de avaliar quando uma função ou método é grande demais. Eu comprei todas estas formas até um certo dia. Isto é normal, isto é o que desenvolvedores inexperientes e ainda ingênuos fazem. Mas um dia descobri que não existe solução mágica e principalmente que não existe número mágico.

Até onde eu sei não existem estudos confiáveis que indiquem o tamanho ideal de uma função. Qualquer tentativa de achar algo assim parece estar fadado ao fracasso. Podemos observar o que outras pessoas pensam disto, aproveitar suas experiências e tentar facilitar um caminho para que cada caso individualmente seja mais facilmente determinado.

Em problemas apresentados de forma geral respostas genéricas não ajudam muito e respostas específicas apenas tentam vender como geral algo que não se aplica ao caso específico. E muitos livros conhecidos fazem isto. Eles precisam satisfazer o desejo dos leitores por alguma fórmula mágica.

Nos anos 80 eu ouvia que o programador ia acabar. Haveria fórmulas que determinavam tudo como um programa poderia se comportar e qualquer pessoa colocaria no computador o que precisava e o programa estaria ponto. Existem teses de doutorado sobre isto! Hoje todo mundo sabe quão ridículo é isto. O programador sempre será necessário justamente para determinar caso a caso o que é bom ou não, o que resolve ou não um problema. Não dá para generalizar. IA ajudará codificar de forma melhor, mas não modelar.

Quando alguém tentar explicar como tomar a decisão certa dá para dizer o que você precisa fazer para facilitar o processo mas nada que possa ser aconselhado irá fazer alguém tomar a decisão certa.

## Algumas definições e dicas

Vejamos algumas tentativas em inglês ocorridas no [Software Engineering.SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) para se chegar a uma "conclusão definitiva".

[What should be the maximum length of a function?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/27798/389) A pergunta foi fechada porque não dá para responder isto sem recorrer à opiniões e encontramos até uma piada sobre isto no [comentário do ThomasX](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27798/what-is-proven-as-a-good-maximum-length-of-a-function#comment276770_27798). Alguém tem dúvida que é uma piada?

**Quando alguém posta um número de linhas que uma função deve ter a pessoa só pode estar fazendo piada**.

Mas lá há respostas que nos ajudam **entender** como saber o tamanho ideal de **cada função individualmente**. Há até a apresentação de estudo que mostra as dificuldades das pessoas para compreender problemas e explicações. Muita informação, dispersa. Pouca informação, não ajuda nada, ou pior, ajuda do jeito errado.

Há quem diga que **depende** da linguagem que está sendo usada. É claro que depende. Depende também da tecnologia usada, do problema que está sendo solucionado, dos requisitos, da equipe que está trabalhando no problema e provavelmente outras coisas.

Outros dizem que a função deve ser **o menor possível**. E parece ser um bom conselho. O problema é saber o que é o menor possível. Muitas vezes isto é interpretado como a menor quantidade de linhas possível. As pessoas costumam ter uma tendência incrível de levar ao pé da letra certas recomendações. E pior, achar que elas valem para tudo. Daí nascem as tais "boas práticas" e de repente você não pode mais fazer de outro jeito, mais correto, porque fere a "boa prática".

Há até a afirmação que você deve diminuir o que a função faz até não ser mais possível diminuir. Um professor já me disse para fazer isto. Eu entreguei para ele um código em Pascal pior que Assembly. Exagerando um pouco cada função fazia apenas o que uma instrução Assembly é capaz de fazer.

Outro bom conselho: Se você não sabe dar um bom nome para a função, ela provavelmente faz mais do que devia. Está no caminho certo, **uma função não pode fazer mais do que deve**. Mas ainda não deixa claro o que é isto.

Alguém pergunta qual o tamanho ideal de um prédio. Por que será que não fazem todos os prédios do mesmo tamanho?

Aí vem o problema da **[complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193665/101)**. Realmente é relevante. É algo que atrapalha muito o entendimento de códigos. Um dos motivos que dividimos as funções em partes menores é justamente facilitar o entendimento de código. Isto tende facilitar a manutenção também. Não existe um número fixo do que é problema. Existem estudos indicando que isto é importante e que há uma relação entre ele e a quantidade de defeitos em software. E funções grandes **tendem** a ter mais complexidade ciclomática.

Há respostas deixando claro que uma função deve fazer apenas uma coisa. Não parece haver discussão sobre isto. É possível mas é improvável que uma função com [**responsabilidade única**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101) tenha muitas dezenas ou centenas de linhas. Todos os desenvolvedores experientes sabem que a maioria das funções terão bem poucas linhas. Mas também fica claro que dividir demais, só porque alguém disse que as funções devem ser pequenas, não trazem bons resultados. **Segmentar demais pode tornar o código mais difícil de acompanhar**. Você sai do código [spaguetti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/101) para o código lasanha.

Daí surge a dúvida se devemos criar uma função para algo que não será usado novamente em outro lugar. Pelo princípio da responsabilidade única da função, sim, devemos. Mas não podemos exagerar. Tem que avaliar o caso para não deixar mais difícil de entender o que está fazendo, criar uma situação mais complicada de lidar, piorar a performance de forma inaceitável ou dificultar a manutenção futura.

Então se for algo repetido, deve ser colocado em função? Não necessariamente. É provável mas, de novo, depende do caso. Lembrando que [DRY não significa necessariamente eliminar repetição de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). E mesmo que seja um caso que seja o ideal pelo DRY, existem outros fatores que precisam ser levados em consideração. De qualquer forma repetição de código pode ser **uma** causa de uma função ser grande. A repetição é um problema em si próprio. Eu já vi casos que a repetição deixa o código menor. Por isso os compiladores costumam otimizar código melhor que os humanos. Eles avaliam o caso específico de forma objetiva e sabem com certeza o que será mais ou menos rápido. Eles não fazem suposições.

Há boas observações que o tamanho pode afetar a performance para mais ou para menos. Esta até era a preocupação original do autor da pergunta mas que não ficou claro para ninguém. Chamar uma função tem custo, chamar mais do que deve (por ter mais funções do que deve, por dividir mais do que deve), afeta a performance negativamente, inclusive força uma manipulação de memória desnecessária. Funções grandes podem afetar o cache ou pode complicar um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) e a organização da memória. Mas funções grandes costumam afetar negativamente mais por um efeito colateral. Como ela pode ser mais complexa do que devia pode ser mais fácil cometer erros que afetam a performance. O oposto também é verdadeiro. Classes ou módulos grandes, cheio de métodos ou funções picadinhas podem causar o mesmo efeito. Falo disto com mais propriedade na [pergunta mais específica sobre consumo de recursos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31486/101).

Gosto da frase que **uma função deve ter o tamanho que ela precisa ter**. Sim, isso não quer dizer nada, mas é a única verdade indiscutível.

Há quem fale em funções que tratam de enormes `switch`s. Para quem coloca limite em número de linhas provavelmente tem exceção para isto. Quantas outras exceções são feitas? E se tudo isto era desnecessário? A exceção deixa passar assim mesmo? Parece que olhar para o número de linhas é, no mínimo, olhar para o problema errado.

E nota-se que cada um dá sua própria interpretação do que leu em algum lugar. E não dá para ser muito diferente. Cada um tem um caminho pregresso único, trabalha em situações únicas.

Depois achei uma [pergunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/133404/389) fechada também. Está ficando longo, não vou me estender. Fala-se muito que linhas não é um bom parâmetro e a função deve **fazer apenas uma coisa**. Alguns dizem que funções grandes são difíceis de testar. Isto é verdade mas complicar um *design* só para facilitar o teste também não me parece uma das melhores ideias (e há guerras santas sobre isto).

E finalmente [nessa pergunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/253267/389) mostra como estabelecer limites não faz sentido.

Se olhar os livros [Clean Code](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Clean_Code.html) e [Code Complete](https://www.cc2e.com/Default.aspx) verá uma discrepância enorme entre a recomendação do número de linhas ideal. O que mostra que estes livros devem ter sua credibilidade questionada (não que todo o livro seja ruim) já que mostram que esses números são apenas opiniões sem sentido. Mas se você quer ouvir algum dizer para você um número, em qual acreditar? 20 do Clean Code ou 200 do Code Complete? Ou 2 ou 12 que outra pessoa possa dizer?

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14275/101) eu falo de algumas coisas que são mais importantes para manter uma função "limpa".

## Conclusão

Se quer saber qual o número de linhas que uma função deve ter para chamar atenção do programador para determinar se ela está grande, escolha o número **um**. Uma linha já pode estar fazendo mais do que devia. E isto é o importante. A não ser que tenha um motivo para fazer o oposto escolha o tamanho que organize melhor o intuito. Não faça nem maior nem menor que isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 15):

Eu produzo em OOP, e aprendi a dividir em métodos. Assim podem ser reutilizáveis sempre que necessário... `**DRY**`

Na minha opinião, funções grandes geram código sujo. A chance de você ter funções muito similares é grande.

---

<sub>**Forma procedual por exemplo**:
`1) function criarLink()`</sub>

Uma função para criar um link, vai verificar o protocolo corrente `HTTP | HTTPS`, subdominio, entre outras coisas pertinentes.

<sub>`2) function criarImagem()`</sub>

Uma função para criar uma imagem, vai repetir algumas verificações similares na função `criarLink`.

---

Para diminuir a redundância o mais simples seria dividir em funções.
Em suma, dividir as responsabilidades para melhor aproveitamento pelo sistema como um todo.

Destrinchando o simplório exemplo acima, ao invés de duas funções redundantes cheias do mesmo código, bastaria ter as funções `criarImagem` e `criarLink` para a composição dos elementos do HTML (por exemplo) e funções como `isSecure`, `getSubdomain`, etc - que estariam sempre acessíveis sem dependência.

Fazendo uso dos exemplos simples, `isSecure` e `getSubdomain`, seriam 2 métodos( em OOP ) que contém elementos para `Response, Request, View, Controller, ...`. Em várias etapas você precisa ter acesso ao tipo de requisição, protocolo de saida entre outros.

> Um sistema orientado de forma correta é de fácil manutenção, fácil adaptação de `pattern's`, possui reaproveitamento de códigos tornando a produção mais ágil...

Comment: Concordo, mas acho que se deve cuidar pra não dividir demais, tipo, uma nova função de uma ou duas linhas. Aí acaba ficando mais trabalhoso pra outra pessoas analisar.

Comment: Sem duvida. Para isso não acontecer vai depender do bom senso do DEV.

Comment: Basicamente você está explicando o DRY que não é causa nem consequência do tamanho dos métodos. @Earendul não há problema algum em quantos métodos forem com 1 linha, se o que ele precisa fazer tem apenas uma linha. O que "não pode" é o método fazer mais do que deveria, ter múltiplas responsabilidades. "Não pode" separar uma tarefa única em vários métodos. É raro acontecer mas se realmente um método faz um única tarefa e precisa de dezenas de linhas, o tamanho dele é bom, divisões adicionais serão artificiais e desnecessárias.

Comment: Citei DRY justamente pela repeticao exagerada de codes... Acho que OOP ou procedial, a nao repeticao de codigo é fundamental.

Comment: Tamanho de código e repetição são coisas distintas. A repetição pode até levar ao método ser grande mas por si só este não é o problema, o problema é a repetição. Se mesmo que tenha repetições (que não é bom) o método tem só o que ele precisa fazer, ele não é grande. Você está falando do efeito colateral da repetição. Eu adoro DRY, você tem razão no que estão falando, mas não é o ponto central desta pergunta. Não diz qual é o problema do método grande. Não diz quando o método é maior do que deveria.

Comment: O metodo é maior que deveria - ao meu ver - quando faz mais que sua responsabilidade. Tentei abordar isso na questao levantando 2 exemplos ficticios que possuem verificacoes em comum que deveriam ser abstraidas. Criar um link por exemplo, nao tem responsabilidade de identificar o protocolo.

Answer (score 12):

Eu acredito que o tamanho da função não seja o critério, mas sim um indicador.

Por exemplo se tivermos uma função `ImprimeRelatorio` por exemplo que dentro dela ela rendenize, ajuste as margens, leia as configurações do usuário para detalhes do relatório, chame a tela de configuração de impressão e depois imprima faz o seu nome diz, mas ali não é o lugar para existir regras sobre as as preferencias do usuário.

se a função não implementar todas essas funcionalidades, mas realizar a ativação de outras funções que façam isso, já não é tão ruim, como por exemplo em:

```js
function ImprimeRelatorio ( relatorio ) {
  relatorio.render( relatorio.getMargins() );
  relatorio.applyUserPrefs( relatorio.getUserPrefs() );
  var cfgImpressao = getCfgImpressao();
  relatorio.print( cfgImpressao );  
}
```

Mas geralmente a regra cai para o bom senso e noções de Coesão e Acoplamento, Injeção de dependência e outras mais.

Comment: A resposta está no caminho certo mas falta um pouco de fundamentação do porque isto é bom.

Comment: @bigown Valeu pela dica! Vou tentar terminar, mas estou com uma demanda grande aqui hoje para entregar para as outras equipes. No horário do almoço consigo complementar explicando melhor com um embasamento teórico melhor.

Answer (score 12):

## O que tento fazer

Procuro seguir o conceito de fazer classes e funções com somente [uma responsabilidade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Programando com esse princípio, naturalmente você vai gerar funções e classes menores.

O maior benefício que percebi programando dessa maneira foi na manutenção e design do código fonte.

Por exemplo, você tem duas funções, uma que busca os dados e outra que renderiza os dados.

Caso você altere a função de busca, você pode ter inserido um bug nessa função, o código referente a renderização continua intacto em outra função.

Caso você programe a renderização e a busca na mesma função, as lógicas desses códigos estarão misturadas, qualquer alteração significa um risco de quebrar as duas funcionalidades.

Resumindo:

> Se você programar somente uma funcionalidade por função, quando você
> for dar manutenção naquela funcionalidade você só vai quebrar aquela
> funcionalidade, as outras continuam intactas.

## O que faço de fato

Escrevo programas comercialmente, na grande maioria das vezes eu programo buscando entregar no prazo.

Dependendo dos prazos meus códigos ficam mais próximo ou mais distantes do modelo que idealizei a princípio.

## Exceções

Existem razões para fazer se escrever funções monstruosas, uma que conheço é com relação a performance em processamento batch.

É mais rápido para o computador acessar um trecho de código que está logo ali pertinho na memória do que pular para uma trecho muito distante e ficar fazendo isso várias vezes.

Dependendo da necessidade do seu projeto, um dia você vai precisar otimizar o projeto fazendo código "feios" performáticos.

Outro caso que eu particularmente não ligo muito para isso é em códigos simples, pequenos scripts, etc. As vezes o projeto é tão simples que você só vai complicar fazendo essas coisas.

## O mais importante

Pegue todas as opiniões, livros que você leu sobre o tema e os veja como ferramentas, usando conforme a necessidade de cada projeto.

Usar como verdade absoluta uma fonte ou outra só vai atrapalhar.

## Update 2021

Recomendo ler a resposta do @Maniero.

Ela diz tudo que eu disse e muito mais de uma forma bem mais aprofundada e com fontes.

Answer (score 9):

O importante é o método fazer apenas uma coisa e somente uma, isso diminui a complexidade e facilita testes e manutenções.

Exemplo:

```php
public function salvar(){
    //salva seu modelo

    //lógica não pertencente ao método 
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Agora pense se você quiser salvar mais não quer realizar um redirecionamento ? Fica complicado, irá acontecer no mínimo uma gambi. Pense também na manutenção, você chama o método e acontece um redirecionamento inesperado. Isso tudo porque o método não está fazendo o que se propõe somente.

Answer (score 7):

Eu acredito que isso varia muito de acordo com a sua necessidade....

Muitas vezes podemos quebrar funções grandes utilizando recursividade e/ou utilizando pedacinhos de funções menores que compõem em conjunto o que a grande faria (A grosso modo, eu prefiro muito mais quebrar em várias funções), isso pode diminuir e/ou aumentar a quantidade de passos que um algoritmo ira percorrer, concordo em muito com comentários acima, de que isso vai mais da lógica do programador do que da linguagem utilizada...
Em geral, isso é um problema mais de complexidade de algoritmos.

Devemos muitas vezes analisar o ambiente que queremos trabalhar, vou dar um exemplo clássico de linguagem de baixo nível:

Quando estamos trabalhando diretamente na programação de micro controladores (um ambiente que trabalhamos na maioria das vezes em binário ou hexadecimal), não podemos usar o operador ‘/’ (divisão) porque é uma função que não é nativa da linguagem. Pra isso temos que incluir uma biblioteca e a usar, isso gera diversos acessos nos registradores do processador, e acarreta que seu algoritmo fica bem mais lento, uma GAMBIARRA que da certo nesse ambiente é utilizar uma espécie de função “empurre o bit para a direita”, exemplificando:

> O numero binário 11101 em decimal é igual a 29, se o empurrarmos uma
>   vez para a direita, teremos 011102 que é 14, ou 29/2, se empurrarmos
>   mais uma vez dará 00111 é igual a 7 ou 29/4.

Com a biblioteca que possui o método de divisão, teríamos apenas 1 linha de código, e com esse algoritmo de “`PUSH TO THE RIGHT`” teremos em torno de 4 a 5 linhas.
Na verdade isso não é uma Gambiarra propriamente dita, mas sim um truque que utilizamos, e o processador agradece, porque assim ele utiliza muito menos recursos de processamento.

Em linguagens de alto nível temos outros tipos de abstrações que devemos tomar cuidado. Por exp: a um tempo atrás tinha que fazer uma lista ordenada dentro de outra lista que também tinha que ser ordenada, tinha várias escolas, e tinha vários alunos dentro de cada escola.

Eu quebrei a minha cabeça durante alguns dias pra desenvolver um algoritmo que fizesse isso, ele deu umas 20 linhas, ai eu mostrei meu código pra um colega, e ele me deu uma sugestão que no final acabou por ser bem mais fácil e melhor, ordenar toda a lista por  escola, e comparar se o ultimo resultado obtido era igual ao atual, se sim continua listando, se não cria uma nova linha pra escola e lista, com isso obtive uma economia de umas 10 – 8 linhas. Não precisei nem quebrar o código em pedacinhos rs

Por essas e outras que isso depende demais da sua necessidade. Não há uma politica de boa prática quanto a quantidade de linhas de uma função, mas sim de performance, se você ver que o algoritmo ta ficando muito lento, para, pensa, e em últimos casos busque ajuda e alternativas (y)