# O que é código spaghetti?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação

Quando se lê sobre arquitetura de software na web, às vezes é usado o termo ***"código spaghetti"***, se referindo a algo que deve ser evitado.

Porém nunca consegui entender com clareza o que "código spaghetti" significa.

Comment: +1. Acho esse tipo de pergunta muito importante e estou ansioso pra ver boas respostas :) De antemão, isso é relevante: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio eu fiquei surpreso, pois trabalho com programação há uns 10 anos e nunca tinha ouvido falar de código lasanha e código ravioli (sério, olha lá!). Vou ver se encontro algo sobre código fusilli pois é minha massa favorita XD

Comment: Antes mesmo do paradigma OO surgiu o paradigma da [**Programação Estruturada**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_estruturada). Acontece que os "jovens" já aprenderam neste paradigma e não imaginam como era a bagunça de programar com **GOTO**, **GOSUB**, **JPZ**, etc

Answer (score 26, accepted):

É um código com complexidade de fluxo, em geral numa linha constante de execução, onde mistura-se saltos de execução usando estruturas de desvio incondicional, como o `GOTO`, `END`, etc.

Um exemplo com código espaguete em BASIC:

```basic
10 i = 0
20 i = i + 1
30 PRINT i; " squared = "; i * i
40 IF i >= 10 THEN GOTO 60
50 GOTO 20
60 PRINT "Program Completed."
70 END
```

Que poderia ser implementado de forma mais bem estruturada assim:

```
10 FOR i = 1 TO 10
20     PRINT i; " squared = "; i * i
30 NEXT i
40 PRINT "Program Completed."
50 END
```

Também é usado como termo para mistura de tecnologias quando desenvolve-se com linguagens script, como em PHP+HTML. 
Entenda que PHP é usado como template em arquiteturas MVC de sistemas onde classes que geram a saída (Visão) precisam escrever HTML puro e inserir dados dinâmicos em sua geração. 
O termo código espaguete aqui seria usado quando a lógica do programa em PHP está inserida juntamente com a saída de interface do usuário.

Um exemplo em PHP + HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Macaronic Code</title></head>
<body>
    <?php
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'username', 'password');
        $statement = $dbh->query("SELECT lastlog FROM logins WHERE ip = '$ip'");
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $dbh->query("INSERT INTO logins VALUES ('$ip', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastlog = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    ?>
    <p>Hello, <?php print $ip; ?>.</p>
    <script>
        var lastlog = "<?php print $row['lastlog']?>";
        if (lastlog > "") alert("You last visited "+lastlog);
        else alert("You've never been here before.");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este código teria uma arquitetura melhor se a lógica de conexão estivesse em uma classe ou função de conexão, separada do HTML. A lógica de query do banco de dados também em uma classe ou função. E existisse uma rotina de controle de fluxo que chamasse a geração de saída, passando os dados que ela deverá usar, talvez no formato de um array.

E então a parte HTML somente usaria o PHP como template de acordo com o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Better Code</title></head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, <?php echo $data['ip']; ?>.</p>
    <script>
        var lastlog = "<?php echo $data['lastlog']?>";
        if (lastlog > "") alert("You last visited "+lastlog);
        else alert("You've never been here before.");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima ainda poderíamos melhorar este código separando a parte JavaScript e inserindo como um arquivo externo de forma não intrusiva.

O [verbete da Wikipedia em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) descreve também o código lasagna, ravioli e macaroni.

O artigo [*Spaguetti Code*](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/spaghetti-code) descreve técnicas, estratégias para refatorar um código espaguete.

Para entender alguns dos demais conceitos citados:

- [MVC](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_mvc.htm)
- [Refatoração](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fd26864d-cb41-49cf-b719-d89c6b072893/entry/o_que__C3_A9_e_o_que_n_C3_A3o__C3_A9_refatora_C3_A7_C3_A3o_de_acordo_com_kent_beck_e_martin_fowler?lang=en)
- [JavaScript não intrusivo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

<sub>Desculpem as referências em inglês, mas elas apresentam um material de melhor conteúdo em relação às em português que encontrei.</sub>

Answer (score 59):

[image: Ensō, o símbolo da iluminação, força, elegância, o universo e o vazio]

<sub>Assim disse o Mestre Programador: *Um programa bem escrito é seu próprio paraíso; um programa mal escrito é seu próprio inferno.*</sub>

---

O código *Spaghetti* é a antítese do código *Zen*.

É o ruído de processo tendendo ao infinito quando expresso em código.

É a solução preferida de paladares iniciantes, porém não refinados; mata a fome, mas não traz satisfação.

O mestre programador, ao contrário, prefere seu código limpo e enxuto. Ele acaricia o processador ao invés de torturá-lo.

O código *Zen* é universal; Com um olhar você sabe exatamente o que ele faz.
O código *Spaghetti* é críptico. Ele não pode ser intuído. Você precisa mapeá-lo.

O código *Zen* é sucinto. Em poucas linhas ele abrange todo o processo.
O código *Spaghetti* se repete ritmicamente, mas é pretensioso e faz mau uso do tempo.

O código *Zen* facilita e abraça o crescimento.
O código *Spaghetti* torna a manutenção difícil, custosa e lenta.

O código *Zen* é como a água, se adaptando a novas formas sem esforço.
O código *Spaghetti*, quando corrigido em um ponto, cria bugs em outros.

O código *Zen* é um poema.
O Código *Spaghetti* é o discurso de três horas do diretor financeiro.

<sub>Fontes (em inglês):</sub>
    <sub>- [O Tao da Programação](http://canonical.org/~kragen/tao-of-programming.html)</sub>
    <sub>- [Leis Fundamentais do Código Spaghetti](http://theprogrammersparadox.blogspot.com/2009/11/spaghetti-code.html)</sub>
    <sub>- [Ensō](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ens%C5%8D)</sub>

<sub>Com colaborações de [@brasofilo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/201/brasofilo). Obrigado!</sub>

Comment: Isso vem de algum livro? Eu preciso saber qual!

Comment: @Renan Não é de nenhum livro, mas é inspirado em vários textos. =) Eu adicionei os links, bom proveito!

Comment: A última "estrofe" me ganhou.

Comment: Não concordo que essa seja a resposta aceita. A idéia por trás dela é boa, mas está expressa de uma maneira subjetiva demais em muitos lugares e para mim serviria mais como complemento a uma resposta como a do @Jay, baseada na Wikipedia. _Just my two cents._ Mesmo assim aprovo o fato dela estar indo um pouco além e demonstrando desvantagens do código _spaghetti_.

Comment: @Piovezan eu entendo o seu ponto, e o programador dentro de mim não poderia concordar mais - a razão do meu upvote para Jay e Ademir. Quando comecei a escrever o primeiro draft da minha resposta eu fui nesta direção; mas, devido à quantidade de linguagens existentes, e já que o objetivo da resposta era ser agnóstica em relação à linguagem, eu me vi escrevendo uma resposta Spaghetti - longa e de difícil leitura. E, enquanto que certas liberdades poéticas foram tomadas, o objetivo de demonstrar clareza, simplicidade e legibilidade (como contraponto ao foco do OP) foram mantidos.

Comment: Às vezes a subjetividade consegue ser mais concisa que a explicação mais cartesiana.

Comment: Essa resposta ficou genial. E concordo com o @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Answer (score 19):

*Código espaguete* é código que tem o fluxo de controle complicado, abusando de mecanismos como exceções, desvios incondicionais (`GOTO`), e construções semelhantes. Dá-se esse nome porque o fluxograma de código desse tipo tem muitas linhas cruzando e indo para todo lado, lembrando de fato um macarrão espaguete.

O código espaguete é prática usual em [BASIC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC), por exemplo, e a linguagem [Pascal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) surgiu justamente para encorajar o uso de programação estruturada, evitando a "bagunça de fluxo de controle".

Há uma [entrada na Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_espaguete) sobre isto.

Comment: Acho que o espaguete é universal. O Esperanto da programação. Já vi em Lingo, ActionScript, JavaScript e PHP. Tenho certeza que meus primeiros passos em Pascal foram espaguete também, mas infelizmente já não tenho registros históricos...

Comment: @brasofilo Sinto muito por você ter programado em Lingo :) Curiosidade: o que você usa hoje no lugar do Director? Eu faço muitas aplicações standalone nesse estilo, e cada hora tenho usado uma tecnologia diferente.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não tenho rancor do Lingo, achava engraçadinho ;) Virou DVD Studio Pro pra apresentação de vídeos e Flash para interatividade web. Algumas navegações malucas no dvd, e até comecei a fazer um híbrido dvd video/mac/win, mas não foi pra frente. Depois virou tudo web, com WordPress/jQuery substituindo o Flash.

Comment: @brasofilo Eu também uso principalmente tecnologias web hoje em dia (HTML5 + JS), mas muitas vezes preciso que isso rode offline, em quiosques ou coisa do tipo. É aí que o bicho pega, ainda não achei um software 100% bacana pra "tocar" isso (o melhor até agora é o [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)).

Answer (score 2):

Código spagheti se refere ao código cujo fluxo de controle é confuso e entrelaçado como espaguete. Dessa forma, cada linha de código pode estar referenciando quase qualquer variável em qualquer lugar e manter o código torna-se praticamente impossível, porque o risco de introduzir erros em outros lugares é muito grande. Este termo é muito usado no contexto da programação que utiliza a declaração Goto.

Isso é diferente de **código macarrônico**, que pode ser definido como um código que usa uma mistura de linguagens de programação em um único documento. Dessa forma, para entender um código macarrônico é necessário ter conhecimento da maioria das linguagens utilizadas nesse código.

O exemplo abaixo é um código macarrônico, que mistura as linguagens HTML, PHP, SQL e Javascript em um único documento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Macaronic Code</title></head>
<body>
    <?php
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'username', 'password');
        $statement = $dbh->query("SELECT lastlog FROM logins WHERE ip = '$ip'");
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $dbh->query("INSERT INTO logins VALUES ('$ip', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastlog = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    ?>
    <p>Hello, <?php print $ip; ?>.</p>
    <script>
        var lastlog = "<?php print $row['lastlog']?>";
        if (lastlog > "") alert("You last visited "+lastlog);
        else alert("You've never been here before.");
    </script>
</body>
```