# Descontinuação da tag <center>

Tags: html

Sei que parece muito, se calhar até é mesmo muita falta de conhecimento, mas eu ja fiz algumas pesquisas e não achei nada que me convencesse de facto.

Alguém tem alguma, ou sabe porquê a tag  foi descontinuada?

Porque as vezes acho muito mais fácil do que ter que centralizar usando CSS. Alguém tem uma explicação?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conforme HTML, CSS e JavaScript/DOM foram evoluindo, os "evangelistas" dos padrões web passaram a defender uma separação mais clara das responsabilidades de cada uma dessas camadas, buscando mitigar o problema do HTML ["espaguete"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31315/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-spaghetti).

As responsabilidades são:

- **HTML:** dar **estrutura** ao conteúdo de acordo com o seu *sentido*.
- **CSS:** definir a **aparência** do HTML renderizado.
- **JavaScript:** definir o **comportamento** do documento na interação com as pessoas.

A tag `<center>` tinha um fim puramente visual, e não estrutural ou semântico. Portanto era uma parte do HTML que deveria estar sendo tratada pelo CSS, e assim foi descontinuada. Isso ocorreu também com [diversos outros elementos e atributos](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html).

Comment: Excelente resposta.

Comment: Convencido! Porém, ainda acho que é sempre mais fácil escrever <center> do que <div class="estilo_central"></div>.
kkkk.

Comment: @ColdHack Na verdade seria mais semântico usar `<div class="conteudo-principal"></div>` (ou seja, um nome de classe que diga a *função* do conteúdo). ;)

Comment: @ColdHack - Com certeza. Porém, pense que você tem vários elementos com `<center>` e mais tarde precise mudar para _left_ ou _right_, você teria que mudar cada elemento. Com CSS você só precisaria mudar o estilo e todos os elementos se adaptariam...

Comment: Têm razão malta, eu até sei disso só que... uffas

Answer (score 5):

> . A  tag deve ser evitado porque ele foi reprovado desde HTML versão 4. [[fonte]](http://www.html-5.com/changes/deprecated/center-tag.html)
>   . Além de não ser suportado em HTML5. [[fonte]](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)

**<center>** está obsoleta mas seu efeito pode ser alcançado usando *align* ou uma formatação do elemento pelo css. Ela não passa de um atalho para `<div align="center">`. *Align* continua sendo válido, *<center>* deve ser evitada.

---

[Debate 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636309/right-way-to-center-a-div-in-xhtml), 
[Debate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html). Ambos abordam o desuso da tag center.

Comment: @Thallyson Dias, essa informação não é garantida para mim. Desculpe, vou desfazer a atualização. Você pode comentar abaixo sua afirmação.

Comment: A 1ª fonte não explica porquê, apenas diz que foi descontinuada desde a versão 4 do HTML, por isso deve-se evitar o uso. 
E sim, eu já sabia que não é suportado no HTML5, mas onde posso encontrar pelo menos uma explanação da sua descontinuação. Se o align ainda é permitido(utilizado), porquê tirar o center?

Valeu pela resposta pronta.

Comment: O motivo exato somente se estiver em doc, caso contrario pode ser mera especulacao. [aqui](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/cani-someone-actually-explain-why-the-center-tag-is-deprecated/6303) tem um debate com alguns pontos interessantes, mas nada oficial.

Comment: @ColdHack, a segunda resposta do debate 2 que eu citei, oferece a melhor justificativa, na minha opiniao. Estou no cel agora, depois faço uma transcrição.