# Substituto da TAG <center>

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```css
.table {
  max-width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 12;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
}

.table tr td{
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;


}
.campo {
  border: 1px double black;
}

#teste {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 18ç0px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999; 
  left:0%; 
  top:0%;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:6px;
}

#teste2 {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999; 
  right:0%;
  top:0%;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste">
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="button" onclick="ver()" value="x">
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;"></div>
  </form>
</div>

<center>
  <h1>x</h1>
</center>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="#">
  <center>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td class="campo">
          <span id="inf1">*x</span><br/>
          <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" size="2"/><br/>
          <span id="inf2">x?</span><br/>
          <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" size="2"/><br/>
          x?
          <input type="checkbox" id="ckb" name="ckb" /><br/><br/>
          <input type="button" value="x" onclick="setaInf();">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <br/>
    <span id="inf3"><small>*x</small></span>
  </center>
</form>

<div id="teste2">
  <form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="button" onclick="ver()" value="x">
    <div id="lol1" style="display: none;"></div>
  </form>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<center>
  <div>
    <form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="#">
      <div id="lol" style="display: none;"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</center>
```

Sei que a tag `<center>` foi descontinuada e segundo referencias, o correto agora seria usar o atributo `css` `text-align:center;` mas mesmo assim não consigo reproduzir o mesmo efeito, vide o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.table {
  max-width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 12;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
}

.table tr td{
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;


}
.campo {
  border: 1px double black;
}

#teste {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 18ç0px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999; 
  left:0%; 
  top:0%;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:6px;
}

#teste2 {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999; 
  right:0%;
  top:0%;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste">
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="button" onclick="ver()" value="x">
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;"></div>
  </form>
</div>

<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <h1>x</h1>
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="#">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td class="campo">
          <span id="inf1">*x</span><br/>
          <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" size="2"/><br/>
          <span id="inf2">x?</span><br/>
          <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" size="2"/><br/>
          x?
          <input type="checkbox" id="ckb" name="ckb" /><br/><br/>
          <input type="button" value="x" onclick="setaInf();">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <br/>
    <span id="inf3"><small>*x</small></span>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="teste2">
  <form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="button" onclick="ver()" value="x">
    <div id="lol1" style="display: none;"></div>
  </form>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="#">
    <div id="lol" style="display: none;"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Como faço pra centralizar as duas `div´s` do primeiro exemplo sem ter que usar a tag `<center>`?

Comment: Vinculado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32276/descontinua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-tag-center/32278#32278

Comment: remova as tags <center> e adicione o css no body, body{ text-align:center; }.. Há outros meios de resolver também. Não quer dizer que isso seja a única solução ou a melhor solução.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `text-align` só serve para alinhar elementos `inline` ou `inline-block`. As divs por padrão são `block`s, por isso não são afetadas por essa propriedade. Você pode centralizar uma div horizontalmente definindo suas margens esquerda e direita como `auto`. Por exemplo:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Só que isso não iria afetar todas as `divs`? No caso devo aplicar a um estilo e jogar nas `divs` que devem ser centralizadas, correto?

Comment: Bom, sua div `#teste` tem `position: absolute`, e nesse caso as duas coisas são incompatíveis. Ou você define a posição na unha com `position: absolute`, ou centraliza automático com a técnica que eu expliquei.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acredito que utilizar `left: auto; e right: auto;` centralize, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: @Oeslei Não, precisaria usar `calc()`.

Comment: Tentei reproduzir o problema no fiddle, tenho 4 divs, duas tem que ser `absolute` e duas centralizadas, uma teria uma div, e a outra uma tabela... desse modo:

http://jsfiddle.net/vb873zo5/

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Não entendi direito no fiddle o que está errado, e o que precisa ser centralizado (nota: `position: float` não existe).

Comment: De fato aquele estilo não estava sendo usado em lugar nenhum, foi apenas ruído que acabei pegando do caso real e acabei trazendo pro exemplo, mas já consegui solucionar o problema @bfavaretto, agradecido ;]

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Só falta adicionar o `margin: 0 auto` na tabela. https://jsfiddle.net/vb873zo5/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 4):

O estilo `text-align: center;` centraliza o conteúdo dentro de um bloco. No seu caso não centralizou porque você colocou o estilo errado: `text=align:center;` onde deveria ser `text-align: center;`.

Para centralizar o bloco (não o seu conteúdo), como é o exemplo da sua tabela, você deve adicionar um outro estilo: `margin: 0 auto;` ou `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. Assim, o browser vai calcular a margem direita e esquerda automaticamente para centralizar o bloco.

Comment: Desculpa ai, eu que na hora de criar a pergunta acabei não prestando atenção e escrevi errado, já corrigi a propriedade `text-align` na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem mas se você deseja centralizar divs na tela você pode adicionar o CSS `margin:0 auto;` na div que será alinhada ao centro.