# Quais são as características da programação estruturada?

Tags: c, estilo-de-codificação, paradigma-de-programação, procedural

Eu gostaria de saber quais são as características que define o paradigma da *programação estruturada*, e qual é a diferença deste paradigma com o paradigma da *programação procedural*? Ambos para mim me parece a mesma coisa, e não muda a maneira de programar.

Aqui segue um programa feito em C que é uma linguagem estruturada para ilustração:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void soma();
void subtrai();

int valor1, valor2;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Valor 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor1);

    printf("Valor 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor2);

    soma();
    subtrai();

    return 0;
}

void soma()
{
    printf("\n\nSoma: %d", valor1 + valor2);
}

void subtrai()
{
    printf("\n\nSubtracao: %d", valor1 - valor2);
}
```

Nota:

> Podem citar exemplos na linguagem C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C é uma linguagem que permite e até facilita a [programação estruturada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming), que em tese pode ser aplicada em qualquer linguagem de programação de alto nível. Na verdade hoje praticamente não há mais linguagem que incentive programação não estruturada, até algumas que incentivavam hoje possuem dialetos mais fortes que não incentiva ou praticamente não permite.

O [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) costuma ser aplicado no código. A maioria das linguagens de programação permitem usar qualquer paradigma. Claro que elas facilitam mais alguns do que outros. Obviamente que paradigmas parecidos são mais facilmente adaptados.

Há algumas "versões" do que é programação estruturada. Uma das mais aceitas é que não pode-se usar `goto` indiscriminadamente e dar preferência para estruturas de controle de fluxo mais organizados como `while` ou funções, por exemplo. Ela prega que se evite [código macarrônico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/101). O uso de funções para ajudar no fluxo é incentivado, mas nada se fala além do fluxo.

O termo era importante nos anos 60 e 70 quando era comum programar-se de forma pouco estruturada, privilegiando a otimização e não a legibilidade (lembrando que antes os computadores eram bem menos poderosos e os compiladores eram bem simplificados, não possuindo otimizações. E os códigos eram muito simples. Hoje é mais comum usar os termos [imperativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) e [procedural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming).

## Procedural

De fato a programação procedural é uma evolução da programação estruturada, ou pelo menos uma definição mais específica. A procedural apenas incentiva mais a modularização do código, mas ainda não é [programnação modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101).

## Imperativo

O paradigma imperativo (comparação com [funcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101) e [declarativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101)) define que o código será executado passo a passo, ou seja, comando por comando, mudando o estado dos dados, incluindo o fluxo de execução. Se o fluxo é controlado de forma estruturada é um paradigma mais evoluído. A imensa maioria das linguagens de programação *mainstream* são predominantemente imperativas com capacidades excelentes para estruturação, e outras organizações.

## Analisando o exemplo

Curiosamente o código do exemplo até mostra alguma estrutura, mas não é um código com boa estrutura. Sei que é só um exemplo, mas ele viola um princípio que é mais bem explorado hoje em dia, que é o da [responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101), em todas as três funções. Esse princípio é a base do paradigma procedural e mais ainda no [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). Um código melhor escrito seria mais procedural e modular:

```
void imprimeSoma(int valor1, int valor2) { //preferi mudar o nome do que mudar a função
    printf("\n\nSoma: %d", valor1 + valor2);
}
void imprimeSubtracao(int valor1, int valor2) { //se mantiver subtrai, não poderia imprimir
    printf("\n\nSubtracao: %d", valor1 - valor2);
}
int pegaValor(char * texto) {
    printf(texto);
    int valor;
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    return valor;
}
int main(void) {
    int valor1 = pegaValor("Valor 1: "); //é mais procedural deixar a variável local
    int valor2 = pegaValor("Valor 2: ");
    imprimeSoma(valor1, valor2); //os dados devem ser locais e passados para funções
    imprimeSubtracao(valor1, valor2); //a função comunica com parâmetros
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/StructuredExample.c).

Não sei se o código funciona, só quis passar a ideia.

Comment: Código correto http://ideone.com/JiLNhV