# Dúvidas sobre análise e design estruturado e orientada a objetos

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, programação-estruturada

Processo de software, envolve várias atividades, dentre elas, análise e design. Entre as opções de métodos para realizar essas atividades, temos o estruturado e orientado a objetos. Em relação a ambas, tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Qual a principal diferença?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de cada uma?
- Por que o método orientado a objetos é utilizado na maioria dos casos?

Comment: Comecei a tentar escrever uma resposta adicional, mas estava ficando bem inferior a resposta existente. Você poderia explicar porque a resposta existente não lhe é suficiente?

Comment: @VictorStafusa É uma boa resposta, mas acredito que faltou citar algumas desvantagens de AOO e vantagens de AE. Quanto a utilização de OO, acredito que há outras razões além reutilização de código e segurança.

Comment: Vou complementar minha resposta.

Comment: Feito, resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Qual a principal diferença?

- Na **Análise Estruturada** (chamaremos de AE), o foco está principalmente no processo e procedimentos. As principais técnicas utilizadas são o DFD (Diagrama de Fluxo de Dados), gráficos de fluxo, tabela/árvore de decisão e análise de Entidade-Relacionamento. É uma prática antiga e não recomendada atualmente.
- Na **Análise Orientada a Objeto** (chamaremos de AOO), o foco está em capturar objetos do mundo real contextualizando-os em um cenário relevante ao problema (de modo amplo, reproduzir *algumas* características do mundo real em um ambiente de software). O detalhamento é maior para as estruturas de dados e menor (menos imperativo/específico) para estrutura de procedimentos e métodos. As técnicas de modelagens utilizam [UML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML) (que pode apresentar tanto aspectos estruturais como comportamentais/procedurais do sistema).

Particularmente eu relaciono, de modo grosseiro, que a análise estruturada está para a [programação estruturada e procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122430/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-caracter%C3%ADsticas-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-estruturada) assim como a análise orientada a objetos está para a [programação orientada a objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/7499); onde a AOO representa as interações entre objetos de um sistema a nível de conceito, e a AE as interações entre partes do sistema a um nível de funções/métodos.

> Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de cada uma?

- A AOO utiliza UML, que é mais reutilizável e fácil de manter, quando comparada aos digramadas da AE;
- A AE possui foco na funcionalidade do programa, resultando em uma linguagem imperativa, mais clara para o programador. A AOO, por ser mais declarativa, pode não ser tão clara/específica em algumas especificações;
- A AE utiliza modelagem orientada a processos, o que torna mais simples a compreensão da movimentação dos dados - seja pelo desenvolvedor ou cliente;
- A AOO é mais eficiente em projetos grandes e com alto risco de mudança nos requisitos do sistema, ao passo de que a AE é eficiente para projetos bem definidos e com requisitos estáveis;
- A AOO foi desenvolvida com o intuito de minimizar os problemas enfrentados na criação de softwares complexos, permitindo o uso de orientação a objetos - herança, polimorfismo, composição, encapsulamento, entre outros -, que não está disponível na AE;
- A AOO é mais utilizada hoje em dia, o que implica em maior disponibilidade de documentação e informações no geral;
- A AOO exige maior esforço na modelagem do sistema quando comparada à AE, mas também menor esforço de codificação - temos aqui uma característica que move a complexidade do desenvolvimento para a análise, o que é bastante discutível no contexto de ser uma vantagem ou desvantagem;
- A AOO têm uma tendência maior a enfrentar problemas de modelagem devido a sua maior complexidade. Um exemplo prático, causado pela falta de conhecimento de abstração, seria a criação de uma modelagem que leva a criação de implementações semelhantes separadas, contidas em classes diferentes não reutilizáveis;
- AOO pode introduzir verbosidade superior à AE em projetos pequenos: em alguns casos a utilização do paradigma de OO pode gerar mais linhas de código que a implementação estruturada. Essa desvantagem desaparece à medida que são adicionados casos de uso que se beneficiem da POO;
- A AOO oferece, por meio da OO, uma facilidade de extensão superior à AE, pois a criação de modelos novos que se comuniquem com os existentes não obriga o desenvolvedor a conhecer o funcionamento interno destes últimos.

> Por que o método orientado a objetos é utilizado na maioria dos casos?

Acredito que a principal razão é devido a sua **semelhança com o mundo real** (objetos possuem características e podem realizar/sofrer procedimentos), o que torna mais fácil representá-lo de maneira natural. Além disso a orientação a objetos permite uma **reutilização de código** muito grande, especialmente em projetos grandes.

No momento que você define, por exemplo, uma classe `Usuário` pro seu sistema, este pode ser importado/requerido em qualquer outro módulo que tenha acesso à classe. Casos de uso complexos que requerem herança ou composição podem ser implementados de maneira simples com OO. Isso implica em processos de **desenvolvimento e manutenção simplificados**, já que existe apenas um arquivo a ser alterado - além de seguir uma importante regra de desenvolvimento, a [DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120931/o-dry-%C3%A9-para-evitar-redund%C3%A2ncias-certo).

Outro aspecto relevante é a **maior segurança**, onde a OO oferece controle de visibilidade (métodos públicos e privados, por exemplo), o que implica em permitir ou impedir a utilização de funcionalidades do sistema num contexto de desenvolvimento. A aplicação dessa prática também **simplifica a API do software**, algo especialmente útil na criação de bibliotecas e exportações do código, pois o programador que desenvolve o software cliente apenas tem conhecimento e acesso aos métodos públicos.

---

Fontes:

- [Vantagens de programar com Orientação a Objetos (OOP)](http://dev.rbtech.info/vantagens-de-programar-com-orientacao-a-objetos-oop/) (RBTech Developer);
- [Difference between Structured Analysis and Object Oriented
  Analysis?](https://slideplayer.com/slide/6214296/) (SlideShare);
- [Chapter 6: Structured Vs. Object Oriented
  Analysis and Design](https://slideplayer.com/slide/7657128/) (SlideShare);
- [Structured Vs, Object Oriented
  Analysis and Design](https://pt.slideshare.net/mksaad/structure-vs-object-oriented-analysis-and-design) (SlideShare);
- [Artigo Engenharia de Software 2 - Análise Orientada a Objetos](https://www.devmedia.com.br/artigo-engenharia-de-software-2-analise-orientada-a-objetos/9150) (DevMedia);
- [Orientação por Objetos: Vantagens e Desvantagens](https://wpjr2.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/orientacao-por-objetos-vantagens-e-desvantagens/) (wpjr2’s Weblog);
- [Desenvolvimento estruturado versus orientado a objetos.](http://www.deinf.ufma.br/~geraldo/dob/1.estruturadoversusorientadoaobjetos.pdf) (Prof. Geraldo Braz Junior, UFMA).