# Por que os códigos de orientação à objeto são diferentes do estrutural?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, programação-estruturada

Vejo códigos iguais que fazem a mesma coisa, ambos funcionam no **estrutural** e no **POO** (programação orientada a objetos), mas orientado à objeto é diferente do estrutural.

Por exemplo, no meu código tô usando

```
mysqli_fetch_row($res)
```

No POO é

```
$res->fetch_row()
```

Contudo eu tô usando o modo estrutural no **POO**, então surgiu a dúvida. Se funciona em ambos, por que existem dois tipos de programação na mesma linguagem? São iguais, apenas questão de opção?

Comment: O que seria "modo estrutural no POO"?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211768/tudo-que-consigo-fazer-em-poo-eu-consigo-fazer-em-pe \n https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213951/poo-%C3%A9-igual-em-todas-as-linguagens/213978#213978 \n https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368638/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-an%C3%A1lise-e-design-estruturado-e-orientada-a-objetos/369212#369212

Comment: Estrutural, exp: mysqli_fetch_row($res)
POO, exp: $res->fetch_row()

Quero basicamente saber a diferença entre os dois. Sei que um é usado em POO e o outro em estrutural, mas qual a diferença se posso usar ambos em ambos?

Além do mais, minha pergunta não é sobre misturar código orientado à objeto com estrutural, não entendi por que o "Essa pergunta já foi postada.."

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, o paradigma de programação é dependendo do que você vai fazer, existe momentos em que um paradigma vai ser melhor que outro. Creio que no estrutural não conseguimos fazer a abstração de um objeto da vida real para o código, mas, em um script usar POO nãos e faz necessário, não é opção na verdade é onde se encaixa melhor.

Comment: Minha pergunta parece ter ficado meio ambigua rsr
Eu estou aprendendo POO, consigo ver já a necessidade, mas oq não entendi é a diferença, não entre os paradigmas, mas entre os códigos.
Por exemplo:
mysqli_fetch_row($res) (Estrutural)

E  

$res->fetch_row() (POO)

Tem diferença?

Comment: Olhando na documentação a maior diferença entre eles são que na orientação a objetos ele é um método statico https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php e no procedural uma função https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php