# O que é um código macarrônico?

Tags: terminologia, estilo-de-codificação

Algumas vezes eu vejo alguns programadores usando esse termo. Código macarrônico se trata de um código ruim ou bagunçado? Não sei se ele tem alguma relação com [código espaguete](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_espaguete).

**Qual é o significado desses termos ?**

Comment: Acho que é a mesma coisa, tem essa pergunta [O que é código spaghetti?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/91)

Comment: @rray agora eu preciso descobrir se o código macarrônico e mesma coisa hehe , aparentemente sim , mas vou esperar mais um pouco.

Comment: código macarrônico deve ter sido alguma adaptação do termo sei lá eu ainda não sei se e mesma coisa kk

Comment: Eu votei como duplicata porque eles são sinônimos. Qualquer resposta aqui falará a mesma coisa que seria dito lá. N]ao tem porque existir duas perguntas abertas sobre o termo. Ainda que esta vá ajudar chegar naquela quando a pessoa pesquisar por "macarrônico".

Comment: Na verdade essa pergunta não deveria ter sido marcada como duplicada. Código spaghetti está relacionado ao fluxo de controle do código, como por exemplo o uso indevido do GOTO. Já o código macarrônico está relacionado a mistura de várias linguagens de programação em um mesmo documento. Eu queria postar a resposta correta aqui, mas essa questão foi marcada como duplicada, então não consigo mais postar uma resposta.

Comment: Eu votei para reabrir @Marcello era exatamente o que eu queria saber rs.

Comment: Ok. Não sei como ela pode ser reaberta, mas vamos esperar.

Comment: @Marcello Por que não apresentar essa visão lá naquela mesma pergunta?

Comment: Ok, deixei uma resposta lá.