# Conversão de fluxograma para código

Tags: c, loop, arduino, controle-de-fluxo, goto

Estou a tentar converter um fluxograma de tamanho considerável para código Arduino. O fluxograma é o seguinte:

[image: fluxograma]

Considerando o seu tamanho sentir-me-ia mais à vontade utilizando o comando `goto` como controlo de fluxo. No entanto sempre ouvi falar que a sua utilização é uma má prática de programação, uma vez que se torna fácil ficarmos perdidos no fluxo do programa e acabarmos com algo impossível de ser depurado.
Neste fluxograma em particular qual seria a melhor opção a utilizar, ciclos ou o comando `goto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanto faz. Afinal esse fluxograma é uma excrecência :) Coisa feita por quem não é programador.

Na verdade fluxogramas são horríveis. Eles serviram bem nos anos 50/60 em códigos bem pequenos. Até servem para dar uma instrução básica para um novato entender o fluxo de código. Na verdade eles são até razoáveis na mão de quem sabe usá-los. Não é o caso de quem fez esse. O erro começa pelo básico onde a pessoa só conhece dois blocos de execução. Ele está manco e é [macarrônico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/101). Tentei segui-lo e entortou minha cabeça :D

Fluxogramas incentivam o uso do `goto` (uma instrução que realmente [deve ser evitada, mas não abolida por completo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101). Ainda que seja possível fazer estruturadamente, é raro fazerem.

Pra seguir esse fluxograma realmente está mais fácil usar o `goto`. Se tentar transformar isso em blocos de controle mais estruturados, vai acabar mudando um pouco, ou muito, o que ele faz, ainda que o resultado, em tese, seja o mesmo.

Pra ser sincero, eu jogaria isto fora e faria outra coisa. Se essa for a única fonte de informação sobre o problema, eu interpretaria ele, entenderia o problema e faria um código sem se basear nesse fluxo.

Se não quiser seguir o conselho aí me parece ser melhor usar o `goto` mesmo, tentar modificar o fluxo de algo tão confuso pode dar problema demais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).