# O que é o problema dos filósofos glutões?

Tags: terminologia, concorrência, teoria-da-computação

Quando se fala em Programação concorrente, sempre citam 3 problemas clássicos/modelos de concorrência:

1. produtores e consumidores
2. leitores e escritores
3. filósofos glutões (ou jantar dos filósofos)

[Procurei aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Jantar+dos+fil%C3%B3sofos) porém em nenhum momento achei explicando o que é esse problema.

Minhas dúvidas então são:

- o que é o problema dos filósofos glutões? (mais focado no enunciado/metáfora do problema)
- o que o jantar dos filósofos modela de fato? (mais focado na coisa técnica do que é esse problema, deixando a metáfora de lado)
- qual a importância dele para um programador? quando um programador deve se preocupar diretamente com esse problema?
- existe alguma coisa real e cotidiana que nos esbarremos com esse problema sem termos conhecimento? sei lá, num banco de dados?

Comment: Pontos extras para quem conseguir explicar porque eles comem tanto

Comment: A questão aqui é, onde é que eles vão buscar tanta spaghetti?

Comment: @lazyFox, [será](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/64969)?!

Comment: Essas coisas sempre me fazem lembrar desse _deadlock_ na Avenida Brigadeiro Faria Lima com a Avenida Juscelino Kubitschek, não faz tanto tempo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/00DIk.jpg (_also_: http://mapio.net/pic/p-7122531/ )

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Isso é fácil, porque sendo filósofos usam a massa cinzenta e chega a um ponto que de tanto uso está pronta para comer  :)

Comment: Downvoter, poderia me dar o motivo para eu melhorar a questão?

Comment: @Everson com hashis faz muito mais sentido do que com garfos. Só quem comeu macarrão com hashi para saber. Ótima referência no assunto.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Jantar dos Filósofos**

Descrição do problema:

- Cinco filósofos estão sentados ao redor de uma
  mesa circular para o jantar.
- Cada filósofo possui um prato para comer macarrão.
- Além disso, eles dispõem de hashis, em vez de garfos
- Cada um precisa de 2 hashis
- Entre cada par de pratos existe apenas um hashi.
- Hashis precisam ser compartilhados de forma sincronizada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Regras do problema:

- Os filósofos comem e pensam, alternadamente
- Quando comem, pegam apenas um hashi por vez
- Se conseguir pegar os dois, come por alguns instantes e depois larga os hashis

**O X da questão**: Como evitar que fiquem bloqueados?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Soluções**

```c
#define N 5 /* número de filósofos */

void filosofo(int i) /* i: número do filósofo, de 0 até 4 */
{
    while(true){
         pense();  /* Filosofo está pensando */
         pegue_hashi(i); /* pegue o Hashi esquerdo */
         pegue_hashi((i+1) % N); /* pegue o Hashi direito; % é o operador módulo */
         coma(); /* yum-yum, spaghetti rs */
         largar_hashi(i) ; /* larga o hashi esquerdo*/
         largar_hashi((i+1) % N); /* larga o hashi direito */
    }
}
```

**O código acima funciona?**

Em `pegue_hashi()`: Se todos os filósofos pegarem o hashi da esquerda, nenhum pegará o da direita – **DEADLOCK**

Veja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E como solucionar?**

Após pegar o hashi da esquerda, o filósofo verifica se o da direita está
livre. Se não estiver, devolve o hashi que pegou, espera um pouco e tenta novamente.

**Qual o problema dessa solução?**

Se todos os filósofos pegarem o hashi da esquerda ao mesmo tempo:

- Verão que o da direita não está livre
- Largarão seu hashi e e esperarão
- Pegarão novamente o hashi da esquerda
- Verão que o da direita não está livre
- ... (Looping infinito)

**Então os problemas que deverão ser evitados**:

- Deadlock - todos os filósofos pegam um único hashi ao mesmo tempo
- [Starvation](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inani%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) – os filósofos ficam indefinidamente pegando hashis simultaneamente.

**E agora? O que eu preciso fazer?**

Poderíamos fazer com que eles esperassem um tempo aleatório

- Reduz a chance de starvation
- Na maioria das aplicações, tentar novamente não é problema
- Via ethernet, é exatamente isso que é feito com envio de pacotes
- E se esse processo é utilizado no controle de segurança em usina nuclear? Será uma boa ideia?

**Voltamos a outra pergunta**: Como evitar as múltiplas tentativas?

A utilização de semáforos solucionaria o problema, veja:

```c
#define N 5 /* número de filósofos */
semaphore mutex = 1;

void filosofo(int i) /* i: número do filósofo, de 0 até 4 */
{
    while(true){
         pense();  /* Filosofo está pensando */
         down(&mutex); /* requisita o semáforo */
         pegue_hashi(i); /* pegue o Hashi esquerdo */
         pegue_hashi((i+1) % N); /* pegue o Hashi direito; % é o operador módulo */
         coma(); /* yum-yum, spaghetti rs */
         largar_hashi(i) ; /* larga o hashi esquerdo*/
         largar_hashi((i+1) % N); /* larga o hashi direito */
         up(&mutex); /* Libera o semáforo para os outros */
    }
}
```

Teoricamente, é uma solução adequada na prática, contudo, tem um
problema de performance:

- Somente um filósofo pode comer em um dado momento
- Com 5 hashis, deveríamos permitir que 2 filósofos comessem ao mesmo tempo

**Mas afinal, como vou resolver sem deadlocks ou starvation e com o máximo de paralelismo para um número arbitrário de filósofos?**

Usar um arranjo – state – para identificar se um filósofo está comendo, pensando ou faminto (pensando em pegar os hashis).

- Um filósofo só pode comer (estado) se nenhum dos vizinhos estiver comendo
- Usar um arranjo de semáforos, um por filósofo
- Filósofos famintos podem ser bloqueados se os hashis estiverem ocupados

Reescrevendo o código:

```c
#define N 5 /* número de filósofos */
#define LEFT /* número do vizinho da ESQUERDA */
#define RIGHT /* número do vizinho da DIREITA */
#define PENSANDO 0 /* Filósofo está pensando */
#define FAMINTO 1 /* Filósofo está faminto */
#define COMENDO 2 /* Filósofo está comendo */
typedef int semaphore; /* o semáforo é um tipo especial de int  */
int state[N]; /* Array para acompanhar o estado de todos*/
semaphore mutex = 1; /* exclusão mútua para regiões críticas */
semaphore s[N]; /* um semáforo por filósofo */

void filosofo(int i) /* i: número do filósofo, de 0 até 4 */
{

   while(true){
      pense();  /* Filosofo está pensando */

      pegue_hashi(i); /* pegue os dois Hashis */

      coma(); /* yum-yum, spaghetti rs */

      largar_hashi(i) ; /* larga os dois Hashis */             
  }
}

void pegue_hashi(int i){ /* i: numero do filosofo, de 0 até N-1 */
   down(&mutex); /* entra na região crítica */
   state[i] = FAMINTO; /* recorda o fato que o filósofo i está faminto */
   testa(i); /* tenta adquirir as DUAS hashis */
   up(&mutex); /* sai da região crítica */
   down(&s[i]); /* bloqueie se os hashis não foram adquiridos */ 
}

void largar_hashi(i){ /* i: numero do filosofo, de 0 até N-1 */
   down(&mutex); /* entra na região crítica */
   state[i] = PENSANDO; /* recorda o fato que o filósofo i está faminto */
   testa(LEFT); /* veja se o vizinho da esquerda pode agora comer */ 
   testa(RIGHT ); /* veja se o vizinho da direita pode agora comer */
   up(&mutex); /* sai da região crítica */
}

void testa(i){ /* i: numero do filosofo, de 0 até N-1 */
   if(state[i] == FAMINTO && state[LEFT] != COMENDO && state[RIGHT] != COMENDO ){
      state[i] = COMENDO;
      up(&s[i]); /* libera se os hashis foram adquiridos */
    }
}
```

---

- O que o jantar dos filósofos modela de fato?

Útil para modelar processos que competem por acesso exclusivo a um número limitado de recursos.

- Qual a importância dele para um programador? quando um programador
  deve se preocupar diretamente com esse problema?

As vantagens da programação concorrente é o aumento do desempenho do programa, devido ao aumento da quantidade de tarefas que podem ser executadas durante um determinado período de tempo. O acesso concorrente a dados e recursos compartilhados pode criar uma situação de inconsistência desses mesmos recursos, isto porque as várias instâncias acessam e manipulam de uma forma simultânea, dando a situações de inconsistência e de falha. Então para que uma rotina ou programa seja consistente são precisos mecanismos que assegurem a execução ordenada e correta dos processos cooperantes.

Fonte da resposta:

- [Problemas Clássicos de Comunicação entre Processos](http://wiki.icmc.usp.br/images/7/76/Aula06_2.pdf)
- [THREADS, SEMÁFOROS E DEADLOCKS – O JANTAR DOS FILÓSOFOS](https://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/threads-semaforos-e-deadlocks-o-jantar-dos-filosofos/)

Comment: Parece que anda um serial downvoter por estas bandas. Tb recebi 1. Se calhar ele tinha o ecra ao contrario rs

Answer (score 24):

**Problema dos filósofos glutões (jantar dos filósofos):**

---

Imaginemos uma mesa redonda com 5 cadeiras e em cada uma das cadeiras está sentado um filósofo. 
Nessa mesa existem 5 pratos de spaghetti e 5 garfos, e em frente de cada prato de spagheti estará um filósofo.
No entanto, para poderem comer cada filósofo terá de usar 2 garfos.

Ou seja, com 5 garfos na mesa e 5 filósofos, só podem comer 2 filósofos ao mesmo tempo ficando 1 garfo de sobra.

Sendo que para estes poderem comer todos ao mesmo tempo seriam necessários 10 garfos.

[image: Jantar dos filósofos]

**Problema:**
Se todos quiserem comer e pegarem num garfo, cada filósofo terá um garfo mas nenhum deles
irá poder comer. Iremos ter um impasse, pois todos os filósofos irão ficar eternamente á espera do outro garfo, dando-se um deadlock. 
No contexto deste jantar acontece quando todos os filósofos são impedidos de comer, pois não têm condições 
para tal.

**DeadLock:** 
dá-se quando dois ou mais processos ficam impedidos de continuar, por
estarem á espera de um recurso que nunca estará disponível.

---

Em termos técnicos, cada filósofo representa um processo e cada garfo um recurso e dá-se uma competição por recursos, sendo por isso considerado um dos modelos de concorrência. Para evitar que isto aconteça é necessário sincronizar os processos, para que quando um estiver a utilizar um determinado recurso outro processo terá de esperar para usar esse mesmo recurso.

---

**Importância para um programador:**
Isto é uma situação importante para um programador, para este conseguir visualizar uma situação de deadlock e para perceber a importância do bom uso dos mecanismos de sincronização.

---

**Situações reais:**
A única situação real que encontrei é o caso dos sinais luminosos de trânsito, 
imaginemos que estes não estavam sincronizados, o que iria acontecer é que eventualmente estes iriam
ficar os dois verdes e iria haver acidentes, portanto é essencial que estes estejam sincronizados para 
evitar acidentes e para permitir um menor tráfego.

Fontes de pesquisa:

[Primeira](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Jantar-dos-Filosofos-Programacao-Paralela)

[Segunda](https://dicasdedevelop.wordpress.com/)

[Terceira](http://ces33.blogspot.pt/2009/05/o-problema-do-barbeiro-dorminhoco-com.html)

[Quarta](https://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/threads-semaforos-e-deadlocks-o-jantar-dos-filosofos/)

[Quinta](https://www.scribd.com/document/242344459/O-Problema-dos-Filosofos-Glutoes-pdf)

Comment: Seria interessante colocar um algoritmo para solução do problema, ou até mesmo um fluxograma / pseudo código.

Comment: É legal querer contribuir, mas nesses casos o legal seria pegar o material e explicar do seu jeito, usando as fontes referenciadas (mantendo os créditos, mesmo assim). Copy & Paste gera uma série de problemas, a começar por talvez nem todas as fontes permitirem reprodução.

Comment: @IdkWhy exatamente como o Bacco disse. Além de que, você não tem noção do tanto que se "aprende tentando ensinar"... você acha as vezes que sabe tão bem de algo, mas quando vai executar, pode não ser tudo aquilo ! é incrível !

Comment: @IdkWhy eu acho que seria mais legal você trabalhar no texto em vez de remover. Por exemplo, dar uma relida nas fontes, e explicar do seu jeito (mesmo que citando coisas dos links que você acrescentou, e é claro, mantendo-os).

Comment: Gostei, não tinha visto isso antes.

Answer (score 12):

O problema dos filósofos glutões já foi explicado pelo @idkWhy. 
Eu queria só complementar a resposta dele uma vez que na minha opinião 
há um pouco mais de conhecimento a ser retirado do problema proposto.

Esta resposta tem em conta outras narrativas que não fazem parte do problema tal como foi 
originalmente proposto em 1965 por Dijkstra. Normalmente o foco cai sempre para o 
problema de obtenção de recursos, contudo eu gostaria também de explorar narrativas 
onde não há qualquer problema na obtenção de recursos.

Tal como explicado, existem 5 garfos (um recurso, vamos imaginar um objecto de sincronização) 
na mesa e 5 filósofos (uma thread). Cada filosofo necessita de 2 garfos para comer. 
Como todos os filósofos estão esfomeados (as threads estão a executar código) 
cada filosofo pega num garfo (adquire o recurso).

#### 1. Filósofos bem comportados, sendo por este motivo um não problema

Mas até aqui ainda não existe qualquer problema, pois um filósofo tem a 
brilhante ideia de largar o seu garfo, em troca, o filosofo que quer o garfo dele 
paga-lhe o jantar (ou seja, as threads negoceiam com um arbritrador, quem deve obter o recurso). 
Assim que esse filosofo acabar de comer (libertar o recurso), todos os outros filósofos 
vão a correr procurando o garfo (adquirir o recurso). Como os filósofos 
são muito competitivos então eles decidiram que aqueles que conseguirem obter o 
garfo primeiro comem primeiro. Vamos dar um exemplo?

```
Filosofo = F
Garfo = G

F1 pega o G1
F2 pega o G2
F3 pega o G3
F4 pega o G4
F5 pega o G5

F2 decide largar o seu garfo.
F4 decidiu pagar o jantar a F2 
F4 obteve G2
F4 acabou de jantar e largou G2 e G4

F1, F2, F3, F5 vao pegar os garfos G2 e G4 o mais rapidamente possível.
Apenas dois deles terao sucesso.

A história repete-se de forma similar a quando F4 obteve o seu garfo, excepto que é de notar
que a medida que os filósofos vão acabando o seu jantar vai havendo mais garfos disponíveis.
```

Esta narrativa desnecessáriamente longa e complicada seria uma possível solução 
para que os filósofos possam comer e ilustra que lá por haver apenas 5 garfos para 
5 filósofos (e cada filosofo necessitar de dois garfos) não quer dizer que eles 
não possam jantar, claro está, num processo devidamente organizado.

#### 2. Identificação devida do problema

Então vamos fazer um narrativa dum processo não organizado, para identificar devidamente 
qual é o problema:

Os filósofos sentam-se á mesa e começam a pensar. Como eles estao esfomeados, 
assim que a comida chega á mesa, eles tentam pegar os 2 garfos perto de si.
Uns filósofos decidem comecar por pegar o garfo á esquerda e outros decidem pelo da direita.

Cenáro 1:
Logo por azar na primeira tentativa todos os filósofos obtiveram um só garfo e nunca
ningúem consguiu comer pois esperam eternamente que os outros filósofos deixem o seu garfo.

Cenário 2:
Um Filosofo consguiu obter 2 garfos mas assim que ele acaba de comer ele fica espamado com a 
confusao de todos os outros filósofos, eles estao á espera do garfo errado.

#### 2.1. Exemplificação do problema (c#)

```csharp
private static Random r = new Random(500);
private static int numeroFilosos = 200;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var garfos = Enumerable.Range(0, numeroFilosos)
        .Select(i => new Mutex(false))
        .ToArray();

    var filosofos = Enumerable.Range(0, numeroFilosos)
        .Select(i => new Thread(ComeOJantar)
        {
            IsBackground = false
        })
        .ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < filosofos.Length; i++)
    {
        //Os filosofos tem conhecimento dos garfos que estao ao seu lado
        filosofos[i].Start(Tuple.Create(garfos[i], garfos[(i+1)% filosofos.Length]));
    }
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    Parallel.ForEach(filosofos, f => f.Join());
    Console.WriteLine("Todos os filosofos comeram");
}

private static void ComeOJantar(object o)
{
    var dados = o as Tuple<Mutex, Mutex>;
    var garfo1 = dados.Item1;
    var garfo2 = dados.Item2;

    //Os filosofos obtem os garfos á pressa, uns obtem o da direita primeiro e outros
    //o da esquerda.
    if (r.NextDouble() > 0.5)
    {
        garfo1.WaitOne();
        garfo2.WaitOne();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        //Os filosofos também nao tem cuidado em qual garfo poisar primeiro
        garfo1.ReleaseMutex();
        garfo2.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    else
    {
        garfo2.WaitOne();
        garfo1.WaitOne();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        //Os filosofos também nao tem cuidado em qual garfo poisar primeiro
        garfo2.ReleaseMutex();
        garfo1.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

#### 3 Filósofos com etiqueta de mesa.

Mais uma vez exploramos um processo organizado. Desta vez os filósofos tem etiqueta de mesa e decidem pegar sempre o garfo da esquerda primeiro.

Contúdo ainda é possível que os filósofos obtenham apenas o garfo da esquerda. Por esse motivo, eles decidem largar o seu garfo e pensar por um tempo para que o seu vizinho, caso esteja interessado, possa obter o seu garfo

#### 3.1. Exemplo duma solucao, usando aquisição ordernada de recursos (c#)

**A solução anterior não tomava conta do caso onde os filósofos obtiam todos o garfo á sua esquerda**

```csharp
private static void ComeOJantar(object o)
{
    var dados = o as Tuple<Mutex, Mutex>;
    var garfoEsquerda = dados.Item1;
    var garfoDaDireita = dados.Item2;

    garfoEsquerda.WaitOne(); //os filosofos obtem o garfo da esquerda

    //este sleep serve apenas para efeitos ilustrativos
    //ele ajuda a simular a situação em que todos os filósofos 
    //conseguem obter o garfo da esquerda
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    //Os filosofos tentam agarrar o garfo da direita o mais rápidamente possivel
    //Contudo todos os garfos já estao ocupados
    while (!garfoDaDireita.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)))
    {
        //O filosofo decide largar o seu garfo e espera que o seu 
        //vizinho vá buscar o seu garfo
        garfoEsquerda.ReleaseMutex();

        //Este sleep faz parte da solução. 
        //Ele evita que o filosofo adquira o mesmo garfo imediatamente após o ter largado
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(r.Next(1, 5) * 100));

        garfoEsquerda.WaitOne();
    }
    //Neste momento os filosofos tem ambos os garfos e podem comer
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    garfoDaDireita.ReleaseMutex();
    garfoEsquerda.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

#### 4. Vitória vitória, acabou a história

A moral deste problema é que em ambientes concorrentes você tem que ter cuidado em que ordem você adquire recursos. Se você trabalha em ambientes de uma única thread (por exemplo nodejs) então você nunca terá problemas em relação a aquisição de recursos.

Em principio se voce usa um banco de dados transicional, o banco de dados resolve este problema por si. [Pelo menos o MSSQL resolve](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx).

> The SQL Server Database Engine automatically detects deadlock cycles
>   within SQL Server. The Database Engine chooses one of the sessions as
>   a deadlock victim and the current transaction is terminated with an
>   error to break the deadlock.

Em tradução livre:

A base de dados SQL server detecta *deadlocks* dentro do SQL Server. Ele escolhe uma das sessões como vitima de *deadlock* e a transacção actual é terminada com um erro para quebrar o *deadlock*

## TL;DR

1. O problema dos filósofos é um não problema, se o processo for devidamente organizado.
2. Para existir realmente problema é necessário haver aquisição de recursos de forma não ordeira
3. Em particular, a aquisição de recursos em ordem diferente é relatado e visualizado de forma relativamente simples
4. A moral da história é que normalmente será suficiente adquirir e libertar recursos na mesma ordem

Comment: Você conciderou que um não pode comer se outro do seu lado também estiver comendo !? Ou seja, sempre deve ser ímpares ou pares comendo ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @RBZ Esta solucao nao garante a maximizacao dos recursos. O que isto quer dizer é que mesmo que haja 5 garfos, podem nao estar 2 filosofos comendo ao mesmo tempo. Mas respondendo á sua pergunta, sim , considerei. Encontrou algum problema?

Comment: Você diz como no exemplo de ter um processo assíncrono. Mas mesmo que no início comecem comer 2 ao mesmo tempo, não significa que vão terminar no mesmo tempo correto !? Mas automaticamente passará ao próximo e ainda sim terão 2 comendo... sendo só 1 que seria o último a comer ou o mais demorado que pode até ser o 1o ainda !

Comment: @RBZ Deculpe, nao consegui perceber o que voce escreveu... Nem sei sequer ao certo de que parte da resposta está a falar.

Comment: Acho que esse problema dos filósofos, até por ser antigo, hoje ficou até em partes defasado e assim abre N suposições e N soluções. Aí ficamos com muitas formas de pensar, que até nos desencontramos ! rs

Comment: Sua resposta está bem completa. Acho que falta o exemplo cotidiano na vida de um programador (o quarto item das minhas perguntas). Sua resposta não dá ênfase no porquê um programador deveria se preocupar com esse problema, mas fala do assunto. (Mas, sim, sou chato, vou reclamar de falta de ênfase). E sua resposta foi além das minhas expectativas na criação da pergunta, não esperava propostas de solução.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Atualizei, até porque tinha uma solução errada também...

Answer (score 4):

> Resposta 2 (nova)

**Complementando** as respostas gerais, coloco um adendo, que ao meu ver é considerável, e também praticamente reforçando a minha primeira resposta:

Como dito na resposta do Bruno Costa, o problema em questão foi formulado por [Edsger W. Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) em 1965.

Com isso, voltando lá atrás onde não haviam inúmeras linguagens de programação como atualmente, e também recursos das linguagens mais limitados, realmente é um simples exercício para mostrar problemas nas sincronizações (como é dito na própria fonte).

Hoje com o grande leque de recursos e linguagens que temos, a questão fica em partes ramificadas por nós mesmos devido a idéias além do contexto proposto (um simples exercício de sincronização).

No Wikipedia, se tem toda a história e soluções do problema:

[Dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)

- Solução de hierarquia de recursos

Que foi a solução original proposta por Dijkstra, tratando os filósofos como processos e os garfos como recursos.

- Solução de arbitragem

Solução onde se tem um "árbitro" no contexto, por exemplo o garçom, que dará as permissões e ordens aos filósofos.

- Solução Chandy / Misra

Em 1984, K. Mani Chandy e J. Misra, deram a solução parecida a arbitrária, mas contando que os filósofos falassem entre si, utilizando "solicitações", ou seja, cada filósofo iria solicitar o garfo ao seu vizinho da direita e ao da esquerda, assim permitindo, teria as 2 ferramentas, e caso não conseguindo, poderia esperar a solicitação de outro e emprestar seu próprio garfo, não caindo em deadlock.

---

> Resposta 1 (antiga) [ -2 ]

Vou responder brevemente do meu ponto de vista, com minhas palavras, ou seja, a linha do pensamento é a mesma, mas as vezes claro que podemos ter outros caminhos.

o que é o problema dos filósofos glutões?

Ao meu ver, simplesmente uma ótima analogia, entre processo x recurso, tarefa x execução, ou até mais exemplos que conseguimos encaixar.

o que o jantar dos filósofos modela de fato?

Um problema bem bolado para uma questão lógica. Ainda que, se aplicado na lógica seria mais fácil de resolver, já que controlamos todos os caminhos.

qual a importância dele para um programador?

Primeiro de tudo, logo de início em "por onde começar a resolver a situação" e após, quais as formas, e qual a melhor.

quando um programador deve se preocupar diretamente com esse problema?

Aí que está o "X" da questão ao meu ver. Entendo que, bem resumidamente, devemos sempre ter bem definido o algoritmo, para não entrar no deadlock, como na resposta acima.

Ou seja, a importância da definição de prioridades, em breve exemplo, uma lista de tarefas que devem ser realizadas mas depende cada uma de outra (seriam os filósofos, que dependem dos garfos), e então se todos precisam ser executados, qual é o prioritário, ou seja, que tem o poder de passar na frente ? Ou por exemplo, numa escala de 0 a 100, qual é o nível da prioridade daquele ?

existe alguma coisa real e cotidiana que nos esbarremos com esse problema sem termos conhecimento? sei lá, num banco de dados?

Um exemplo com banco: O que é deadlock no SQL Server?

Se alguém entende diferente, por favor, comente !

Comment: Não discordo do conteúdo, mas da forma. Minha intenção era que a pergunta "o que é o problema dos filósofos glutões?" fosse descrever o enunciado de maneira intuitiva deles comendo macarrão. Já o que você respondeu nessa pergunta se aproxima do que eu pretendia como resposta de "o que o jantar dos filósofos modela de fato?"

Comment: A importância para o programador ficou meio vaga, acho que você consegue fazer melhor =] Já os dois últimos pontos estão ótimos, não vejo críticas apenas elogios

Comment: Nossa aí a resposta ficaria gigantesca se for fazer do ponto de vista pessoal, com cada tópico que você colocou ! rs Vou acompanhar dos demais também, quem sabe mais pra frente eu faço como você disse. Desculpe não entender antes. ;)

Comment: Não fica tão grande assim. Estou ansioso esperando a sua atualização. Qualquer coisa vou atrás de chamar mais atenção para receber mais postagens