# O que é starvation (inanição)?

Tags: terminologia, teoria-da-computação

Algumas condições podem impedir o progresso da execução de processos ou threads, duas dessas condições são chamadas `dead-lock` e `live-lock`, onde o que extraí de informação foi que, `dead-lock` remete a processos que estão bloqueando um ao outro, impedindo a execução flua e `live-lock` remete a processos que impedem uns aos outros de progredir, mas que não interrompem a execução.

Não ficou muito claro para mim, e creio que seria interessante tocar no assunto, talvez mais pessoas se interessem e por isso trouxe a questão para cá.

- Como isso funciona?
- Em que cenário isso é útil? ou até mesmo pode atrapalhar?
- Podem dar algum exemplo disso?

Answer (score 5):

Starvation é um conceito que não se refere a diretamente a deadlock/livelock.

Starvation é quando um processo não consegue ser executado, de forma alguma, pois sempre existem processos de prioridade maior para serem executados, de forma que o processo "faminto" nunca consiga tempo de processamento.

Segue o diagrama de estados de processo no Linux.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você executa um processo, ele começa no estado `initial` e então vai para o `ready`.

O Starvation ocorre quando processos de maior prioridade aparecem sempre que tem um processo de menor prioridade ativo e querendo chamar o kernel. Nesse caso, os processos mais prioritários ficam com acesso ao kernel e o outro processo fica apenas esperando permissão, que nunca chega.

Ele não consegue agir e fica parado, sem fazer nada, ocupando memória e tempo de processamento (visto que o SO tem que fazer o escalonamento dos processos!) do processador sem fazer nada.

Starvation sempre atrapalha, pois é tempo de processador/tempo de kernel/memória disperdiçado(a), pois é um processo querendo ser executado e que fica em memória, mas nunca consegue definitivamente concluir o seu fluxo.

O escalonador de processos do Windows, se não estou enganado, ele faz uso de um sistema de prioridades dinâmico, onde o processo começa com a sua prioridade normal, mas conforme ele vai ficando parado, a sua prioridade começa a aumentar de forma que ele eventualmente veja um tempo de kernel.

(Qualquer erro, por favor corrijam)

Comment: Você mata uma requisição (pode ser qualquer cabeça de execução, como processo, _thread_ ou o que for) de fome quando não permite que ela siga em frente e não o assassina. Isso significa que pode, inclusive, ocorrer em um único processo concorrente consigo mesmo. Por exemplo, em um cruzamento com preferencial, e você estiver no `PARE` e tenha um fluxo intenso e infinito na preferencial, o processo do seu carro sofrerá _starvation_. O mesmo pode acontecer com leitores e escritores se o sistema sempre der a preferência aos leitores e nunca a algum escritor

Comment: Essa resposta sobre o [problema dos filósofos glutões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285313/64969) fala sobre inanição. Inclusive, achei muito bem humorado o jeito como foi apresentado