# Conceito de deadlock em Java

Tags: java, terminologia, concorrência

Me deparei com o termo deadlock em Java. Mas, não consigo compreendê-lo. Assim, gostaria de fazer estas perguntas:

- O que é um deadlock?
- Por que e como evitar um deadlock?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283375/64969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Deadlock* é a dependência cíclica que acontece entre duas ou mais *threads* compartilhando dois ou mais recursos (variável, bloco de código etc.). Em outras palavras, uma *thread* `T1` depende de outra `T2`, sendo que esta `T2` depende, por sua vez, de `T1`.

Esse tipo de dependência acontece exclusivamente por falha na lógica implementada pelo programador, que, quando desenvolve uma aplicação *multithreaded*, precisa se preocupar não apenas com *deadlock*, mas com outros conceitos relativos a programação concorrente, como *starvation*, *livelock* e *race condition*, sendo este último provavelmente o mais comum de acontecer.

Um exemplo de [código](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_deadlock.htm) no qual ocorre *deadlock*:

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");

            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");

            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock2) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");

            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");

            synchronized (Lock1) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Quando a aplicação é executada e ambas as *threads* iniciadas, `T1` adquire o *lock* (como se fosse uma exclusividade de acesso), representado pela palavra `synchronized`, sobre o objeto `Lock1`. Ou seja, até que `T1` libere o *lock* sobre este objeto (quer dizer, até que o bloco de código dentro de `synchronized` seja completamente executado), nenhuma outra *thread* pode acessá-lo. Pode-se perceber que dentro desse primeiro bloco `synchronized`, há uma outra tentativa de *lock* (representado  pelo outro bloco `synchronized`), desta vez sobre `Lock2`. Isso quer dizer, trocado em miúdos, que o *lock* original sobre o objeto `Lock1` só vai ser liberado se a *thread* `T1` conseguir também o *lock* sobre `Lock2` e executar o código dentro desse segundo bloco. Resumindo, neste ponto do código `T1` tem *lock* sobre `Lock1` e **PRECISA** do *lock* sobre `Lock2` para terminar sua rotina e liberar todos os recursos para outras *threads*.

Por sua vez, `T2`, quando é iniciada, adquire o *lock* sobre `Lock2` e, para finalizar sua execução e liberar os recursos, **PRECISA** do *lock* sobre `Lock1`.

Com esse panorama, fica fácil perceber o que está ocorrendo: a *thread* `T1` lockou o objeto `Lock1` e precisa ganhar o *lock* sobre `Lock2` para finalizar, mas `T2` já lockou `Lock2` e para terminar precisa ganhar o *lock* sobre `Lock1`, que por sua vez está lockado por `T1`. Eis a dependência cíclica, ou *deadlock*. O output desse código ao ser executado:

```
Thread 1: Holding lock 1...
Thread 2: Holding lock 2...
Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...
Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...
```

Neste ponto, sua aplicação está em permanente estado de espera e assim ficará para sempre e esse é o motivo de você não querer nunca um `deadlock`.

E aí vem a pergunta: como corrigir o código para que ele não ocorra? Basta inverter a ordem dos objetos dos quais se quer o *lock*. Ou seja: ambas as *threads* vão tentar primeiro lockar o objeto `Lock1` (e, conseguindo, também lockar `Lock2`), executar o código e finalizar, permitindo então que a próxima *thread* adquira o *lock* e execute também seu devido código:

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");

            try {
               Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");

            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1...");

            try {
               Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 2...");

            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Executando, eis o *output*:

```
Thread 1: Holding lock 1...
Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...
Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...
Thread 2: Holding lock 1...
Thread 2: Waiting for lock 2...
Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...
```

E sua aplicação estará pronta para continuar executando o que quer venha a seguir.