# É possível mesclar Java com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java

Por exemplo, se eu tenho uma função `soma(a, b)` em JavaScript e eu queira usar essa função em um código Java, é possível? Se sim, como?

JavaScript:

```js
function soma(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Java:

```java
public class SomaJS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = args[0];
        int b = args[1];
        int res = soma(a, b); // Função JavaScript

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade disso?

Comment: Eu quis dar um exemplo simples para não complicar as coisas, mas só o fato de juntar Java e JavaScript por si só é bastante útil não acha?

Comment: Não é o mais funcional, para nenhuma das linguagens. Mesmo que seja possível, é improvável que se tenha algum ganho real com isso

Comment: Então poderia por favor me ajudar a dar um exemplo melhor? Eu não sei como relacionar de forma eficiente esses dois, já que nem ao menos sei como mesclá-los.

Comment: Exemplo: você tem uma função de acesso a banco de dados usando PHP e PDO, e você quer usar essa função em um servidor node.js. Mesmo que seja possível, é gambiarra, e no futuro vai se transformar em [macarrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31315/o-que-%c3%a9-c%c3%b3digo-spaghetti), ou  te dar uma certificação de [Especialista Sênior em XGH](https://sou.gohorseprocess.com.br/extreme-go-horse-xgh/)

Comment: Em resumo @NinjaTroll: não faça isso. Vai se transformar em um monstro que vai te devorar...

Comment: Haha, então acho que a pergunta fica mais por curiosidade, valeu pelos conselhos

Comment: Chamar a função diretamente no código, como vc colocou, provavelmente não dá. Talvez o máximo que dê pra fazer é [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22856279). De qualquer forma, acho que vale repensar porque vc quer fazer isso. Tem grandes chances de ser um [problema X/Y](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/112052) e de ter uma solução melhor :-)

Comment: Isso resolve a pergunta, só teria que traduzir e responder aqui. Ok :D

Comment: Tem uma discussão sobre isso no [ fórum do GUJ](https://www.guj.com.br/t/java-com-javascript/65391/6), além de que, aparentemente, [dá pra misturar scripts ao seu código Java](https://www.guj.com.br/t/java-6-permitira-misturar-scripts-com-codigo-java/5895/3). Não recomendo nenhum dos dois usos, mas fica pela curiosidade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A não ser que você encontre algum projeto mantido de runtime de javascript que rode na JVM,  a única forma de fazer isso é ter dois processos separados, com um deles atuando num modo de "escuta" - aí é possível usar  algum protocolo de "rpc" - "Remote Procedure Call" que funcione em ambas as linguagens.

Mas parece que foram feitos vários projetos de rodar javascript direto na JVM - uma busca rápida no google retorna "Rhino", "RingoJS", "Nashorn" e "Graal.js" - a página da wikipepedia sobre liguagens na JVM indica maiores informações para 3 desses 4 projetos: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages
Em qualquer um deles deve ter uma forma de tanto expor uma função de javascript para ser chamada a partir do Java, como de instanciar objetos e chamar métodos escritos em Java a partir do Javascript.

A outra forma, como citado acima, é usar um protocolo de RPC - uma forma de computação em que seus objetos sejam serializados em um processo, na lingagem cliente, recebidos e processados num worker na outra linguagem, e devolvidos pelo mesmo canal (ou um parecido).

Construir uma arquitetura dessas para um único sistema monolítico seria possível, mas temerário - por outro lado, em paradigmas de sistemas distruibuidos, e microserviços, que são bem usáveis,é exatamente isso que acontece. 
Os métodos chamados podem estar expostos de forma mais conveninente (parecendo exatamente uma chamada de função), ou menos conveniente (você tem que preparar manualmente um payload para o protocolo de transporte, que pode ser HTTP ou outro, e conferir o resultado da chamada de rede, ter um ponto de callback pra receber o resultado, etc...) mas com microserviços você de forma alguma está limitado a apenas uma linguagem entre dois serviços que se comunicam.

Então é basicamente escolher um protocolo de chamada remota (rest, SOAP, graphQL, xmlrpc, jsonrpc, developer kit de SQS da Amazon, developer kit de Pubsub do google, redis, rabbitMQ, Cap'n Proto, Google protocol buffers,   ou qualquer protocolo que seja uma camada acima desses que esteja disponível tanto em Java quanto em Javascript e  ir por esse caminho.

(eu poderia colocar cada um desses termos no google, e colocar um link aqui, mas dá para quem estiver interessado em estudar fazer isso).

A maioria desses protocolos permite o deploy em servidores separados, mas também vão funcionar na mesma máquina. Alguns, como os que usam infraestrutura da Amazon ou do Google, podem precisar de um emulador da aplicação de comunicação para funcionar local - mas esse emulador, via de regra, vai estar disponível como uma imagem docker, então até isso é tranquilo.

Comment: Uau que resposta incrível! Nem imaginava que dava pra fazer essas coisas

Comment: desculpa  - eu realmente gostaria de colocar alguns exemplos, mas ia me tomar muito tempo - mas sim, dá pra fazer tudo isso. Há bastante tempo atrás (uns 10 anos) eu pesquisei um tanto disso de chamar uma linguagem a partir de outra, mas sempre envolvendo Python, que é minha "casa". Hoje, no entanto, a ideia de microserviços permite qualquer-linguagem pra qualquer linguagem  - e é so voce procurar um tutorial de Google Pubusb, ou Amazon SQS pra ver como fazer.

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer uma resposta de rodar Java **sobre** JavaScript: uma visão diferente da que você apresenta aqui. Enquanto aqui você está falando sobre JS em cima da JVM, eu gostaria de mostrar como rodar Java em cima de um motor de JS qualquer. E, obviamente, sem RPC envolvida, caso contrário não teria graça =) Quem sabe no final do dia eu consiga fazer essa resposta?

Comment: O runtime do Python compila, com a LLVM para webassembly, e pode rodar num browser ou no node - o projeto é esse aqui: https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide -  a mesma abordagem pode ser feita para qualquer runtime do Java - possivelmente exista alguma. Nesse caso trata-se do runtime original, que é executado em javascript como se os opcodes do webassembly fossem uma CPU. Não tem por que não funcionar - pode ser que seja complicado só de acertar os detalhes da compilação de algum runtime do Java.

Comment: mas - rodar uma JVM em cima de um runtime javascript é uma coisa - ter uma interface nessa JVM para interagir com o namespace do Javascript (e possivelmente com o DOM da página hospedeira) é outra - aí tem que ter código específico. Vamos ver se tem algum projeto legal por aí - aguardando seus experimentos!