# Como programar em java e python junto

Tags: java, python, json

Vejo vários programas e sistemas que são programados em várias linguagens, como por exemplo o android. Eu estou tentando programar em java junto ao python, mas não acho nada sobre isso. Ja tentei juntar as informações em json para trabalhar, mas não parece algo muito bom para se usar. Alguém consegue me ajudar

Comment: O que exatamente precisa fazer em Java e o que precisa fazer em Python?

Comment: Como java tem vários recursos achei melhor colocar ele como gerenciador de input, e python como é bom para IA estou usando para output. Pois acho difícil fazer IA em java

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: Python não é bom em IA, nada. Python pegou fama de ser bom em IA, é diferente. Java pode tudo o que Python pode fazer em IA. Achar difícil é outra questão. Tudo é mais difícil fazer em Java. É uma linguagem que afasta amadores, exige um pouco mais que a pessoa realmente aprenda programar.

Comment: É que estou familiarizado com IA em python diferente de java

Comment: Maniero: "Python é bom em IA" - quando 90% dos frameworks para IA disponiblizam suas APIs e documentação primariamente em Python. A premissa de Python sempre foi facilitar a interface, e deixa o que é computacionalemtne intensivo ser executado em código nativo.

Comment: Se lhe for útil, eu votei para fechar porque acho vago demais uma pergunta do tipo "como uso X e Y juntos". Dependendo o objetivo, a resposta variará ou até a recomendação será "não use". Abordar todos os contextos possíveis na resposta costuma ser inviável e há uma grande chance da resposta ser um "chute" sobre o contexto da pergunta. Se o chute for errado, será uma resposta inválida, que só o autor da pergunta poderá avaliar. Por isso comentei questionando quais eram os objetivos e se a pergunta for editada complementando isso eu reavaliarei meu voto de fechamento.

Comment: Considero ser uma pergunta completamente válida, mas não no formato atual. Discordo dela receber três votos negativos, pois ela não é, na totalidade, ruim; mas também discordo dela receber três votos positivos, pois na sua forma atual a pergunta não é suficiente.

Comment: Por exemplo, uma forma melhorada poderia ser "*Eu gostaria de fazer ... em Java porque ..., mas gostaria de fazer ... em Python porque ..., como eu posso integrar essas duas linguagens para que isso seja possível?*"

Comment: @Woss como você deve saber as pessoas votam por ser engraçadinha, curioso, também queria a opinião, normalmente enviesada, de alguém sobre o assunto porque eu quero fazer igual já que não tenho capacidade de tomar as próprias decisões. Então a pergunta é fora de escopo, é baseada em opinião, não clara e ampla. E de fato a resposta dada não responde a pergunta, mesmo que curiosa, dar o que as pessoas **querem ouvir**. Em geral só acha bom esse tip ode pergunta quem só responde e não participa da comunidade e não vê o monte de problema que iso costuma gerar ,mesm oque algum caso não gere.

Comment: Ok - só me ajude a entender como esta resposta "não responde a pergunta"? As primeiras duas linhas dela já respondem a pergunta. O restante vai além, incluindo outros casos de uso, inclusive o uso no mercado, em larga escala.  O AP aprovou como respondida. O que poderia ser mais objetivo que "o projeto Jython (link incluso) permite o uso de Python e Java no mesmo programa." ?

Comment: "Como programar em java e python junto?" a pergunta é esta e ele quer que ajude ele fazer algo não descrito. Isto nem dá para responder, no mínimo precisa de um capítulo de um livro. Dizer que tem uma ferramenta que pode ser usada não responde a pergunta feita. Ainda mais que depois a resposta diz "para o seu caso não dá para usar o que eu falei que dá para usar no começo". Isto é um bom comentário, não é resposta. Nós temos uma definição do que é resposta e do que é um comentário, por isso uma pergunta assim é fechada, ela não é adequada para uma resposta, para um comentário é.

Comment: Aceitar resposta é justamente o que eu disse, a pessoa ouviu o que ela queria ouvir, mesmo que a prejudique, mesmo que a leve para um caminho ruim. Por isso essas respostas não são boas. Não estou entrando no mérito da resposta específica porque estou julgando a pergunta, e ela dá muita margem para ter uma resposta que leva a pessoa para o caminho errado, o caminho que é do interesse de alguém. Muitas vezes a pessoa aceita porque é o que tem, ou até pra fazer birra, acontece muito quando tem alguém que diz o contrário do que ela quer ouvir.

Comment: Responder ou aceitar algo ruim acontece quando a pessoa não conhece bem o funcionamento do site. A pergunta é uma das piores já postadas no site, não é uma questão de estar em uma linha tênue. Claro que ela pode ser refeita e ter um propósito, claro, objetivo, que leve a algum lugar, e aí mereça uma resposta. Este caso não merece, e o fato da resposta ter sido postado burlando o fechamento não colabora. Foi um "vai na marra".

Comment: É bem simples de entender o problema até. Da forma como foi feita podem surgir inúmeras respostas usando Java e Python, todas com cenários, pressupostos e finalidades completamente sem relação entre si.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existe uma implementação de Python 2 chamada "[Jython](https://www.jython.org/)" - ela permite que você execute código Python dentro do ambiente da JVM, importando e instanciando classes em Java normalmente.

Isso é o que normalmente se entende por "programar Python e Java junto".

Agora, há a abordagem sistemas distribuídos - em que sistemas independentes compartilham dados e eventos por meios de comunicação como requisições web, gerenciadores de fila (redis, Amazon SQS, etc...)  para trabalhar em conjunto. O uso do "JSON" entraria aí: ele é um protocolo de serialização comum para troca de dados entre os sistemas nesses casos. Normalmente essas aplicações que trabalham junto são o que empresas fazem para realizar seus negócios - é comum uma empresa ter um eco-sistema com aplicativos em várias linguagens diferentes.

Tem bastante mais informação e detalhes dessas abordagens nesta resposta:
[É possível mesclar Java com JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427674/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-mesclar-java-com-javascript/427694#427694)

Agora, dado seu esclarecimento:

> Como java tem vários recursos achei melhor colocar ele como
>   gerenciador de input, e python como é bom para IA estou usando para
>   output. Pois acho difícil fazer IA em java

FIca claro que suas premissa sobre as vantagens do Java nesse caso estão incorretas. O que seriam "vários recursos"?
Dá para garantir com tranquilidade que quaisquer "vários recursos" para interface, e entrada e saída de dados, seja num sistema Web, seja no terminal, e até mesmo num aplicativo desktop, são mais fáceis em Python (e isso pode até mesmo ser demonstrado objetivamente: o número de detalhes da linguagem, classes, interfaces que você vai ter que saber pra criar seu app em Python, em relação a Java, vai  ser quase uma ordem de grandeza menor).

Se o seu interesse é chegar a um aplicativo para sistemas Android, a escolha óbvia é fazer uso do PyQT5, com [pyqtdeploy](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/) para criar o APK. Não sei quanto bem as bibliotecas de IA em si vão funcionar no Android, e se o pyqtdeploy vai conseguir empacota-las corretamente. Uma alternativa é ter a parte de IA em um servidor remoto, como backend, e aí você cria o App Android ou iOS na tecnologia que achar melhor (esse já é um caso de sistema distribuído, como acima)

Por outro lado, a sua premissa em relação a linguagem Python - de que nesse momento do tempo, a maior parte das ferramentas e frameworks para desenvolvimento de IA tem interfaces, exemplos, e documentação em Python está correta.

A solução para você então é: esqueça o Java por agora. Se em algum ponto você tiver uma razão objetiva para usar Java (por exemplo, integrar uma parte de IA em um sistema grande já existente), você volta se procupar com isso.

E, por fim, o Jython não tem um eco-sistema em que as ferramentas de IA do Python estão replicadas - alguns provavelmente até podem funcionar, mas vão perder eficiência - e vai ter pouca documentação. Além do quê ele usa Python 2. A abordagem para esse caso seria de sistemas distribuídos mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado por responder minha pergunta. Diferente de algumas pessoas que só criticaram. Muito obrigado. Provavelmente não vou me dar bem por esse comentário.

Comment: Criticaram para melhorar o conteúdo da pergunta e entender o que quer, não há problema em receber críticas, o problema é não melhorar com elas

Comment: O primeiro comentário a sua pergutna, nao foi uma crítica. Já o fechamento da pergunta pelo moderador, eu já tentei conversar com ele - não adianta. Ou é uma pergunta com exemplo de código e só uma dúvida pontual, ou é fechada.  A rede em inglês do stackeschange tem outros sites sem ser o stackoverflow, que permitem perguntas mais genéricas sobre t.i.  e aprendizado - a única forma de essa pergutna estar 100% alinhada seria achar o site exato aqui (https://stackexchange.com/sites), e nem eu sei dizer qual - prefiro ser um pouco mais tolerante no que são dúvidas válidas.

Comment: Dá uma lida no manual que colocaram nos comentários, é muito importante entender como o site funciona para se dar bem aqui

Comment: @Denis: não - de acordo com a interpretação rígida que tem sido dadas as orientações pra perguntas aqui pelo moderador (e segundo ele, é a vontade dos "participantes mais efetivos"), essa pergunta não teria como ser feita aqui, não importa o quanto fosse melhorada - a nao ser que o AP trouxesse vários exemplos já quase funcionando, de sistemas em Python e Java se comunicando.

Comment: @jsbueno não sei se vc não entendeu mesmo quando fala certas coisas do outro moderador, que não procedem sobre o que o autor teria que fazer para reabrir o post (vou presumir boa fé, como obrigação de moderador). O quadro azul é bem claro, um convite a melhorar o post. O fechamento para perguntas que não tem como ser recuperadas é outro.

Comment: @jsbueno "essa pergunta não teria como ser feita aqui, não importa o quanto fosse melhorada - a nao ser que o AP trouxesse vários exemplos já quase funcionando, de sistemas em Python e Java se comunicando" – isso não é verdade. Mas a pergunta precisa ser melhorada para ser reaberta. Por que você não colabora e edita você mesmo? A sua resposta já foi meio caminho andado na salvação da pergunta.