# O tamanho de uma função afeta a performance e consumo de memória?

Tags: php, funções, desempenho, memória, estilo-de-codificação

O fato de uma função ser maior ou menor afeta a performance da aplicação? Especialmente em PHP. Se precisar de performance, seria melhor funções grandes ou pequenas?

E o consumo de memória é afetado se uma função grande dá lugar a diversas funções pequenas?

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo feita porque era o que o autor da pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30772/101 queria. Ele não conseguiu dizer isto com clareza, as pessoas responderam outra coisa, ele clarificou nos comentários (agora apagados) e se recusou a fazer uma nova pergunta. Como a informação pode ajudar ele e outras pessoas, está postado. Espero que outras pessoas possam colaborar com novas respostas.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sempre *pode* afetar a performance. Depende um pouco da tecnologia usada. Da linguagem, da implementação. O mesmo vale para o consumo de memória.

Mas este "pode" é relativo. Vou evitar [falar sobre o conteúdo da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30772/101) e me ater puramente ao tamanho dela. Mas não se esqueça que a preocupação do tamanho deve ser mais relevante para facilitar o *design* e entendimento por parte dos programadores.

## Performance

No passado a existência de muitas funções atrapalhava muito a performance e fazia todo sentido fazer funções "linguições". Hoje o *hardware* ajuda e os compiladores costumam fazer otimizações que eliminam o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) de chamadas de funções criadas só para manter o código mais organizado. Claro que o custo da chamada a uma função não é zero e nem sempre as otimizações são possíveis. Há casos que a otimização é possível mas não é viável ou pelo menos necessária (funções que possuem *loops* não [desenrolados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186216/101) em código *flat* provavelmente não sofrerão a otimização de [*inline*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101) que substitui a chamada pelo seu próprio código). Mas também é certo que não são tantos casos onde isto realmente é relevante.

Por outro lado funções pequenas podem facilitar a melhor utilização do cache de código no processador (isto varia de processador para processador) e em alguns casos pode afetar positivamente a performance. Novamente, não costuma ser muito relevante na maioria dos casos.

Isso varia de acordo com a implementação e em [linguagens dinâmicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21513/101) costuma ser menos relevante ainda.

Essa preocupação já pode ser considerada uma [micro-otimização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30277/101) em qualquer linguagem. Mas pode não ser em casos específicos. Em PHP provavelmente é, apesar de ser uma das linguagens mais lentas para chamadas de função. Se alguém realmente precisa de performance, porque vai escolher PHP? PHP é ótima para resolver vários problemas, tem suas virtudes mas entre elas não está a velocidade. PHP é uma das linguagens *mainstream* mais lentas que existem, o problema não está só na chamada das funções.

Otimizações que envolvam a escolha certa de algoritmos e estruturas de dados são importantes. Em alguns casos saber alguma deficiência da implementação e tentar contornar pode ser uma micro-otimização aceitável, mas quebrar uma função em pequenas partes ou fazer um "linguição" dificilmente trará qualquer resultado relevante em PHP. Provavelmente nem vale testar para ver o que acontece. Mas se alguém tiver dados que mostrem isso, não deixará de ter sua utilidade pelo menos para ter certeza que não muda nada relevante.

## Memória

O espaço ocupado em memória para o código pode ser um pouco maior se tiver várias funções ao invés de uma. Mas isso é irrisório na maioria dos casos. Em PHP mais ainda. E otimizações podem fazer com que o que pareça intuitivo se mostre o oposto. Por outro lado funções menores podem ser distribuídas em vários arquivos e menos código seria interpretado desnecessariamente. Isso geraria um ganho de performance na interpretação do *script* PHP. É um ganho que não está totalmente relacionado com o tamanho da função. Mas novamente, o ganho provavelmente não será relevante.

O espaço ocupado na *[stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)* também pode variar um pouco em alguns casos. Claro que chamar separadamente funções pequenas que não vão sendo empilhadas na *stack*, ou seja, quando uma termina (fazendo o *pop* na pilha), volta para sua chamadora e uma nova função é invocada (fazendo um *push*), tende a ocupar um pouco menos de espaço da *stack* (note que o tamanho da *stack* em si, costuma ser fixo, portanto o consumo da memória total nunca é alterado neste caso), mas é irrisório. Se você está correndo o risco de estourar a capacidade da *stack* há algo muito errado na sua aplicação e diretamente não é porque fez uma função muito grande ou muitas pequenas.

As variáveis alocadas em *stack* costumam ser bem pequenas. São valores primitivos que cabem no registrador do processador, incluindo ponteiros para objetos existentes no *heap*. Em linguagens onde é possível determinar grandes volumes de alocação na *stack*, o programador precisa saber o que está fazendo e saber que precisa desalocar ou encerrar um escopo para forçar a liberação da *stack*. Uma das formas para encerrar o escopo é encerrar a função, mas não precisa ser assim. Mesmo estes casos são raros.

O mais comum é a linguagem ter um *garbage collector* e os tipos existentes na linguagem têm semântica que determina o que deve estar na *stack* e o que deve estar no *heap*. O escopo pode determinar se um objeto no *heap* deve ser eliminado logo ou não. E já sabemos que o fim da função é uma possibilidade de fim de escopo. Então funções menores, que contenham menos variáveis, em tese, podem economizar memória. Mas vamos analisar melhor.

- Se o gerenciamento da memória é manual sabemos que é uma decisão do programador quando remover objetos do *heap* e ele tem liberdade para liberar a memória quando ele bem entender. O tamanho e quantidade de funções não costumam influenciar em nada.
- Quando se usa alguma forma de gerenciamento automático da memória, provavelmente usando uma contagem de referência, o fim do escopo é fundamental para a liberar o *heap* ocupado à partir deste escopo (que pode ser a função). Então pode ser que ter uma função menor, ajude reduzir o consumo de memória. Você tem ali só as variáveis necessárias para aquela parte do problema. Claro que se você devolver de alguma forma um valor de variável desta função para a chamadora que passa para outra funções, ou seja, a contagem de referência não zera, o objeto permanece lá. Na maior parte das vezes isto não importa muito. Mesmo quando importa é preciso estar ciente de todas as implicações do que está fazendo. E note que em geral a liberação é feita no fim do escopo que pode ser o fim da função ou não.

  Dividir uma função em várias pequenas para liberar mais rápido a memória pode não ser a solução se a memória está "atolada". Pode até criar complicações que dificultem a solução.

  Se realmente há um recurso que está ocupando muito do *heap* e não está sendo usado provavelmente é possível liberá-lo atribuindo `null` para a variável. De qualquer forma se você tem variáveis que não são mais usadas em parte de uma função, é provável que ela esteja fazendo mais do que uma coisa, é um [problema de organização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31473/101).
- Se usa o GC rastreador, que é cada vez mais comum na maioria das linguagens, a memória só será liberada quando for necessário, então tem menos relevância ainda. Ainda assim você pode precisar de uma liberação enquanto está dentro de uma função. Cai no mesmo problema anterior. A única solução é forçar uma liberação da variável que referencia um objeto para que o GC libere o *heap*. Não precisa terminar a função para isto. Claro que em uma função menor é mais difícil acontecer um problema assim, mas provavelmente o problema não é a memória, é o *design*.

Não tenho dados sobre o PHP mas se estiver com problemas de memória você provavelmente tem problemas que independem do tamanho da função. Tem que entender outras coisas que estão sendo feitas erradas. O PHP não deve ser usado para problemas que precisem de um cuidado especial com memória ao ponto que determinar o tamanho da função seja fundamental para alcançar o resultado adequado.

Lembre-se que o *design* muito fragmentado pode dificultar o rastreamento manual ou automático e acabar segurando dados no *heap* mais tempo que o necessário.

## Conclusão

Em PHP é fácil responder que não, pelo menos não de forma relevante. Não escolha funções pequenas ou grandes por esta causa.

Em uma linguagem como C é possível que haja algum ganho para um lado ou para outro, mas são raros os casos que o ganho seja relevante e necessário e só analisando cada caso para determinar se o melhor é a função ser menor ou maior.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente, +1! Só faltou falar que diferentes processadores também podem beneficiar programas com funções maiores ou menores, de acordo com a implementação da cache e da predição de salto.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira vou ver se melhoro alguma coisa depois. Mas sinta-se à vontade para responder também já que parece ser um assunto que você conhece.