# Tempo de processamento é afetado pelo tamanho dos nomes de variáveis?

Tags: desempenho, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, tempo-de-resposta

Estava analisando alguns *frameworks* desenvolvidos por grandes empresas e notei uma determinada singularidade, suas variáveis e funções geralmente têm nomes pequenos.

#### O tamanho do nome da variável ou função interfere do tempo de processamento?

---

Pela lógica eu diria que sim, pois ler 4 *bytes* ao invés de 20 tornaria a busca pela variável ou função mais rápida.

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31485/o-tamanho-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-afeta-a-performance-e-consumo-de-mem%C3%B3ria Não é exatamente a mesma coisa mas acho que é o mesmo propósito. Resumindo o link: em linguagens compiladas os nomes desaparecem, em linguagens totalmente interpretadas há tanta ineficiência que uma mais não vai fazer diferença (ou, já tem que *parsear* mesmo de que vale o tamanho ser menor?). Quando for fazer afirmações seria bom citar exemplos para dar mais contexto. Pode ser que tenha um motivo específico. É dup? Se não for, eu respondo.

Comment: @bigown acho que a diferença entre lá e cá é que na outra pergunta se analisava o tamanho da função. Aqui se analisa o tamanho dos nomes das variáveis.

Comment: Fiquei curioso pra saber quais frameworks possuem nomes de funções e variáveis tão pequenos que chega a ser notável como uma característica comum entre eles. Quais são?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em linguagens compiladas, seu código é traduzido para linguagem de máquina. As variáveis que você chama de *"foo"*, *"bar"*, *"_auxTempObj"* etc... Viram sequências de zeros e uns geradas na conveniência do compilador.

Os processadores de hoje em dia tem "portas de entrada" para seus registros que passam 64 bits de cada vez (isso é o significado da arquitetura de 64 bits ;) ), então qualquer coisa com menos do que isso é completada com zeros.

Dessa forma, a relação entre tamanho de nome e performance é praticamente irrelevante. **As variáveis devem ser nomeadas de forma a serem legíveis por pessoas, não por máquinas.**

Agora vamos as linguagens interpretadas.

O simples ato de ler uma palavra é um algoritmo de [complexidade O(n)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O). Quem é <strike>nerd</strike> estudado o suficiente para entender isso já entendeu com isso que a conclusão para linguagens interpretadas é a mesma conclusão para linguagens compiladas.

Em linguagem humana, o que isso quer dizer é que ler nomes de variáveis é "barato" computacionalmente. Em termos práticos, os nomes das variáveis não serão o gargalo na hora de interpretar seu código. O simples ato de determinar os escopos de cada parte do código é ordens de grandeza mais caro que a leitura dos nomes. Então mais uma vez, dê nome as variáveis pensando em quem vai manter o seu código.

Ainda que isso não fosse verdade... Um interpretador pode montar uma [tabela hash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) com os nomes das variáveis e trabalhar com os hashes. Dependendo do algoritmo, isso equivaleria a ter todos os nomes de variáveis com o mesmo tamanho. Novamente, não vale a pena se preocupar com isso.

Só para concluir: falei várias vezes que você não deve se preocupar com o impacto na performance. Mas o fato de você ter pensado que isso pode afetar o desempenho do programa, essa curiosidade, é a marca do bom desenvolvedor. Ainda que qualquer motivo para preocupação seja desfeito pela teoria e pela prática, os conceitos que você precisa conhecer para compreender essa questão lhe ajudarão a programar melhor.

Comment: A resposta em si está perfeita, só não entendi bem essa coisa de 64 bits. Eu acho que não é bem assim que funciona. Será que você não está confundindo com *cache line* que tem 64 **bytes**? A não ser que seja construído um algoritmo específico, o que raramente acontece, tratando vários caracteres de uma vez ou quem sabe usando instruções SSE, cada caractere processado individualmente. Há vantagem de não ter que carregar uma por um por causa do cache, mas até onde eu sei, só isto. Perdi alguma coisa?

Comment: @bigown eu apenas imagino que um compilador transforma cada variável que houver no código em um simbolo durante a tradução. Não importando o formato do símbolo, em geral oito bytes devem ser suficientes para guardar todos os símbolos possíveis que representem algo no programa (a menos que você tenha mais que 2^64 variáveis...)

Comment: Agora entendi o que você está dizendo, pensei que você estava colocando que o *parsing* ocorria em grupos de 64 bits (8 bytes) de cada vez.

Answer (score 5):

## Linguagens compiladas

Em linguagens compiladas o nome das variáveis são importantes apenas para o compilador.  Quando o programa termina de ser compilado, esses nomes não existem mais, são apenas endereços de memória que serão acessados em tempo de execução. Então não o nome não faz a menor diferença no processamento da aplicação. O computador não quer saber de nomes de variáveis. Isto é uma abstração para humanos entenderem melhor o código. Então use os nomes para isto, para fazer o seu código ser o mais compreensível possível.

É possível que alguém ache que para fazer o [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) consuma mais tempo porque os nomes das variáveis são maiores. Tecnicamente isto é verdade mas isto é tão ínfimo, tão pouco perto do todo que precisa ser feito e uma redução dos nomes traria tantos problemas que não vale à pena nem pensar nisto. Comentários causam ainda mais perda de tempo durante o processo de compilação e ninguém ousa dizer que não deve usar nenhum comentário para tornar a compilação menos de 0,1% mais rápida.

Note que algumas linguagens são compiladas para alguma forma intermediária (um *[bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)* ou uma *[AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)*). Nestes casos o processo costuma funcionar de forma análogo à compilação para código nativo.

## Linguagens interpretadas

Quando a linguagem é totalmente interpretada, o que é raro hoje em dia, então o processo de compilação se interpola com a execução do código propriamente dita, então vai ter uma pequena perda, mas de novo, a perda é tão ínfima que não fará nenhuma diferença real. Será difícil até mensurar a diferença, provavelmente outros fatores não controláveis farão mais diferença que isto, você ficará sempre dentro da margem de erro. Analisando de outra forma, um código interpretado é tão ineficiente que ter que analisar uns caracteres a mais não faz diferença mesmo que o processamento da aplicação em si seja muito pequeno. O tempo adicional se considerarmos apenas a interpretação já será muito irrisório.

E note que mesmo interpretadores costumam só perder tempo com a interpretação inicial, os acessos subsequentes provavelmente serão feitas de forma otimizada através de [símbolos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)).

## Nomes de variáveis pequenos em *frameworks*

Os *frameworks* que eu conheço não costumam se preocupar com o tamanho das variáveis. As vezes a despreocupação é tão grande que chegam ter nomes assim: `InternalFrameInternalFrameTitlePaneInternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonWindowNotFocusedState`. O único problema dele é que mesmo humanos não conseguem entender isto.