# É uma boa ideia declarar variáveis com acentos?

Tags: php, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Eu estava dando uma olhada no Manual do PHP sobre as [variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php). Lá encontrei um trecho de código que me deixou com o "pé atrás".

```
$täyte = 'mansikka';    // válido; 'ä' é um caracter ASCII (extendido) 228
```

Sempre vejo em tutoriais para iniciantes em PHP afirmações de que não é uma boa ideia declarar variáveis com acentuações e coisas semelhantes. Porém, agora no Manual do PHP vi essa variável `$täyte`.

Decidi realizar um teste ...

```
$usuário = 'Wallace';
 
$cidadão = 'Brasileiro';
 
$preferências = ['PHP', 'jQuery'];
      
print_r(compact('usuário', 'cidadão', 'preferências'));
 
var_dump($usuário);
```

...  e consegui esse resultado:

```
Array
(
    [usuário] => Wallace
    [cidadão] => Brasileiro
    [preferências] => Array
        (
            [0] => PHP
            [1] => jQuery
        )

)
string(7) "Wallace"
```

Veja no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/b2tUPM) que tudo ocorreu corretamente.

Outro ponto que gostaria de colocar é que, quando estava aprendendo um pouco de `java`, vi um trecho de código assim:

```
JButton botão = new JButton();
```

E isso também funcionou corretamente.

## Perguntas

- Existe algum possível problema em declarar variáveis com acentos (Como `$joão`, `$está_certo`, `$é_array`) em relação à linguagem PHP?
- É uma prática comum entre as linguagens de programação a não-utilização de caracteres acentuados na declaração de variáveis?

Comment: Eu poderia lhe dar a resposta, contudo não tenho muito tempo para elaborar, mas leia primeiramente as resposta desta questão, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40893/tempo-de-processamento-%C3%A9-afetado-pelo-tamanho-dos-nomes-de-vari%C3%A1veis e apos este artigo http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29, em conclusão creio que a conversão de bites poderia ser interpretada diferente. devido a se tratar de caracteres abaixo do 127.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @GuilhermeLautert. Vou dar uma lida sim

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/91

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema maior em usar os caracteres ASCII extendidos é que nem sempre cada computador os interpreta igualmente. Todos os computadores interpretam o ASCII igual, mas quando se trata de extensões - e.g. os caracteres de outros idiomas além do inglês, a interpretação não é garantida a ser igual.

Aí, como foi falado em outra resposta, essa diferença em interpretação pode inteferir com o código fonte... por exemplo, no seu computador:

```
$variável
```

No meu:

```
$vari?vel
```

Answer (score 7):

Wallace, a utilização de acentuação de variáveis é permitida, porém não um bom hábito as utilizar.

Existem alguns padrões de nomeclatura, um exemplo deles é o camelCase, onde as variveis são nomeadas com a primeira palavra totalmente em minusculo e as demais possuem a primeira letra em maiúsculo. ex: clienteExterno.

Encontrei essa [pergunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196416/whats-the-dominant-naming-convention-for-variables-in-php-camelcase-or-undersc) no stackexchange que discute qual é o melhor padrão a ser utilizado em php.

> É uma prática comum entre as linguagens de programação a não-utilização de caracteres acentuados na declaração de variáveis?

Não é uma prática comum nas linguagens de programação se utilizar acentuação nos nomes das variáveis. Em algumas linguagens isso é dado por problema de encoding que podem ocorrer.

Você citou nomes de variáveis de java com acentuação, achei um [página](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/java/variable_names.shtml#.VeXOjXUVhBc) que fala um pouco do padrão que o java usa. O que ele fala sobre acentuação é, podem ocorrer problemas de encoding e ou o seu parceiro de programação não está acostumado com acentuação, isso pode acontecer por exemplo em um projeto open source, onde pessoas de vários lugares estão codificando.

Basicamente, cada linguagem possui um padrão de nomeclatura para variáveis que é utilizado.

Não quer dizer que a acentuação é proíbida, apenas não recomendada.

Comment: Exatamente essa é a questão. Por que _não é um bom hábito as utilizar_? Como disse na minha pergunta: _Existe algum problema possível_?

Comment: Gostei da pergunta postada. Porém vejo que a pergunta postada se trata de "quais são as convenções  de nome de variáveis para PHP?". Inclusive a mesma foi fechada por ser baseada em opniões. O foco mesmo é entender o motivo da _não-recomendação_

Comment: Wallace, existe essa página(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) sobre padrão de nomeclatura, que lista alguns dos motivos pelos quais os padrões são utilizados. Além dos motivos nessa página acredito que a acentuação não é utlizada por conta do encoding.

Answer (score 3):

> Existe algum possível problema em declarar variáveis com acentos (Como $joão, $está_certo, $é_array) em relação à linguagem PHP?

Um dos maiores problemas que vejo e que as vezes um desenvolvedor pode estar com o encoding diferente na sua IDE e acabar detonando o nome das variáveis

> É uma prática comum entre as linguagens de programação a não-utilização de caracteres acentuados na declaração de variáveis?

Sim