# Ler duas notas e exibir uma string conforme a média entre elas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Faça um programa que receba duas notas, calcule e mostre a média e a mensagem que está na tabela a seguir:

```
0,0 - 4,0   Reprovado
4,0 - 7,0   Exame
7,0 - 10,0  Aprovado
```

```py
print('ATIVIDADE 2 -ESTRUTURA CONDICIONAL')
print('----------------------------------')

nota_1 = float(input('Digite a primeira nota: '))
nota_2 = float(input('Digite a segunda nota: '))

média = (nota_1+nota_2)/2

print('A média aritmética é: ',média)

if float(média <=4.0):
    print('Reprovado')

elif float(média <=7.0):
    print('Exame')

elif float(média <=10.0):
    print('Aprovado')
```

Comment: Qual sua dúvida?

Comment: como insiro aqueles valores da tabela no programa usando condicional

Comment: Ola @Halan, bem vindo ao SOpt,  Você precisa informar qual é a sua duvida, de uma olhada no nosso [Tour] e em [ask]. - Para adicionar informações clique em [edit] abaixo da pergunta. =P  --- No seu codigo tem 2 coisas que eu não faria, Variável com acentuação e converter o `boolean` no `if` para `float`.

Comment: Oi, acredito que seja acentuação mesmo, que não pode ser usada, por conta da conversão do compilador dele mesmo.

Comment: @PhilipRamkeerat Pode sim, Python aceita nomes unicode sem problema algum.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu lembrei do utf-8 que a gente pode inserir

Comment: Ao invés de `if float(média <=4.0):`, você deveria usar `if float(média) <= 4.0:`, ou seja, o fecha-parênteses está no lugar errado. Melhor ainda seria simplesmente usar `if média <= 4.0:` como foi dado nas respostas. O mesmo se aplica ao `elif`. Assim sendo, considero que a sua pergunta é um erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1):

Eu arriscaria algo como:

```
media = (nota_1 + nota_2)/2
if media <= 4.0:
    print('reprovado')
elif media >= 7.0:
    print('aprovado')
else:
    print('exame')
```

Agora, não basta saber **COMO**, mas sim **O QUE** esta fazendo, em primeiro lugar, evite usar acentuação, pois isso pode gerar muitos problemas por compatibilidade de formatação de arquivos, isso se torna ainda mais perigoso em linguagens interpretadas (como o caso do Python).

Entendendo o código: bem, não coloquei inteiro, mas sim apenas o trecho que tu tem dúvida, note que eu recebo os valores das notas e efetuo o calculo da média, o Python entende que a variável `media` é um `float` porque ela recebe `float` como valor.

Entendendo os condicionais `if`, `elif` e `else`: eles trabalham com valor `boolean`, ou seja, **verdadeiro** ou **falso**, não compare valores diferentes disso, note que em `media <= 4.0` o resultado desta comparação é um `boolean`apesar dos dados serem `float`, isso porque o condicional esta comparando a condição `<=`, ou seja: "`media` é maior ou igual a `4.0`, verdadeiro ou falso?".

Perceba que montei uma estrutura diferente, pois entendendo o problema da tabela eu vejo que a média sendo inferior ou igual a 4.0, o aluno esta reprovado, caso seja entre 4.1 e 6.9 ele entra em exame, porém se for acima de 7.0 ele esta aprovado.

Comment: "*evite usar acentuação*", não é uma verdade, pois Python suporta nomes unicode sem problemas algum.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, o fato do Python suportar (não é a única linguagem) não diminui o fato de que não usar seja uma boa pratica, o uso de acentuação é fortemente desencorajado.

Comment: Por quais motivos?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, segue referencias interna: 
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83725/%C3%89-uma-boa-ideia-declarar-vari%C3%A1veis-com-acentos
-.https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16555/existe-algum-problema-em-usar-caracteres-unicode-para-identificadores-em-c%C3%B3digo?noredirect=1&lq=1

Aqui é possivel ver outras referencias também que acabam por ajudar a entender o porquê de não ser uma boa pratica apesar de ser permitido.

Lembrando, algumas linguagens permitem a declaração de emojis, pense na legibilidade e falta de padrão disso e já terá um bom motivo para não usar.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código produz a saída esperada, como pode ser visto aqui: https://sopt-question-381571.acwoss.repl.run.

Mas há considerações que serão importantes:

1. O método inicializador de `float`, chamado em `float(input('...'))`, lança uma exceção `ValueError` se o valor retornado por `input` não puder ser representado como ponto flutuante. Isso acontece, por exemplo, quando é retornado um texto. É interessante você tratar isso no código para dar o *feedback* correto ao usuário e não quebrar a aplicação:

   ```
   while True:
       try:
           nota_1 = float(input('Entre com a nota 1:'))
           break
       except ValueError:
           print('Valor inválido! A nota precisa ser um número real')
   ```
2. Não há motivos para você considerar no seu código notas negativas - até porque seria estranho um aluno tirar -5 na prova. Considerando que a nota máxima do enunciado é 10,0, também não tem motivos para considerar notas acima disso, então fazer a validação do intervalo também é importante:

   ```
   while True:
       try:
           nota_1 = float(input('Entre com a nota 1:'))
           if not 0 <= nota_1 <= 10:
               raise ValueError('Valor fora do intervalo')
           break
       except ValueError:
           print('Valor inválido! A nota precisa ser um número real entre 0 e 10.')
   ```
3. Nas verificações para exibir o resultado você fez `float(média <= 4)`. Perceba que você colocou a comparação inteira dentro de `float`. Isso funciona, mas por mera "coincidência", por consequência do operador `<=` retornar um booleano e o booleano no Python ser um sub-tipo do inteiro. Assim, se retornado `False`, será considerado como `0.0`, que será interpretado como falso pela estrutura `if`, semelhantemente quando retornado `True`, será considerado `1.0`, que será interpretado como verdadeiro. Faria mais sentido (ler item 4) fazer:

   ```
   if float(média) <= 4.0:
       ...
   elif float(média) <= 7.0:
       ...
   else:
       ...
   ```
4. O operador `/`, que fará a divisão aritmética entre a soma das notas e a quantidade, para calcular a média, já retorna por padrão um número de ponto flutuante. Ou seja, fazer `média = (nota_1 + nota_2)/2` já faz com que `média` seja um `float`, então fazer `float(média)` é redundante.
5. Você pode gerar *strings* repetitivas através da multiplicação, com o operador `*`. Por exemplo, fazer `'-' * 3` gerará a *string* `'---'`. Desta forma, você não precisa digitar todos os caracteres como você fez; e aliado a isso você consegue deixar o código mais dinâmico caso precise alterar as informações:

   ```
   title = 'ATIVIDADE 2 -ESTRUTURA CONDICIONAL'

   print(title)
   print('-' * len(title))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para complementar as respostas, Serve para versão 2 do python. seguindo por um caminho diferente, se você estiver com a necessidade de utilizar a acentuação no seu trabalho, de curso, faculdade etc. Você pode utilizar uma sintaxe que permite o uso, configurando o UTF-8 no inicio do seu código.

Por exemplo:

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

De acordo com a documentação do python, Unicode ( https://www.unicode.org/ ) é uma especificação que visa listar todos os caracteres usados ​​por linguagens humanas e dar a cada caractere um código único. As especificações Unicode são continuamente revisadas e atualizadas para adicionar novos idiomas e símbolos.

Comment: E isso não é necessário apenas para o Python 2?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu estava trabalhando com python 3.7 e fiz o teste para poder postar aqui, acredito que serve para o 3 tbem

Comment: Realmente, na versão 3 não precisa, eu editei o post, para informar que é na versão 2 agora, obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss xD