# Como chamar um função através de um botão usando o querySelector?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal!
Eu preciso que ao clicar em um botão apareça um alert, porém nada que tentar funcionou. Segue o trecho do código:

```
function alerta(){
         alert("Este é um alerta");
}

Var botão = document.querySelector(".button_menu");

botão.onclick = alerta;
// não exibe o alerta, porém com os parênteses () no final exibe ao carregar a página, não ao clicar. //
```

Me ajudem por favor.
Vlw!!

Comment: use `botão.addEventListener("click", alerta);`, e evite nomes com acentos, tente usar somente `botao`

Comment: Ricardo Pontual, vlw cara, vou tentar aqui!

Comment: @DavidArtagnan Sua lógica está correta e é melhor que a resposta dada. A única coisa é que você colocou `Var` com `V` maiúsculo. Basta resolver isso que o código funcionará, mas cuidado ao fazer a atribuição no `onclick` de qualquer forma. Prefira sempre `addEventListener` para evitar gerar efeitos colaterais na aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando o `Var` com a primeira letra maiúscula.

```js
function alerta() { alert("Este é um alerta"); }

var botão = document.querySelector(".button_menu");

botão.onclick = alerta;
```

```html
<button class="button_menu">Alert</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo aqui!!✌

Comment: @Renan O negativo é consequente da versão original da resposta, mas parece que já foi removido pelo autor

Answer (score 0):

No seu exemplo, o erro era a letra 'v', em maiúscula. Quando se acrescenta os parênteses '()' ao nome da função, você está invocando-o 'alerta()'. Quando não os acrescenta, se está passando/acessando a função por referência.

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está correto, exceto pelo erro de sintaxe no `Var`, que seria tudo em minúscula: `var`. Se atente à sintaxe do JavaScript, que diferencia letras maiúsculas de minúsculas. Ao usar `Var` o programa não reconhece o comando e retorna o erro: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` (é sempre bom olhar o console para visualizar possíveis erros no código).

Sobre a questão de adicionar os `()` na atribuição e disparar o alert da função, ocorre porque o código que vem após o operador de atribuição `=` é executado assim que é lido, ou seja, ao fazer:

```
botão.onclick = alerta();
```

Simplesmente irá executar a função `alerta()` e nada mais. Seria o mesmo que colocar apenas `alert();`.

O `onclick` chama uma função anônima desta forma:

```
botão.onclick = function(){}
```

Como você criou uma função `alerta()`, você pode substituir o bloco `function(){}` pelo nome da função, sem os `()`, assim como fez:

```
botão.onclick = alerta;
```

Desta forma você está atribuindo a função ao evento `onclick`, e não executando ela, porque a variável `alerta` já é uma função e você está atribuindo ela por referência.

Veja a diferença entre as duas coisas:

```
alerta(); -> com parênteses: executa a função
alerta;   -> sem parênteses: referencia ao valor na variável "alerta"
```

Agora, como disseram nos comentários, evite acentos em variáveis: use `botao` em vez de `botão` (**[veja um tópico falando a respeito disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83725/%C3%89-uma-boa-ideia-declarar-vari%C3%A1veis-com-acentos)**).