# Chamar dezenas de classes em um sistema influencia perceptívelmente no desempenho da aplicação?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, desempenho

Estou começando a trabalhar com **orientação a objetos em PHP** e gostaria de saber se a quantidade de classes existentes num sistema pode interferir no desempenho do mesmo ou se teria que ser centenas dessas classes para que realmente o desempenho pudesse começar a ser afetado.

Comment: A quantidade de classes não influencia não, as instancias é que ocupam memoria e os algorítimos processadores.

Answer (score 7):

A quantidade de classes não faz diferença perceptível, o que você faz nelas pode fazer diferença. Claro que diferença faz, mas não é por isso que deve usar classes ou não.

O termo "chamar classes" nem faz sentido.

Classes são usadas para organizar o código, então use as para organizar, ou deixe de usar se essa organização não traz vantagem alguma. E em PHP é comum ela não trazer vantagem, há um uso excessivo de classes na maioria dos códigos. Em geral a pessoa usa uma classe porque ela não sabe o que está fazendo, ela apenas segue o fluxo.

Não tem problema algum criar classes quando elas vão trazer alguma coisa útil, se a pessoa conseguir justificar clara e individualmente a sua necessidade. Se ela não conseguir fazer isto - e não basta dar uma justificativa genérica do tipo "vai organizar o código" - é porque a classe não é necessária.

Então a preocupação não deve ser essa, e se for, provavelmente deve trocar de linguagem, já que PHP não é uma linguagem para ser rápida, é para desenvolver rápido. O que mostra como é estranho usar classes na linguagem, já que ela remete a OOP que é um desenvolvimento mais bem arquitetado e que seria útil em sistemas complexos, não em sistemas de *scripts*.

O certo depende do contexto. Qualquer um que diga coisas deste tipo que é o certo para um lado ou outro em termos gerais está apenas *papagaindo*. Tem que analisar o problema para decidir o que deve fazer. Experiência conta nestes casos. Quando não tem ela tem que pedir ajuda, mas tem que pedir em termos que dê para fazer uma análise, isto não é fácil, e principalmente não costuma caber aqui, a não ser que a pessoa saiba bem como perguntar.

É comum a pessoa optar por uma forma sem justificativa plausível. Ela escolhe uma forma e vai nela sem pensar.

Algumas perguntas que podem ajudar entender melhor o assunto:

- [Qual o overhead de utilizar orientação a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50273/101)
- [PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101)
- [O tamanho de uma função afeta a performance e consumo de memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31485/101)

Comment: +1 pela resposta, desmistifica fatos que os "programadores só de vitrine" não entendem. Acho extremamente importante ensinar coisas que funcionam no mundo real aqui no SOpt. Só esse parágrafo já iria eliminar muitos absurdos que eu vejo em PHP se as pessoas entenderem: _"Não tem problema algum criar classes quando elas vão trazer alguma coisa útil, se a pessoa conseguir justificar clara e individualmente a sua necessidade. Se ela não conseguir fazer isto - e não basta dar uma justificativa genérica do tipo "vai organizar o código" - é porque a classe não é necessária."_

Comment: @Maniero neste contexto " já que PHP não é uma linguagem para ser rápida, é para desenvolver rápido." que linguagem para web (com suporte a modo cli) seria compativel com este cenario (de velocidade/performance) na tua opiniao ?

Comment: @MCunha98 As linguagens rápidas que são usadas pra performance são C# em primeiro lugar e Java em segundo. Outras também são usadas, mas pouco, é claro que sabendo fazer C++ ou Rust pode ser mais rápidas ainda, mas poucos se aventuram, é trabalhoso demais, e se fizer errado fica mais lento (tem diversos casos de C# mais rápido que C++, C++ só fica rápido com muito esforço. Essencialmente qualquer linguagem suporta CLI, algumas mais que outras, c# suporta muito bem. Curiosamente o jeito que as pessoas fazem hoje em PHP nem desenvolver rápido tá rolando mais :D

Answer (score 7):

Falando mais do mesmo, não faz diferença. A explicação está nas outras respostas.

Um ponto prático que deve-se estar atento é a forma como essas classes são carregadas.

Provavelmente você vai querer usar um autoloader. Aí sim, nesse caso vai consumir processos que influenciam muito na performance.

Um autloader consiste em incluir um arquivo quando invoca uma classe que não esteja presente no corpo do script. Esse processo de incluir o arquivo consome bastante memória e processamento.

Para reduzir esse custo, é recomendável criar estruturas de cache de compilação. Também podemos optar ou reforçar com bibliotecas de cache como o Memcache, APC, Opcode, dentre outros.

Todavia, se a preocupação é se o uso de classes ou conceitos OOP tornarão o sistema menos performático do que escrever os códigos em estilo procedural, obviamente, o estilo procedural é muito mais rápido. Contudo, pense da seguinte forma, você precisa ir da sua casa até o bar da esquina que fica a 20 metros. Como você vai ir?

```
1. a pé
2. de moto
3. de lamborguini
```

Vou acreditar que vc optou pela opção 1.

Agora, vamos supor que vc quer ir de sua casa até Paris.

```
1. a pé e segue nadando pelo oceano
2. de moto e segue de barco a remo pelo oceano
3. vai até um aeroporto e segue de avião
```

Acho que você optou pelo avião.

Mas por quê avião se consome muito mais recursos e é pesado? Não dá na mesma ir a pé e seguir nadando pelo oceano? Afinal, dá o mesmo resultado.

Pense nessa analogia ou analogias similares e entenderá quando usar um estilo ou conceitoY.

Pense sempre no objetivo final. Qual custo/benefício que a opção X ou Y vai gerar?

Analisado o custo/benefício, pense na efetividade.

O custo/benefício é efetivo?

Esses são passos básicos para fazer uma escolha mais adequada.

Comment: **:)** Excelente resposta. É variável e devemos analisar a melhor forma de aplicar alguma estilo ou conceito. O exemplo demonstrado é bem específico e direto ao caso da pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

O desempenho vai depender de como as classes são usadas, como são escritas, como elas se comportam e como elas se relacionam, além das características do servidor que hospeda sua aplicação. Simplesmente ter a classe no sistema não afeta o desempenho.

Answer (score -4):

Somente para reforçar, um contexto muito importante para OOP é usar classes estaticas quando teu objetivo sim é limitar as funcionalidades de um objeto (assim nao ficando com um monte de funções genéricas no código), traz organização para teu código sem necessidade de instanciar

Comment: Sua resposta ficou bem vaga e sem sentido. Conseguiria explicar melhor isso? Por que agrupar funções em uma classe estática é melhor no OOP? Aliás, qual a relação entre classe estática e OOP? Se as funções são ditas genéricas quando definidas fora da classe, por que elas deixariam de ser genéricas dentro da classe? Por que uma classe estática melhora a organização? Qual é a diferença entre ter um arquivo com uma classe com de métodos e um arquivo com funções?

Comment: O contexto é simples, por exemplo agrupar funções relativas a data em uma classe estática que trate de data (adicionar dias, converter formatdos, validar, etc...) claro que você pode enfiar tudo num arquivo só e rezar para lembrar dos nomes as funções ou então encapsular os operadores em classes estáticas que se liguem ao contexto ...por exmeplo ClasseData::validar($value),  ClasseData::adicionarDias($value), etc... de novo, questão de abordagem, dá para fazer tudo em um arquivo geral também , vai do nível de organização que se quer atingir

Comment: Mas não consigo compreender como `ClasseData::validar` pode ser mais organizado que `validar_data`. Ao ler o nome da função eu sei exatamente o que ela faz e não preciso me preocupar com classe alguma.

Comment: De novo...depende do nivel de organizacao, nao estou dizendo que voce esta certo e eu errado (ou vice-versa), somente que operacoes limitadas a um escopo podem ser melhor mapeadas/compreendidas quando estao abaixo de algo mais representativo