# Minha calculadora a partir do while na posição 2, pula a inserção do primeiro valor alguém consegue me ajudar?

Tags: java

```
package Calculadora;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculadora {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float valor1 = 0;
    float valor2 = 0;
    float opcao = 5;
    float resultado;
    //boolean loop = true;

    System.out.println("-Seja bem-vindo(a) a sua calculadora-");
    System.out.println("Escolha uma o por favor!!");
    System.out.println("1. Soma");
    System.out.println("2. Subtracao");
    System.out.println("3. Multiplicacao");
    System.out.println("4. Divisao");
    System.out.println("0. Sair");
    System.out.println("Operação: ");

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    opcao = teclado.nextFloat();
    clearBuffet(teclado);

    while (opcao != 0) {
      if (opcao == 1) {
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
        clearBuffet(teclado);

        try {
          valor1 = teclado.nextFloat();
          clearBuffet(teclado);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
          clearBuffet(teclado);
          continue;
        }
      }
      System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
      try {
        valor2 = teclado.nextFloat();
        clearBuffet(teclado);
        break;
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
        clearBuffet(teclado);
        continue;
      }
    }

    resultado = valor1 + valor2;
    System.out.println(resultado);

    while (opcao != 0) {
      if (opcao == 2) {
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
        clearBuffet(teclado);

        try {
          valor1 = teclado.nextFloat();
          clearBuffet(teclado);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
          clearBuffet(teclado);
          continue;
        }

        System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
        clearBuffet(teclado);
        try {
          valor2 = teclado.nextFloat();
          clearBuffet(teclado);
          break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
          clearBuffet(teclado);
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    resultado = valor1 - valor2;
    System.out.print(resultado);

    while (opcao != 0) {
      if (opcao == 3) {
        System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
        clearBuffet(teclado);
        try {
          valor1 = teclado.nextFloat();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
          clearBuffet(teclado);
          continue;
        }

        System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
        clearBuffet(teclado);

        try {
          valor2 = teclado.nextFloat();
          break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
          clearBuffet(teclado);
          continue;
        }
      }

    }

    resultado = valor1 * valor2;
    System.out.print(resultado);

    while (opcao != 0) {
      if (opcao == 4) {
        if (opcao == 1) {
          System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
          clearBuffet(teclado);

          try {
            valor1 = teclado.nextFloat();
          } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
            clearBuffet(teclado);
            continue;
          }

          System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
          clearBuffet(teclado);

          try {
            valor2 = teclado.nextFloat();
            break;
          } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Vamos começar denovo, digite apenas números\n\n");
            clearBuffet(teclado);
            continue;
          }
        }
      } else if (valor2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Impossivel dividir por 0!!");

      } else resultado = valor1 / valor2;
      System.out.print(resultado);

      if (opcao >= 5) {
        System.out.println("Opção invalida");

      }
    }
  }

  private static void clearBuffet(Scanner scanner) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      scanner.nextLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que o Scanner retorna erro em algo que está dentro do esperado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262976/por-que-o-scanner-retorna-erro-em-algo-que-est%c3%a1-dentro-do-esperado)

Comment: Só pra constar que a afirmação da resposta abaixo, de que um método deve ter no máximo 15 linhas, é equivocada e absurda. Qualquer um que tente definir um número "mágico" de linhas que seja o "certo" pra todos os casos está automaticamente errado, pois isso depende muito do contexto. Para saber mais sobre o assunto, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30772/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31485/112052)

Comment: Só pra deixar uma sugestão, em vez de tentar limpar o buffer (não é buffe**t**), você pode simplesmente ler a linha toda e tentar converter para número, assim: https://ideone.com/XNOA0p (para ler do teclado é melhor assim, entenda os motivos lendo o [link já citado](/q/262976/112052)). Repare também que eliminei esse monte de loop desnecessário, e ele só faz a operação que foi escolhida no menu (além disso a resposta abaixo sugere criar o `Scanner` toda hora dentro do método `lerOpcao`, o que é desnecessário). Enfim, daria para melhorar mais, mas em linhas gerais seria isso.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

O código é longo, por isso `pouco legível`, o que é normal quando estamos fazendo os trabalhos tendo pouca experiência. Faz parte do aprendizado.

Minha sugestão até para que seja mais fácil encontrar qualquer possível erro, é `dividir o código em métodos`.

Eu sugiro que o código seja dividido em métodos menores, onde cada um será definido para uma função específica. Algumas razões para isso:

- O conceito do que o método faz fica facilmente entendível e definido em nossa mente
- A leitura de um método poderá ser feita na tela sem rolagem da página
- Encontrar um erro no problema como um todo fica muito mais fácil
- A manutenção (alterações futuras) de códigos com pequenos métodos fica muito mais fácil e rápida

Dito isso, vou apenas começar a escrever um código do que você precisa e você pode continuar fazendo assim... com pequenos métodos sendo chamados. Por exemplo:

```
static void iniciarCalculadora() {
    System.out.println("-Seja bem-vindo(a) a sua calculadora-");
    System.out.println("Escolha uma o por favor!!");
    System.out.println("1. Soma");  
    System.out.println("2. Subtracao");  
    System.out.println("3. Multiplicacao");  
    System.out.println("4. Divisao");  
    System.out.println("0. Sair");  
    System.out.println("Operação: "); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    iniciarCalculadora();
    int opcao = lerOpcao();
}

static int lerOpcao() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcao = teclado.nextInt();
    clearBuffet(teclado);
    return opcao;
}

private static void clearBuffet(Scanner scanner) {
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Esse é apenas o início do trabalho feito dessa maneira diferente, com pequenos métodos resolvendo cada parte do problema.

Minha sugestão é essa. Você refazer, e posteriormente postar aqui com `pequenos métodos` e ele ficar `mais legível`, aí podemos ver de forma muito mais fácil se há um `bug`.

Comment: Um método não fica facilmente entendível porque ele tem de 5 à 15 linhas. Método com outros tamanhos cabem na tela sem rolar a página a não ser com muitas dezenas de linhas. Encontrar um erro fica mais fácil por diversas razões e não porque ele tem de 5 à 15 linhas, pode ser mais fácil com menos de 5 linhas, e se bem feito pode ser com mais de 15. O mesmo vale para a manutenção. Quem conta linhas para definir qualidade de um método não sabe programar e se agarra à fórmulas para fingir que está bem feito. Qualidade se dá estudando profundamente e aplicando raciocínio lógico.

Comment: Dividir adequadamente é bom, contar linhas não.

Comment: Não se trata de contar linhas para definir qualidade. No entanto, um método com tantas linhas pode gerar inúmeras saídas, ser pouco ou nada reutilizável. Somente a contagem de linhas não faz sentido. Mas como ter coesão em métodos? Com uma função bem definida pra ele ou com ele fazendo tudo? O autor pelo tipo de problema apresentado está em fase de aprendizado. Penso que seria útil esse conceito pra ele. Quem já deu manutenção em código em qualquer empresa sabe o quanto é doloroso pegar códigos extensos para procurar bugs.

Comment: O problema é cravar "números mágicos" (5 a 15 linhas, mas poderia ser quaisquer outros valores que o problema continuaria o mesmo) e dizer que é por causa desses números que vc consegue todas as vantagens que menciona. Dá para obter essas mesmas vantagens com valores diferentes (20 a 30? 10 a 40?), e isso varia e depende muito do contexto. Não existem valores absolutos que funcionam para qualquer caso, e tentar cravar tais valores é o principal problema que está sendo criticado aqui. Leitura relacionada (e recomendada): [aqui](/q/30772/112052) e [aqui](/q/31485/112052)

Comment: Aliás, é justamente pelo autor da pergunta - aparentemente - estar em fase de aprendizado que estamos alertando aqui, pois esse tipo de pensamento ("métodos só podem ter no máximo X linhas", sendo X um valor fixo qualquer) é prejudicial e acaba criando vícios difíceis de tirar depois. Seria muito melhor ensinar que isso depende do contexto e não existe um número mágico de linhas que é o ideal para todos os casos (que é a discussão dos links que indiquei acima). Concordo que o ideal é que eles não sejam muito longos (mas o "muito" é relativo, e nem sempre será exatamente "15 linhas").

Comment: Eu editei a resposta tirando a ideia sobre número de linhas ideal. Até porque a ideia era apresentar o conceito de coesão. Vocês podem remover a resposta se julgarem que ela não acrescenta nada ao aprendizado. Agradeço as indicações de leitura.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que seja por causa do método `clearBuffet(Scanner)`. Ele pula para próxima linha: `scanner.nextLine();`.