# Como imprimir um vetor de inteiros retirando a última vírgula em Python 3?

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, inteiros

Quero imprimir na tela um vetor de números inteiros na mesma linha e separados por vírgula, e quero retirar a vírgula que fica após o ultimo número.

Como eu poderia fazer isso em Python?

Meu código está assim:

```
for i in range(12):
    print(numeros[i],end=",")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De um jeito *Pythonico* é possível concatenar os elementos da lista numa `string` separados por vírgula. O `map` serve para converter os valores da lista (criada por `range()`) para `string`.

```
numeros = ','.join(map(str, range(12))) 
print(numeros)
```

Ou talvez assim, fazendo a conversão para string usando *list comprehension*:

```
numeros = ','.join([str(x) for x in range(12)])
print(numeros)
```

Também é possível fazendo um `if`. Este é um *approach* menos *Pythonic*, porém é bem mais simples de entender, principalmente se estiver aprendendo.

```
for i in range(12):
    if(i != 11):
        print(i, end=",")
    else: 
        print(i)
```

Comment: Para questões de estética (apenas exibição), seria possível fazer apenas `print(str(numeros)[1:-1])`. Se o retorno é utilizado para qualquer outra coisa que seja, utilizar `join`.

Comment: Obrigado! Resolvi usar a sua primeira sugestão para resolver o meu problema.

Comment: cara - o approache "menos pythonic" não é "bem mais simples". join com genertor expression é o jeito certo de fazer isso (mas não com o map, map realmente quebra a legibilidade).

Answer (score 4):

Python tem essa ideia de ter um jeito que é o óbvio de resolver as coisas - mas nem sempre o óbvio é tão óbvio a primeira vista.
Esse problema sempre fica feio em outras linguagens, justamente porque você tem que deixar um caso especial para o último elemento.

Então, no caso de uma sequência que você não saiba o comprimento de antemão, (por exemplo, se está lendo de um arquivo) em outras linguagens você pode ter que usar uma variável auxiliar para saber se é a primeira interação, senão imprimir a "," no começo do loop:

```
primeiro = True
for i in sequencia:
    if not primeiro:
        print(", ", end="")
        primeiro = False
    print(i)
print()
```

Se a sequência tiver comprimento conhecido, como uma lista, pode-se fazer um "if" e não imprimir a ", " para o último elemento.

Em Python, as strings tem o método `join` que é bem interessante: ele concatena strings  de uma sequência usando a string inicial como separador. Então ele nunca imprime o separador nem no começo nem no final de uma sequência.

Então se tenho:

```
a = ["Universidade", "de", "Campinas"]
b = " ".join(a)
print(b)
```

Vai exibir

> Universidade de Campinas

O único problema é que sendo um método de string, o "join" espera que todos os elementos da sequência que vai concatenar sejam eles mesmos strings.

Aí  entra um outro elemento do Python - a linguagem tem uma forma sintática para resolver de forma sintética tudo o que resolve repetição (e filtros) de uma sequência - os chamados problemas de "mapeamento e filtragem": você usa um `for` como parte de uma expressão: você põe primeiro a expressão que quer usar para transformar todos os elementos da sequência, e aí escreve o "for" - por exemplo:

```
(elemento * 2 for elemento in sequencia)
```

Resultaria num iterador que entrega cada elemento da "sequencia" inicial multiplicado por 2.

Então, como queremos todos os elementos do vetor de números transformados numa string antes de chamar o "join", basta fazer:

```
print(", ".join(str(i) for i in range(12)))
```

Para fazer sua impressão dos elementos intercalados com ", ".

(Note que há uma diferença se o "for" de uma expressão é colocado entre colchetes (`[x for x in y]`)- isso sempre gera uma lista, com todos os elementos na memória - sem os colchetes adicionais, você tem um `generator` que pode ser usado uma única vez, com a diferença que os elementos são computados a medida que são usados e nunca são guardados todos na memória. Para uma chama imediata ao `join` isso não faz diferença).

Answer (score 4):

Resolvi dar uma resposta para esclarecer para quem está aprendendo algo que falo muito que é fazer códigos que não apenas funcionem, mas que estejam certos também.

## Melhor solução

Bem, no caso específico aqui não posso dizer que os códigos apresentados nas outras respostas estejam errados, e podem ser usados sem problemas. Especialmente em Python não vejo problema porque é uma linguagem de *script*, então meio que tanto faz. O problema é que muita gente usa Python para fazer aplicações e usam a linguagem para aprender programar. E como sempre falo:

> se você treina o erro e ele que fará para sempre

Antes de tudo o problema tem uma solução simples, pronta e eficiente em desempenho já postada:

```
print(", ".join(str(i) for i in range(12)))
```

Gostaria que a linguagem tivesse até algo mais eficiente já que o `for` de Python é consideravelmente mais lento que o laço que é feito dentro da maioria das funções padrões de biblioteca que na verdade são escritas em C e não passa pela máquina virtual de Python, pelo menos na implementação principal dela, que é a que quase todo mundo usa.

Na verdade, para apenas imprimir ela tem, o `print()` exatamente o que o AP deseja com uma sintaxe própria ligeiramente diferente da usada de forma mais curta e eficiente por não ter um laço rodando na máquina virtual:

```
print(*range(12), sep = ",")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5CrfsL). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/brokgsahzg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/PrintLastDistinct4.py).

Ainda terá um laço dentro da `range()`, mas não tem como fugir disto, toda linguagem terá que fazer um laço, e tem a vantagem de ser algo interno escrito em C, então é uma boa. Também terá um laço para a  [sintaxe `*` (como um *splice*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101) que transforma o conteúdo repetido em um resultado único, mas se o `range()` for um iterador bem feito isso não é tão crítico porque ele aproveitaria os dois laços como um só (não vou entrar em detalhes porque não é o foco aqui.

E provavelmente esta deveria ser a solução a ser adotada.

## Condicional de filtro

Novamente, não é que esteja errado, mas não faz muito sentido colocar um condicional dentro de um laço para tratar uma única exceção em uma posição que se sabe qual é. Isso deixa o código lento, fica feito, mais longo, difícil de entender (sob certo ponto de vista, isso pode ser subjetivo de acordo com a experiência de cada um) e aumenta a [complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193665/101). Esta resposta tenta mostrar a tal da "boa prática" que as pessoas tanto gostam e que em muitos casos não faz a diferença que as pessoas acham que faz. Portanto entenda que pode fazer com condicional.

Ninguém vai morrer se insistir no condicional, mas se for fazer o laço por conta própria trate a exceção fora do laço para não repetir várias vezes algo desnecessário. Aprenda isso para evitar em outros códigos como se faz, não porque deve seguir uma receita de bolo, mas para pensar em algoritmos.

## Sem condicional

O laço pode tratar todos os elementos de forma padrão e deixar o único elemento que é tratado de forma diferente em código diferente. É assim que se programa, encontrando o melhor caminho, não o primeiro que vêm à mente.

```
print(*(str(i) + "," for i in range(11)), end = "")
print(11)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZpXt7B). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/bsnfqiwkuj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/PrintLastDistinct.py).

Ou seguindo o padrão ao da pergunta, que fica até mais curto e de certa forma mais legível (pare já de querer fazer tudo curti, em uma linha, só faça onde faz sentido):

```
for i in range(11):
    print(i, end = ",")
print(11)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uuPoAf). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/kmeorbetvo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/PrintLastDistinct2.py).

Claro que este código pode ser feito com vários detalhes diferentes. Um exemplo é que já que a informação do valor limite passou ser usado em dois lugares então o certo seria criar uma constante para indicar isso (alguns dirão que já deveria ter feito isso mesmo quando usava em apenas um lugar, porque mesmo em uso único não deixa de ser um [número mágico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101)). Como Python não tem constante crie uma variável, e esta é só mais uma "boa prática" que estou mostrando do que deveria fazer para aprender bons códigos, mesmo que fique mais longo:

```
limite = 11
for i in range(limite):
    print(i, end = ",")
print(limite)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AZxIeR). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/tmcljlgqgq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/PrintLastDistinct3.py).

Se colocar isto em uma função fica até natural porque a variável seria um parâmetro já obrigatório. Até aconselho isso.

## Pior que condicional

E para terminar, se esforce em não usar variáveis chamadas de *flag*<sup>*</sup>, isso é estado e estado sempre complica o código. Pode ter caso que é melhor, mas geralmente mais atrapalha do que ajuda, tem casos que até um `goto` (tão demonizado, mas só porque as pessoas não o entendem) no lugar dela pode simplificar um código, em linguagens que tenha essa instrução de desvio de fluxo.

Isso é a mesma coisa do que as pessoas fazem quando defendem que deve escrever um código chamado de *pythônico*, ou seja, do jeito que a comunica prega que é a melhor forma, mesmo que outra forma funcione e esteja certa igualmente, é só uma questão subjetiva de estilo. Esta forma que estou apresentando é mais *programônica*, é mais elegante, subjetivamente.

## Conclusão

Reforço que o `join()` está ótimo, o `print()` com separador deve ser a melhor opção, mas todas as outras soluções apresentadas eu não gosto ou abomino, não queira fazer graça para parecer inteligente, o efeito é contrário, não faça isso com seu código.

Não vou medir a performance de cada um porque não é o objetivo, mas a diferença é muito pequena, ambas têm um laço, a solução do `join()` tem um laço interno extra nesta função, mesmo que feito em C é um custo extra que minha solução não tem, então ela deve ser mais lenta que a pura que eu coloquei aqui. Nem vou comparar com as que usam várias funções para atingir o resultado porque são mais laços sem necessidade. Só porque não vê não quer dizer que não tenha um laço. Imagine processar uma lista de bilhões de elementos em algo que é executado repetidas vezes em um cálculo maior.

Eu não quis entrar no uso de `while` porque não é tão *pythônico* e deve ser menos eficiente por ser código executando 100% em contexto Python não delegando nada para C, exceto pelo `print()`.

Agora com as informações por completo tome a melhor decisão em cada contexto.

---

<sup>*</sup>variável, geralmente booleana, para indicar um estado que será usada para decidir se deve executar algo ou não, então em determinada situação ele trocará de valor. Quase sempre é o mesmo que dizer que quer descer para baixo. Tem exemplo na outra resposta.