# Quadrado (figura geométrica) em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo

Tenho um exercício que é para formar um quadrado com o número que nos é dado.

Aqui está o código que realizei:

```
int altura=5;
int largura=5;

for(int i=0; i<altura; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<largura; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

}
```

O problema é que eu gostaria que o quadrado mostrasse apenas as arestas, ou seja dentro não teria os asteriscos, ou seja gostaria que aparecesse assim:

[image: quadrado]

Porém no meu código ele aparece todo "preenchido".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ou seja no seu exemplo tamanho 5x5

Primeiro veja quais são as posições

```
x.y

0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4
3.0 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4
4.0 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4
```

Então você quer que imprima as posições

do lado de cima ou seja  com x = 0

```
0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
```

do lado esquerdo ou seja com y = 0

```
0.0 
1.0 
2.0 
3.0 
4.0
```

do lado direito ou seja com y = 4 ou n-1

```
0.4
1.4
2.4
3.4
4.4
```

do lado abaixo com x = 4 ou n-1

```
4.0 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4
```

Então:

```
for(int i=0; i<altura; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<largura; j++)
    {

        if ( i==0 || j==0 || i == altura-1 || j == largura-1){
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

}
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Eu estava a tentar com um if, entretanto não estava a conseguir chegar ao altura-1, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int altura = 5;
        int largura = 5;
        for (int j = 0; j < largura; j++) System.out.print("* ");
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int i = 2; i < altura; i++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
            for (int j = 2; j < largura; j++) System.out.print("  ");
            System.out.print("* \n");
        } 
        for (int j = 0; j < largura; j++) System.out.print("* ");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QpyeHb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DrawSquarejava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/DrawSquare.java).

Você tira o que é fora do padrão do laço principal e evita condicionais sem necessidade que torna o código com mais [complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193665/101) e menos eficiente por gerar bem mais processamento e quebrar o *branch prediction* do processador.

Então você faz a primeira linha em um laço separado (primeiro `for`), assim como a última (poderia até criar uma função pra não repetir o código, mas para efeito de exercício não é necessário) que é o último `for`.

As linhas internas (`for` do meio) você faz considerando o asterisco no começo (primeiro `print()` dentro desse `for`) e no fim da linha (último `print()` dentro desse `for`) e o que é variável é só o espaço que fica no laço mais interno que só imprime espaço.

Claro que tanto na linha quanto na coluna você conta 2 a menos porque está fazendo-os fora do laço, por isso eu comecei no 2 e não no 0.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Também é uma boa solução, porém não percebi bem o porquê de em dois for o i e o j estão =2

Comment: Conforme está na resposta se está imprimindo duas linhas fora do laço de forma fora do padrão tem que imprimir duas linhas a menos no laço (o mesmo vale pras colunas), já fez fora, não pode fazer de novo essas duas, então em vez de começar pelo 0 comecei pelo 2.