# Como garantir que um método seja inline em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, otimização, inline

O que fazer para garantir que um método seja linearizado e com isso melhore o desempenho da aplicação? Tem algo como em C/C++ que diga que é para ser *inline*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#, assim como C ou C++, faz otimizações sempre que possível se tiver ganho real. Não está na especificação, mas os compiladores são permitidos fazer se não mudar o resultado, e eles fazem. Em C ou C++ costuma ser possível e há um investimento para que seja bem agressivo, desde que não tenha uma piora, e tem casos que a técnica pode piorar.

Em C#, o compilador é mais conservador e tem mais casos que ele não pode fazer o *inlining* de forma segura.

Assim como C ou C++, tem como quase forçar fazer o *inline*. Mas mesmo isso não obriga o compilador fazer, apenas aumenta a chance.

Existe um atributo que pode ser usado para indicar que você deseja essa otimização: [`MethodImpl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e o uso da enumeração [`MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Percebe-se que tem outras opções, até mesmo proibir o *inlining*.

Mas procure fazer isso apenas em métodos simples, pequenos, sem laços, sem grande [complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193665/101), sem tratamento de exceção, etc. Ou seja, se fizer certo, provavelmente não precisa ser agressivo. Se for muito ruim fazê-lo dizer que quer agressividade pode não dar resultado.

O compilador costuma saber melhor o que ficar mais eficiente. Tem poucos casos que você consegue informar melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Qual a vantagem de fazer isso?

Comment: Fica mais rápido, potencialmente.