# Qual a diferença de otimização linear e agressiva?

Tags: c#, .net, otimização

Estava lendo essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/579481/24529), que fala sobre otimização linear de métodos.

No entanto, o atributo `MethodImpl` fornece dois enumeradores que fornecem otimização: `AggressiveInlining` e `AggressiveOptimization`.

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
static int Sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

Qual a diferença entre eles, tanto na performance, estabilidade e uso real?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110886/101

Comment: Eu não sei bem como funciona a segunda, então não vou me arriscar. De qualquer forma isso em parte depende de implementação, pode mudar, a não ser o que está documentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A principal diferença entre as duas opções é a intensidade da otimização.
O nível de otimização agressiva é mais alto do que o linear, o que significa que o compilador vai realizar mais transformações no código para produzir um código mais eficiente. Isso pode incluir coisas como a eliminação de código morto, reordenação de instruções, substituição de chamadas de função por código inline etc

Resumidamente, quando se usa "AggressiveOptimization" o código final pode sofrer alterações significativas, podendo ocorrer (embora que muito raramente) alguns [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135509/bug-only-occurring-when-compile-optimization-enabled).

Já no caso do "AggressiveInlining", o compilador deve tentar incluir o corpo do método diretamente no local em que ele é chamado, em vez de criar uma chamada de método separada.

Comment: É legal mencionar que o JIT faz uma breve otimização no código presando pela velocidade de compilação. Usando o `AggressiveOptimization`, você indica que o método contém um "hot path", ou seja, indica que aquele método será muito usado pela aplicação, e acaba indicando o JIT a fazer uma otimização completa naquele método.

Comment: Além disso, "sendo mais propício a problemas", poderia especificar melhor quais problemas poderia ocorrer?

Comment: Por experiência, quanto mais agressiva a otimização, mais suscetível a bugs o código gerado é, irei adicionar um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Sinceramente, isso foi em 2010. O compilador foi reescrito desde o Roslyn. Nunca mais vi reclamações sobre otimização de código. Mas, se você diz, eu vou tomar cuidado :)

Comment: Sim, realmente não há muitos relatos, posso considerar editar a resposta, mas se aconteceu uma vez pode acontecer novamente, embora seja raro.

Answer (score -2):

O AggressiveInlining indica ao compilador que ele deve tentar inlining agressivo para o método anotado. O inlining é uma técnica de otimização em que o código do método é copiado diretamente para o local em que o método é chamado, em vez de fazer uma chamada explícita ao método. O inlining pode aumentar o desempenho do código, reduzindo a sobrecarga de chamadas de método, mas pode aumentar o tamanho do código gerado e pode tornar o código mais difícil de depurar.

Por outro lado, AggressiveOptimization indica ao compilador que ele deve tentar otimizar o código do método de forma agressiva, a fim de melhorar o desempenho. Essa opção pode resultar em código mais rápido, mas também pode introduzir instabilidade no código, já que algumas otimizações podem alterar o comportamento do programa.

Em geral, a opção AggressiveInlining é útil para métodos que são chamados com frequência e que são relativamente pequenos, enquanto a opção AggressiveOptimization é mais apropriada para métodos que são computacionalmente intensivos e que precisam ser executados rapidamente.