# Quantos parâmetros um método deve ter?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, método, parâmetros, projeto-de-software

Qual é o número máximo de parâmetros que um método deve ter?

Quando se deve considerar que há parâmetros demais?

E o que fazer nesse caso?

Versão tupiniquim e orientada a objetos da pergunta: [design - How many parameters are too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174968/how-many-parameters-are-too-many)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nunca trabalhe com números absolutos. Essas métricas não funcionam. Se algo assim pudesse ser determinado os compiladores proibiriam um número maior.

Você pode estabelecer algo para o seu projeto, mas é uma bobagem. No fundo isso é o que se chama "boa prática", ou seja, a pessoa estabelece uma regra porque não sabe como resolver o problema de forma conveniente.

**Deve ter tantos parâmetros quanto for necessário**.

Tem parâmetros demais quando eles não servem ao propósito do método. Eles são demais quando está passando o que não precisa. Em geral se você não está usando um parâmetro em determinada situação deve existir uma versão dele sem o parâmetro. Para tudo existe exceção. Devemos ser pragmáticos.

Algumas pessoas vão dizer que a solução para muitos parâmetros é passar um objeto. Até faz algum sentido, de fato se você tem vários parâmetros relacionados um objeto ali reduz a quantidade de parâmetros. Mas isso traz algum benefício de fato?

Você criará um objeto só para atender esse "requisito" de poucos parâmetros? E se fizer isso, formalmente diminuiu a quantidade de parâmetros, mas a quantidade de informação que entrou é a mesma. Qual o benefício disso? Performance? Mas não tem custo para construir esse objeto? Digitar menos? Mas digita menos mesmo? Sabe lidar com esse objeto corretamente? Sabe que pode ter a semântica diferente, já que provavelmente os parâmetros acabam sendo passados por referência?

E se o objeto já existir? Ótimo, né? Só passá-lo. Não digo que tem algo de errado nisto, se faz sentido, passe mesmo. Se sabe lidar bem com essa situação não há problema. Mas quem gosta de dizer de forma geral o que é bom fazer dirá que isto provoca [acoplamento excessivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) (esse é o mais importante que deve ler) já que é quase certo que estará passando dados que não são necessários para o método.

Aqui cabe um adendo sobre o livro Clean Code ou tudo o que o Uncle Bob fala, já que [há uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175035/221800) (e reproduzida em outra resposta aqui) na pergunta que serviu de inspiração que cita o livro. [O mesmo ocorre com o Code Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319295/221800). Eu acho que todo programador deve ler estes livros. Mas se ele não tiver personalidade, não tiver uma base muito boa, aquele livro poderá trucidar a mente da pessoa. Há coisas incoerentes no livro, há muita ideologia, há muita coisa sem justificativa plausível ou está sem contexto. Eu tenho medo quando um incauto lê essas coisas e começa seguir cegamente.

A maioria das respostas lá na pergunta falam de número baixo e tentam justificar o porquê disso. O problema é que elas não dão uma outra solução ou a outra solução sofre essencialmente do mesmo problema. Não existe mágica. Se o problema é complexo a solução será complexa. Só não pode ser complicada. E muitas vezes tentando maquiar a complexidade os programadores tendem a tornar tudo mais complicado. Vão adicionando camadas em cima de camadas sem necessidade. Só o fato de criar um objeto apenas para evitar passar argumentos é uma camada desnecessária e que não resolve algo já que terá que lidar com várias informações do mesmo jeito.

Ali você vê que as pessoas têm muita opinião e pouco senso real. O que mais se aproxima de uma solução é criar um objeto para evitar passar vários parâmetros, o que não resolve algo e torna o código mais complicado.

Claro que ter muitos parâmetros costuma mostrar que o método está fazendo coisas demais ou a estrutura de dados está mal formulada. Mas isso tem que ser analisado caso a caso. É claro que chega em um ponto que as coisas começam ficar confusas.

Quero ressaltar que ninguém deu uma solução para o caso que faz sentido o método ter vários parâmetros. Ninguém diz isso porque depende muito de contexto e em muitos casos não tem como fazer isso para resolver o problema de fato.

O que não pode mesmo é passar argumentos sem necessidade. Se o método estiver fazendo coisas demais provavelmente ele recebe parâmetros demais. Mas o problema aí é de responsabilidade e não de parâmetros em excesso. Resolva o problema certo. É a mesma questão do [número de linhas que a função deve ter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31473/101).

As pessoas acham que as coisas são [ortogonais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101) quando elas não são. Elas acham que mudando o argumento de lugar resolve algum problema, quando só o muda de lugar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E problema de responsabilidade é um problema de falta de coesão da classe, correto?

Comment: Não só da classe, do método mesmo. Não existe regra mágica que defina a responsabilidade. É uma questão de colheita correta de requisitos, interpretação e uso adequado dos mecanismo certos.

Comment: Acredito que criar uma Classe (mesmo que privada e interna) para agrupar as variáveis melhore a organização e torne o código mais fácil de entender. Uma vez criei um Map com três Maps dentro para estruturar os Dados retornados por um método e enviados para outro da mesma classe, torna-se muito confuso fazer uma coisa dessas.

Answer (score 3):

### Qual é o número máximo de parâmetros que um método deve ter?

> O número ideal de argumentos para um método é zero (niládico). Em
>   seguida vem um (monádico), seguido de perto por dois (diádico). Três
>   argumentos (triádicos) devem ser evitados sempre que possível. Mais de
>   três (poliádico) requer justificação muito especial - e então não deve
>   ser usado de qualquer maneira.

*E como sempre temos essa "justificativa muito especial", não há um número certo de parâmetros que você diga que está correto em um método, a questão é a necessidade que você está tendo, o que o seu método vai fazer, quais regras de negócio estão envolvidas nesse processo. Aqui entra o seu bom senso, você não pode também querer deixar parâmetros inutilizados. Crie o método utilizando o mínimo de parâmetros possíveis.*

### Gosto muito da opinião abaixo a respeito do tema:

> Eu odeio fazer regras duras e rápidas como este porque a resposta muda
>   não só dependendo do tamanho e escopo do seu projeto, mas acho que
>   muda até mesmo para o nível do módulo. Dependendo do que seu método
>   está fazendo, ou o que a classe é suposto representar, é bem possível
>   que 2 argumentos é demais e é um sintoma de muito acoplamento.
>   [referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174968/how-many-parameters-are-too-many)

### Conclusão

***Varia de projeto a projeto, você deve buscar o número correto de parâmetros de acordo com sua necessidade.***

Comment: E quando tenho um WebMethod com quatro ou cinco parâmetros, como posso reduzir isso? Passando um objeto em vez de vários parâmetros?

Comment: Por que o número ideal de um método é zero ?

Comment: @MagicHat método com parâmetro vazio, porém quase nunca acontece, eu mesmo, faço uma assim poucas vezes...

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber por que ele é considerado ideal.

Comment: @MagicHat na disciplina de análise de algoritmos vista normalmente na faculdade de ciências da computação, estudamos muito essa parte de qual código é mais "Leve" em relação ao outro, então essa ideia da quantidade de parâmetros ideal ser 0 diz respeito a "leveza" do código. É por conta dessa disciplina de análise de algoritmos que existe esse tipo de comentário, sobre o "ideal".

Comment: Ahhhh...Faz sentido agora....Visto que está havendo uma comparação sem parâmetros na citação...

Comment: Um método com parâmetro vazio não indica que ele é "leve". Uma forma que isso poderia ser justificado seria por simplicidade e/ou facilidade de uso. Mas não concordo.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann porém qualquer tamanho de byte é considerado nesse tipo de estudo, eles criam toda uma teoria por trás, que foi aprovada em vários lugares do mundo, durante anos, e só nos resta aceitar o teorema do autor. Até surgir um fundamento melhor e a ideia anterior seja descartada.

Comment: Eu entendo oque você quer dizer Philip, mas ainda assim, não é isso que define se é "leve" ou não. Um método com 5 parâmetros `int` que soma todos eles e retorna o valor é mais "pesado" que um método sem parâmetro que realize milhares de loops com cálculos de números grandes? Mas não vamos estender aqui, se quiser entender melhor meu ponto de vista me chame no chat.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann eu entendi sim colega, enfim, não existe algo 100% em nenhuma ideia definida no mundo, então estou aberto a outras opiniões.

Answer (score 3):

## Métricas são relevantes, você deve usá-las!

Você deve sim fazer uso de valores "clássicos" e se basear neles para, caso sejam "desobedecidos", fazer a devida investigação, que pode resultar na necessidade de ajuste do código ou na constatação de um falso positivo. Neste sentido, se faz uso de Java, entendo que deve fazer uso de ferramentas como Checkstyle e PMD, eventualmente calibrar os valores para um valor de referência a ser usado no seu contexto. Por exemplo, salvo engano, Checkstyle sugere no máximo 7 argumentos (valor padrão desta ferramenta).

Se ultrapassar 7, então é oportuno investigar. Não significa que há um erro, nem tampouco que os métodos com menos de 7 estão "corretos", certo? Contudo, agora, há um limite que pode ser automaticamente verificado. Talvez seu contexto configure para 5 ou até para 25 (que é maior que a quantidade de registradores de um i7), de qualquer forma, e em ambos os casos, você terá uma orientação acerca de onde oferecer atenção adicional.

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma regra! Assim como citado por outros amigos, deve ser levar em conta a necessidade do trabalho.

Sem Parâmetro:

```
            var product = new BllProduct
            {
                Code = TxtQueryByCode.Text,
                Size = TxtQueryBySize.Text,
                Reference = TxtQueryByReference.Text,
                Description = TxtQueryByDescription.Text,
                DataPagination = dataPagination
            };

            product.FetchData();
```

Com parâmetro:

```
            var product = new BllProduct()
            product.FetchData(TxtQueryByCode.Text, TxtQueryBySize.Text, 
            TxtQueryByRefence.Text, TxtQueryByDescription.Text, OffSetValue, 
            PageSize);
```

**FechData()** é um método de interface e seria complicado usar essa interface em outras partes do sistema. Para fazer isso tenho que deixar alguns parâmetros NULL, já que no meu caso um cliente não tem buscas por tamanho(SIZE). Ou então criar um método de busca para cada negócio, mas prefiro reaproveitar o método pois acho mais simples.

Isso é apenas um exemplo do contexto do meu trabalho, tem momentos que utilizo alguns parâmetros também, por exemplo:

```
        public static void ShowReport(string path, string reportName, 
        bool isEmbeddedResource, 
        Dictionary<string, object> dataSources)
        {

         var frmReportView = new FrmReportView(path, reportName, isEmbeddedResource,
         dataSources);

         frmReportView.Show();

        }
```

Esse método é genérico e seu trabalho principal não muda. Eu posso usá-lo  para exibir qualquer relatório sem a necessidade de modificar seus parâmetros para cada novo report. Repare, passei até muitos parâmetros porem o contexto da atividade foi diferente para cada caso.