# Amontoar coisas em uma função x DRY

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação, princípios-de-programação, dry

Essa parte em negrito tirada [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120932/357) não ficou muito clara para mim:

> *DRY soluciona o quê?*
>
> Alguns ainda podem estar pensando que DRY é para reduzir digitação. Ou pelo menos ganhar tempo de manutenção. Até é no último caso, mas não porque tem menos código por si só (ainda que menos código sempre ajude alguma coisa). A redução no tempo de manutenção é não ter que ficar caçando as redundâncias, fazer tranquilamente uma mudança sabendo que tudo continuará consistente, sem ter que arrumar erros que nem imagina que acontecerá quando mudar algo.
>
> DRY exige que qualquer informação de código seja única. DRY cria uma fonte autoritativa de como deve ser um comportamento.
>
> Feito corretamente aumenta a coesão e diminui o acoplamento. Feito errado...
>
> DRY ajuda ter responsabilidade única. **Tentar amontoar as coisas em uma função só para evitar repetição só piora o SRP. Por isso é que é importante distinguir DRY de eliminação de repetição.**
>
> DRY concretamente evita pesadelos de manutenção. Mais abstratamente exige que o programador pense no que está fazendo, porque ele está colocando aquele código ali e se pode fazer de outra forma para uso futuro. DRY é planejamento.

Tem a ver, em OOP, com quebrar um método que faz muitas coisas em objetos distintos? Alguém teria um exemplo? (não precisa ser OOP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem a ver com OOP, tem a ver com modularização. OOP pode ser uma técnica a ser usada para isso. Quebrar algo em vários métodos nem é algo de OOP mesmo, OOP pode facilitar porque você não tem que que ficar passando argumentos quando chama métodos que faz só uma parte da tarefa, algo que pode ser viso com mais detalhes em [Quantos parâmetros um método deve ter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197735/101). É fato que você ter uma estrutura de dados única acessível em um método sem você fazer esforço adicional incentiva você quebrar os métodos em pedaços pequenos mantendo uma única responsabilidade. Nada impede de fazer de outra forma, mas se tiver que usar parâmetros para se comunicar a tendência é você preferir quebrar menos (é mais ou menos o que acontece com o Git e outros VCSes distribuídos, eles acabam incentivando você fazer mais *commits* com pequenas alterações).

Tem coisas que a gente escreve porque tem algo em mente no momento, nem sempre fica claro mesmo, pode ter influência de algo que havia acontecido a pouco. Então eu não lembro exatamente o que se passava naquele momento :) Eu sei o que isso significa no geral.

O que eu acho que quis dizer aí foi menos sobre amontoar coisas e mais sobre a repetição. E talvez fosse sobre o que eu disse no primeiro parágrafo acima. Talvez algumas pessoas pensem que ficar passando dados pra lá e para cá gere repetições de código. Eu sei de muita gente que prefere fazer um linguição para não ter que fazer isso. Eventualmente para fazer DRY e seguir o SRP você tem que repetir alguma coisa, tem que escrever algum código de cola que parece que já fez antes.

Um outro caso que me vem à mente é o uso da sobrecarga. Algumas pessoas podem achar que criar várias sobrecargas vai repetir o cabeçalho da função ou até mesmo partes do código, e fazendo um só tomando decisões do que realizar pode diminuir a repetição, mas piora o SRP, e performance.

Em muitos casos, mesmo que o código fique mais longo, pode ser mais legível criar algo canônico. Algumas pessoas acham exagerado, e pode ser mesmo em alguns casos, mas pode haver ganhos de expressividade interessantes quando por exemplo cria um método só para estabelecer uma condição e chame esse método em um `if` ou outro lugar que seja pertinente. O método dá um nome para o que é aquilo, fica mais SRP e possivelmente mais DRY porque sempre que precisar saber sobre o estado atendendo aquela condição tem um método pronto para isso e não tem que caçar pra ver se não está reinventando a roda, se tem que mudar em algum lugar.

Dá para pensar em alguns casos que é melhor separar uma parte do código, mesmo que ele não seja usado repetidamente em outras partes. DRY pode não evitar a repetição, mas ele sempre deixa mais óbvio o que está fazendo.