# Código limpo: funções e métodos devem fazer uma coisa só? Isto torna o código mais manutenível?

Tags: funções, método, estilo-de-codificação, solid, princípios-de-programação

A pergunta-título é retirada das orientações do conhecido livro *Clean Code* (Código Limpo). Seguem abaixo um trecho original, pego da Internet, e uma tradução livre do mesmo:

> A function should do one simple thing and do it well. In clean coding, this means that you should simplify (and even over-simplify) your functions so that they are small and straightforward. Likewise, they need a good name that describes what they do. If you're at a loss, simply ask yourself what each function does.

Traduzindo:

> Uma função deve fazer uma coisa simples e fazê-la bem. Em programação limpa, isto significa que você deve simplificar (e até mesmo simplificar demais) as suas funções de maneira que elas fiquem pequenas e objetivas. Da mesma forma, elas precisam de um bom nome que descreva o que elas fazem. Se você estiver em dúvida, simplesmente pergunte a si mesmo o que é que a função faz.

Não tenho muita experiência com isso, as minhas funções e métodos tendem a amontoar coisas ([relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451443/357)). Mas quando tentei praticar me pareceu que reduzir o número de reponsabilidades de cada função deixou o código mais manutenível, embora mais lento para mexer pois não estava acostumado a trabalhar nesse nível de granularidade.

**Funções e métodos com uma única responsabilidade tendem a ser mais manuteníveis?** Minha breve experiência me fez crer que sim, e que as funções em geral ficam mais propensas à extração de padrões e ao reúso.

Relacionado a isso há o mantra de deixar as funções curtas. É similar, porém tem menos relação causa-efeito; o verdadeiro objetivo deveria ser realizar uma coisa só, mesmo que essa coisa ocupe um certo número de linhas, e evitar juntar várias "coisas" desconexas em uma função só, que fogem de uma única responsabilidade, mesmo ocupando poucas linhas.

Comment: Confesso que fiquei confuso com a pergunta "funções devem fazer uma coisa só?" e nela mesma você coloca um trecho de um livro bem conceituado dizendo que sim. O que espera como resposta?

Comment: _"Funções e métodos que realizam uma única tarefa tendem a ser mais manuteníveis?"_ Sempre que eu posso, aplico esse conceito pois fica, não só mais fácil de dar manutenção, como também de escrever os testes de unidade para aquele código. Porém, trabalho em projetos de MS em que eu percebi que essa granularidade em excesso, acabou gerando duplicação de código por parte do antigo dev, o que dificulta a terefa de manutenção. Tipo, a pessoa tinha uma boa ideia, mas não organizou direito os códigos.

Comment: Em OOP, eu gosto de considerar que membros no geral possuem **uma única responsabilidade**, mas que isso não quer dizer necessariamente que eles devem fazer apenas uma coisa. Eles podem fazer mais de uma coisa, desde que a responsabilidade deles permitam e que seja bem explícito isso.

Comment: @Woss Acho que a pergunta por trás que eu queria fazer era se funções assim tornam o código mais manutenível. Acabei de mudar. Para muitas pessoas essa forma de programar não é intuitiva, por isso a pergunta que fiz originalmente me soava como a que elas fariam ao motor de busca.

Comment: Pra quem estiver se perguntando sobre a palavra "manutenível": é feia, mas existe :)

Comment: @bfavaretto até me levantou a questão: a definição de "manutenível" é clara ou acaba sendo abstrata? haha

Comment: @bfavaretto e desde quando você entende de palavras? :P só pra relembrar os velhos tempos quando isso era divertido :D

Comment: @Woss provavelmente foi empréstimo do inglês, herdando a definição. Só verifiquei que consta do vocabulário ortográfico da ABL (o VOLP)

Comment: @bfavaretto A pergunta foi mais no sentido de "o que é manutenível para mim é o mesmo que para você?" ou isso dependerá de requisitos, necessidade do time, pessoa, etc. Foi mais uma curiosidade se realmente é possível classificar como "mais manutenível".

Comment: @Woss Fiquei mesmo na dúvida se eu tinha entendido seu comentário :). Verdade, uma parte depende, mas existem práticas/protocolos que costumam ajudar no geral. Realmente o SRP dá uma ajuda nesse sentido, eu acho. Pode até ser adaptado para os níveis mais altos da arquitetura do software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boa parte disto está em [O que é e como se usa o SRP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101).

Todo o assunto é sobre manter a [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101), que é o que importa.

Então a resposta para pergunta é sim. Fazendo desta forma, provavelmente aplicando o DRY (não vou colocar *link* em tudo aqui porque já tem nos outros), deixará o código mais fácil de dar manutenção. O objetivo é todo e quase que só este (obviamente que em alguns é só questão de dar flexibilidade).

Precisa? Nem sempre.

Você consegue fazer de uma forma que sempre fica melhor? Não.

Pode piorar? Pode.

Tende dar um pouco mais de trabalho para dar manutenção? Sim, por mais estranho que pareça, afinal ser mais fácil nada tem a ver com ser menor ou dar menos trabalho.

Tudo depende de contexto. Esta é a beleza e dificuldade de fazer software.

Nem entrei nas questões de performance.

Me lembro de uma vez que um aluno da faculdade pediu para eu ajudar com um exercício que o professor mandou deixar só uma responsabilidade por função o máximo que pudesse. Eu fiz para ele. O código virou praticamente Assembly de alto nível. Sempre é possível exagerar e ficar pior. Por isso tem que entender do domínio, tem que fazer certas proteções, especialmente com APIs que devem ser públicas e depois não dá muito para consertar.

Não pode fazer de tal forma que começa violar YAGNI, KISS, DRY, etc. Quando você olha para um princípio e esquece dos outros está fazendo errado, mesmo que não dê problema.

Mas adotando responsabilidade única e nomes bons, o código fica mais expressivo, tende ser mais legível e pode ajudar. Só testando, praticando e vendo onde cabe ou não. Evoluir na programação é experimentar e avaliar. Ninguém fica bom sem fazer ambos. Experimentar já pressupõe um questionamento.

Mas tome cuidado. Tem função que o objetivo é justamente juntar coisas. Provavelmente ela em si não faz mais que uma coisa, o que ela faz é a junção, que não deixa de ser só uma coisa, mas no resultado ela está realizando indiretamente mais que uma coisa.

Se eu não estiver confundindo de livro, esse mesmo diz que se você colocar um `and` no nome da função provavelmente está fazendo algo errado. Não gosto muito disso, porque apesar de ser verdade, direciona um pouco para a pessoa achar que não pode e se não tiver a palavra está ok, já que ele é todo cheio de regras que as pessoas pegam para seguir (o livro diz para não seguir cegamente, mas muitos não seguem essa regra). A função pode estar justamente fazendo algo e ainda outra coisa, e esta será a única função dela.

Você tem que achar uma função única para ela, sem ficar forçando para que seja. Isso não tem regra e ninguém te ensina, tem que fazer e melhorar nas próximas, quem sabe pedindo para outras pessoas, possivelmente mais experientes, dar pitaco. Elas podem te ajudar, ou atrapalhar.

Eu vou no que parece mais óbvio e depois refatoro se precisar. Não exagero nem para um lado ou para outro, ou tento.

Hoje vejo mais abuso de fazer funções "curtas" demais do que o contrário, embora ainda aconteça, já apareceu aqui um método de 35 mil linhas (eu confiante em dizer que ele tinha mais de uma responsabilidade, e de fato não sei como ele colocou tantas em um só lugar).

Pessoas com boa memória, que trabalham sozinhas, fazendo códigos mais simples, e não cometem outros erros piores, podem até não cumprir muito essa recomendação aqui e ali. Tudo pode fazer se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo e se responsabilizar pela consequência.

Curto e responsabilidade única não são sinônimos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).