# Método em PHP tem limites de linha?

Tags: php, netbeans, método

> O tamanho do método é 22 linhas. (20 Permitido)

O NetBeans me da esse "aviso", isso por que? É uma regra do PHP?

O que é melhor:

1. Um método grande com com todo código de que ele precisa.
2. Dividir esse código em métodos menores
3. Existe uma um numero adequado de linhas em um método?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31473/101

Comment: Recomendo o livro Código Limpo, de Robert Martin, ele aborda de forma bem clara as melhores práticas para criação de classes, métodos, além de vários outros pontos extremamente importantes para um desenvolvimento ágil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é uma **sugestão** do netbeans não existe nenhum limite de linhas ou caracteres para um método. O ideal é que ele resolve apenas um problema ou seja tenha apenas um responsabilidade.

> 1) Um método grande com todo código de que ele precisa.

Nessa situação existe uma grande possibilidade do método estar fazendo várias coisas.

> 2) Dividir esse código em métodos menores

Em alguns casos é a melhor solução.

> 3) Existe um numero adequado de linhas em um método?

Não.

Comment: Obrigado, rray! Boa noite!

Comment: Basta lembrar das [unidades de códigos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878).

Comment: Esse é o pior tipo de "boa prática" que conheço, forçado pelo IDE sem contexto algum.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do rray esta boa, só adicionar uma coisa:
Você deixar os métodos menos específicos tem haver com reuso de código, com métodos menos específicos você pode reaproveita-los mais.

Talvez isso seja melhor visto quando se esta na parte de design na aplicação ou depois quando você vai rever o código e vê que tem muita coisa repetida que poderia ser feita uma vez só e reaproveitada mais de uma vez.

Comment: Eu acho que entendo o que quis dizer, mas "métodos menos específicos" passa uma ideia errada.

Answer (score 0):

> O NetBeans me da esse "aviso", isso por que? É uma regra do PHP?

Conforme esta [thread](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227747) no `bug tracking` do [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/), é apenas um `hint` que pode ser desabilitado em `Editor > Hints`.

E não, isso não é uma regra do `PHP`. Para o `PHP` costumamos seguir a [`PSR`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/), acrônimo para `PHP Standards Recommendations`, onde nela há padrões definidos pela comunidade para uniformizar o desenvolvimento com a linguagem. Na sua dúvida em específico, há o tópico [`2.3. Lines`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#lines) que diz o seguinte:

- A linha não deve possuir um limite rigoroso em seu comprimento. O máximo deve ser 120 caracteres, exibindo um `warning` mas não ocasionando `error`. O ideal é que seja 80 caracteres ou menos, porém caso seja necessário pode-se quebrá-la.
- Um comando por linha;

> 1. Um método grande com com todo código de que ele precisa.
> 2. Dividir esse código em métodos menores
> 3. Existe uma um numero adequado de linhas em um método?

Essas três dúvidas entram mais sobre padrões e arquiteturas de desenvolvimento, então tentarei responder em uma única tacada:

Conforme esta [thread no software engineering / se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method-for-you), Robert Martin em seu livro, [`Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship`](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882), diz:

> A primeira regra de funções é que elas devem ser pequenas. A segunda regra é que elas deveriam ser menores que isso. Não devem possuir mais que 100 linhas. Dificilmente deveriam passar das 20 linhas.

Se um método é grande e realmente há necessidade disso, é um caso específico do teu software. Mas se puder analisá-lo melhor, verifique se ela entra de acordo com o `Princípio da Responsabilidade Única`, o também Robert Martin diz que ela deve ser responsável por apenas uma coisa.

A divisão em códigos menores também compreende também nos seguintes tópicos:

- Testabilidade
- Coesão e Acoplamento
- Compreensão

Dica de leitura:

- [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code 1st Edition
  by Martin Fowler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201485672)
- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture 1st Edition
  by Martin Fowler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321127420)
- [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship 1st Edition
  by Robert C. Martin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)

Comment: Falta uma coisa pra que eu concorde 100%, esses números são quase arbitrários e servem para vender produtos, fazer parecer que o IDE é melhor do que, livros, palestras, etc. As pessoas adoram essas coisas, mas elas mais criam problemas que soluções.

Comment: Não entendi, @bigown. Quais números? O informado no `hint` da `ide`? Também não concordo com esses `style code` empurrado goela a baixo.

Comment: Tudo que tenta colocar em números algo que não pode ser colocado desta forma. IDE, livros, etc.