# O que define um código limpo?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

Vi esse termo sendo empregado diversas vezes, muitas pessoas e empresas querem que seus códigos sejam "limpos"... Vi também o livro [Código Limpo Habilidades Práticas do Agile Software](http://www.livrariasaraiva.com.br/produto/2666082/codigo-limpo-habilidades-praticas-do-agile-software-edicao-revisada/).

Mas eu queria saber o que define um código ser limpo ou não? Quais os pontos são avaliados uma vez que o conhecimento e o domínio sobre uma determinada linguagem pode influenciar na avaliação de quem está lendo.

Na pergunta ["Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13890/como-escrever-um-c%C3%B3digo-leg%C3%ADvel-e-de-f%C3%A1cil-manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o) temos alguns exemplos de um código que aparentemente está bem escrito, porém o domínio da linguagem é que faz bastante diferença na hora de interpretá-lo.

Então focando bem a pergunta, quais o pontos que são avaliados? Qual a importância e o peso de cada um desses pontos dentro da avaliação?

Gostaria principalmente das referências para estudar um pouco mais a fundo, e que não fosse limitado a um paradigma (ex: Orientação a Objeto) e sim num contexto geral.

Comment: Ainda estou pensando sobre as *tags*, não sei se esta é mais adequada. Respondi porque acho que dá para ter uma resposta objetiva. Claro que as anteriores não estavam ajudando variavam entre algo muito específico que dá margem para a subjetividade até a definição explícita de que é opinião. Evitei negativá-las mas no meu entendimento fogem do que foi perguntado. A culpa pelas opiniões não parece ser da pergunta.

Comment: @bigown também estou pensando sobre a tag, está dificil definir e também não sei como poderia ser o nome para uma nova tag...

Comment: A resposta para esta pergunta ou é subjetiva e por isso não útil, ou é sucinta e por isso não útil, ou rende um livro. Leia o livro do Uncle Bob que você citou (464 páginas na versão original em inglês) e encontrará o que procura. Aqui no SO você não vai encontrar.

Comment: @Caffé infelizmente não disponho de tempo hábil para uma leitura tão extensa, por isso achei que poderia achar algo mais resumido dos profissionais que lidam com isso

Comment: Continue lendo as respostas e veja que infelizmente você não achará algo resumido e ao mesmo tempo útil para você. Mas posso sugerir uma filosofia para te pôr no caminho: o código precisa contar uma história, precisa poder ser lido e entendido como se estivesse em português muito claro e contando uma história que faz muito sentido ao negócio que o software atende - sem depender de comentários.

Comment: @Caffé ele só quer a definição, não um tratado sobre o assunto. O livro citado é um tratado (e por ser detalhado, discutível) sobre o assunto. Um resumo dos princípios podem ser úteis. Claro que a utilidade é limitada, mas as respostas não precisam encerrar o assunto, não precisam ser teses. Aliás, em Métodos e Técnicas de Pesquisa aprendemos bem isto. Se resumos fossem inúteis, cientistas não deveriam publicá-los. Eu deliberadamente não citei fontes porque quando detalha costuma ser tendencioso favorecendo uma técnica sobre outra sem base nenhuma.

Comment: @bigown Não entendi a qual parte do meu comentário você se refere, já que eu não disse que o livro é indiscutível, não disse que resumos são inúteis, não disse que as respostas precisem encerrar o assunto nem que devam ser teses. Além disso, o que você disse sobre cientistas e resumos não fez o menor sentido pra mim. Eu apenas tentei orientar o perguntador. E por enquanto está bem fácil enquadrar todas as respostas aqui: sem utilidade para o perguntador nem para o visitante do SO.

Comment: E tão pouco eu não disse que você disse que o livro é indiscutível, apenas estou dando uma informação relevante. No outro ponto citando você: "sucinta e por isso não útil". Eu sei que não fez sentido para você mas deve ter feito para quem sabe como funciona a comunidade científica, que informações sucintas são úteis também para evolução da ciência. Imagina em um ambiente mais informal como o nosso como pode ser útil. Tem quem discorde com você quanto a utilidade da pergunta e das repostas (pelo menos de uma), e tem quem concorde.

Comment: @bigown "Eu sei que não fez sentido para você mas deve ter feito para quem sabe como funciona a comunidade científica" é um estratagema ingênuo. Como estamos na página de uma pergunta em específico, não útil por sucinta refere-se, naturalmente, à característica das respostas para esta pergunta em específico; e não à evolução da ciência, tampouco ao nosso modelo informal do SO.

Comment: Abra o livro que você mencionou no primeiro capítulo que você vai ver. Preste bastante atenção na primeira ilustração, que diz qual é **a única métrica de qualidade válida para código fonte** ;)

Comment: @Renan vou dar uma olhada nesse capitulo então :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Não há definição formal e duvido que um dia vá existir (é sintomático que não exista verbete na Wikipedia). Ele é subjetivo. Sempre que alguém disser o que é, desconfie. Mas é claro que algumas observações podem ser feitas independente de opinião. É óbvio que elas são vagas e não vão ajudar muito a definir com clareza o que é o termo, mas também não farão presunções tendenciosas.

- O fluxo de execução da aplicação é facilmente entendível, não importa em que paradigma, (não entenda fluxo só como o fluxo imperativo).
- Os diversos objetos (nada a ver com OOP) tem relacionamento claramente definidos e é fácil percebê-los.
- O papel e responsabilidade de cada participante da aplicação (classes, funções, variáveis, etc.) são claros, possivelmente com nome bem escolhido.

No momento não consigo lembrar de nada mais que não seja específico e subjetivo demais para ser aplicado como uma forma geral de entendimento do assunto.

Então o código precisa:

- Ser fácil de **entender** por quem nunca o tinha visto antes.
- Possibilita **manutenção** sem grandes sobressaltos.
- Funciona **corretamente**.

Claro que espera-se que o leitor do código seja um desenvolvedor capacitado, quem entenda bem a linguagem onde está escrito e entenda os fundamentos da computação. A não ser que um código seja escrito para fins didáticos não é obrigação do código limpo explicar de qualquer forma seu funcionamento para leigos (mesmo aqueles que são remunerados como desenvolvedores, isto existe, e muito).

Aí podemos começar definir algumas coisas mais específicas que ajudam cumprir estes três requisitos destacados acima:

- As unidades de código devem ser curtas e ter apenas uma responsabilidade.
- As partes "públicas" (a API) devem ser claras (óbvias, sem surpresas) e concisas (faz o mínimo necessário).
- As estruturas de dados e algoritmos devem funcionar como o esperado.
- O código deve ser facilmente verificável.
- Códigos devem ser organizados e expressivos (concisamente indica a sua intenção)

Além disto provavelmente está indo além da definição básica e começa entrar no campo subjetivo.

Eu até usei uma fonte bem recente para escrever esta resposta. Nem vou citá-la porque o meu texto está suficientemente diferente e o original induz à ditadura do mono paradigma que tão bem o AP renegou. Paradigmas não são mágicos, não resolvem problemas. São ferramentas que podem ser mais ou menos adequados.

O primeiro capítulo do livro está [disponível como artigo](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1235624). Conforme o livro vai se aprofundando ele vai sugerindo certas coisas que são discutíveis. O livro não é ruim, todo mundo deveria lê-lo, porém quem não está suficientemente preparado acaba comprando indiscriminadamente algumas técnicas, no mínimo, duvidosas.

Na [pergunta que foi citada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14275/101) pelo AP eu faço uma análise rápida do livro e outro que trata de assunto semelhante.

---

Só um adendo para não passar a falsa impressão que 100% do código escrito deva ser limpo. Claro que isto seria ideal mas há certos domínios em conjunto com certos requisitos que conflita com o conceito de código limpo. Pode ser raro, não ser aplicável em determinados tipos de projeto, mas existem situações assim. Como em tudo, você deve saber quando perseguir um ideal e quando ser pragmático e resolver o problema da forma mais adequada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sobre seu adendo, só gostaria de sugerir que, a forma mais adequada é sempre a mais limpa. O melhor é sempre escrever código limpo (mesmo que seja subjetivo, faça o seu melhor). Nem sempre essa possibilidade existirá, mas pensar que você pode se dar o luxo de decidir quando ou não fazê-lo pode fomentar a qualidade horrível do que temos visto por aí. Na primeira dificuldade o desenvolvedor vai abandonar suas práticas e voltar para o hack-n-slash.

Comment: Um exemplo de onde não se pôde ter código limpo foi na implementação do OpenSSL. Conseguiram identificar qual era a chave privada de acordo com ondas de baixas frequências na hora de transportar variáveis entre registradores, então o código precisou ficar propositadamente sujo para dar um arenque vermelho de modo que o atacante não consiga descobrir qual é a chave primária

Answer (score 8):

Existem vários fatores que definem um código limpo, alguns que considero importantes:

- Cada função/método tenha uma única responsabilidade bem definida, realizando uma única ação.
- A utilização de nomes de variáveis, classes e funções descritivos, sem ambiguidade.
- Indentação do código.