# Passar array como parâmetro

Tags: java, array, parâmetros

Tenho uma dúvida em relação a *arrays*. Então, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Objetos.....

    ColeçãoCidades ListaCidades = new ColeçãoCidades();

    //Adicionar regiões
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite quantas regiões serão criadas: ");
    int quant = sc.nextInt();

    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);

    Regiao[] regioes = new Regiao[quant];
    for (int i=0;i<quant;i++){
        System.out.print("\nInforme o nome da região: ");
        String reg = sc3.next();
        System.out.print("\nINforme o código da região: ");
        int cod = sc3.nextInt();
        regioes[i]= new Regiao(cod,reg);
    }


    // Menu
    MenuCidade(ListaCidades);
    }


    private static void MenuCidade(ColeçãoCidades lista) {

    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int op;

    do{
        // Apresentar as opções
        System.out.print("\n\tSegue abaixo as opções disponíveis para o menu cidade...\n\n" + 
                        "1) Adicionar cidade\n" + 
                        "2) Pesquisar Cidades Por Região\n" + 
                        "3) Pesquisar Cidades Por Estado\n" + 
                        "4) Pesquisar Cidades Por País\n" + 
                        "5) Pesquisar Cidades com Mais de 'X' habitantes\n" + 
                        "6) Remover cidade por nome\n" +
                        "7) Remover cidade por código\n" +
                        "8) Pesquisar Cidades Com Nível De Complexidade Maior Que 'X'\n" +
                        "0) Sair\n");
        System.out.print("Digite uma opção: ");
        op = sc2.nextInt();

        // Verificar se o valor dado está entre as opções válidas...
                    if((op < 0) || (op > 8)){
                        System.out.println("\n\tOpção inválida - Tente novamente");
                    }else
                    switch(op){

                    case 1: Cidade cid = new Cidade();
                            Cidade(cid);
                            lista.adicionarCidade(cid);
                            break;

                    case 2: System.out.print("NOme da região: ");
                            String regiao = sc2.nextLine();
                            lista.pesquisaCidadesPorRegião(regiao);
                            break;

                    case 3: System.out.print("NOme do Estado: ");
                            String estado = sc2.nextLine();
                            lista.pesquisaCidadesPorEstado(estado);
                            break;

                    case 4: System.out.print("Nome do País: ");
                            String pais = sc2.nextLine();
                            lista.pesquisaCidadesPorPaís(pais);
                            break;

                    //case 5:

                    case 6: System.out.print("Nome da cidade: ");
                            String nome = sc2.nextLine();
                            lista.removeCidadePorNome(nome);
                            break;

                    case 7: System.out.print("Código da cidade: ");
                            int codigo = sc2.nextInt();
                            lista.removeCidadePorCódigo(codigo);
                            break;

                    //case 8:

                    }
    }while (op!=0);

}   


    public static void Cidade (Cidade cid){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Apresentar o menu cadastro...
    System.out.println("\n\tCadastro de nova cidade");

    System.out.print("\nCódigo da cidade: ");
    int codigo = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\nNome da cidade: ");
    String nome = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nPopulação: ");
    double populacao = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("\nEstado: ");
    String estado = sc.next();

    System.out.print("\nPaís: ");
    String pais = sc.next();

    System.out.print("\nRegião: ");
    String reg = sc.next();
    //pesquisaRegiao(Regiao[] array,reg);

    System.out.println("\n\tCadastro realizado com sucesso!!!");

}


    //private static void pesquisaRegiao(Regiao[] array, String reg) {


    }
}
```

Comment: É só isto que deseja? `private static void pesquisaRegiao(Regiao[] array, String reg) {`. Ah, eu vi agora que está passando um variável que nem existe no método. O código está muito confuso, então não só para você, mas para todos que estão lendo está difícil fazer algo correto.

Comment: Então, eu achei que deveria criar as regioes antes, dai quando eu fosse criar as cidades as regioes ja existiriam. Não tem como passar esse array pra o metodo?

Comment: O código está completo? Estou vendo agora que parte da bagunça é porque faltam partes relevantes. Ou código é completamente sem sentido.

Comment: Tem mais só que nao da pra colocar no comentario.

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar nela.

Comment: Ta completa agora(a classe Main).

Comment: @bigown você deu rollback na ultima edição? Bem que tinha reparado que removeram partes do código nela, deliberadamente e tava achando que era o OP.

Comment: Sim, ela destruiu a edição do AP.

Comment: @willian.as A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está bastante confuso e precisaria fazer diversas alterações para resolver o problema. A primeira é acertar a assinatura do método que receberá as regiões, faltou colocar o tipo:

```
private static void pesquisaRegiao(Regiao[] regioes, String regiao) {
```

A outra alteração necessária é passar o *array* com as regiões para o método que precisa usá-lo:

```
public static void Cidade(Cidade cid, Regiao[] regioes) {
```

Aí chamaria assim:

```
Cidade(cid, regioes)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Parameter.java).

Teria que fazer o mesmo quando passa para o menu.

Você tem um método estático com o mesmo nome de uma classe? Não faça isso.

Procure evitar abreviações nos nomes das coisas, afeta a legibilidade e não traz benefícios reais.

Para o estilo do Java, o mais certo neste caso talvez seja jogar a variável `regioes` para a classe e acessá-las de todos os métodos onde ela seja necessária sem precisar ficar passando pelos métodos.

Eu pensei em escrever um exemplo de como fazer isto, mas para fazer certo teria que reescrever todo o código, o que eu acho que não é o objetivo. E não sei se seria uma boa, já que está com dificuldades no básico, começar estruturar o código em classes parece ser uma passo que ainda não está preparado para fazer.

Procure primeiro organizar o código em [métodos mais simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31473/101), que [só fazem uma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101), que se comunicam de forma mais clara. Lembre-se que o código não é algo mágico, é um texto que o computador deve entender, mas principalmente que um humano deve ler naturalmente. Antes de codificar é necessário entender o problema e encontrar a estrutura correta para representá-lo no código.

Uma dica: quando **precisa** colocar comentários significa que ali deveria estar em outro método. Tem comentários que simplesmente são desnecessários. [Comentários raramente são necessários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101) de fato e certamente não devem ser usados para o que foi neste código.

Vá arrumando uma coisa de cada vez. Alias, talvez seja melhor começar de novo fazendo uma coisa de cada vez. Pode ir perguntando aqui em cada passo que for dando, aí fica mais fácil ajudar. É muito difícil ajudar quando o código está profundamento mal estruturado. Sugiro fortemente seguir esta sugestão para obter ajuda qualificada. Em novas perguntas aqui descreva o problema e o que você começou fazer, um passo de cada vez. É importante fazer um [código limpo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33702/101) e [coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81337/101).

Comment: Realmente tenho que aprender muito ainda, programação não é muito minha área pois estudo Redes de Computadores e eu to apenas pagando a disciplina de POO. Mas quero agradecer muito sua ajuda, pois você resolveu o problema. E como você disse, vou tentar ajeitar esse código que tá bem confuso. Valeu.

Comment: Conseguiu fazer bastante coisa. Agora precisa aprender o que é mais difícil, fazer organizado :) É muito importante, não é frescura.