# O que torna um código fonte um código de fácil manutenção?

Tags: característica-linguagem, código-fonte

Durante o curso técnico que fiz, muitas vezes ouvi meus professores de programação (C# e JAVA) falando a importância de desenvolver um código de fácil manutenção,  mas o que em si determina que um código fonte é ou será de fácil manutenção?

No momento estou desenvolvendo um código de certa forma extenso e que futuramente poderá sofrer manutenções por outros desenvolvedores, por esse motivo surgiu essa preocupação/dúvida

Comment: Isto pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33726/101

Comment: A pergunta beliscou a amplitude também.

Comment: Só experiência faz a pessoa conseguir fazer algo fácil de dar manutenção. Não tem jeito. Pode existir algumas técnicas, mas quando aplicá-las é mais importante do que elas em si e isso demora pra aprender, tem que fazer muito, trabalhar com quem já faz bem feito (se não tem esse apoio, a internet tá aí pra ajudar em pontos específicos), mas não tem uma receita de bolo fácil.

Comment: Certo, obrigado pelo retorno. Essa é minha primeira pergunta considerada duplicata, preciso remover ela @bigown?

Comment: Não, pode ser útil para outras pessoas chegarem nela e depois ir para a pergunta onde tem resposta relevante.

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns fatores, como:

- facilidade de leitura
- comentário claro e objetivo
- sem gambiarras
- entre outros

Existem diversas metodologias de desenvolvimento que visam facilitar a manutenção e entregar outras vantagens, vai do gosto de cada um seguir uma metodologia, ou adaptar uma existente para sua própria, ou seguir a metodologia existente no seu local de trabalho.

Se você pesquisar "metodologia de desenvolvimento de software" irá encontrar vários artigos explicando cada uma.

Comment: Por que o voto negativo?