# Legibilidade de códigos javascript

Tags: javascript, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Ao escrever um código você deve fazê-lo de modo que o tempo necessário para sua compreensão seja mínimo. Essa é a métrica mais importante para se ter um código legível e é o fundamento do teorema fundamental da legibilidade.

Quanto maior o tempo gasto, menor é a legibilidade do seu código, e isso é um sinal de que ele precisa de melhorias a nível de legibilidade. Um código ilegível hoje, pode ser a sua perda de produtividade no futuro. O que você faz hoje, com total compreensão, daqui uns 2 anos quando precisar fazer uma manutenção, pode ser ilegível até para você mesmo, e isso fará com que você gaste um tempo precioso tentando entender aquilo que você mesmo escreveu.

> Então, quais seriam as formas interessantes de aplicar esse teorema e medir o nível de legibilidade do código?

**Não é desejável** que as respostas a esta pergunta sejam baseadas em opiniões mas sim em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.

Comment: devo entender que o voto negativo diz que não é necessário se preocupar com legibilidade, qualquer porcaria escrita de qualquer forma está bom, desde que funcione

Comment: Não fui eu que votei negativo, mas suponho que quem quer que seja tenha simplesmente entendido que a pergunta é ampla demais. De fato, "legibilidade" é um conceito nebuloso, e um bom estilo em uma linguagem pode ser um estilo ruim em outra. Aliás, pode variar de projeto para projeto. E a linha que separa "opiniões" de "experiência específica" é tênue...

Comment: Eu escrevi um artigo há algumas semanas para um blog onde descrevo algumas práticas para deixar um código autodocumentado. Segue o link: http://www.sigaonerd.com/2017/06/vba-artigo-034-deixando-o-codigo.html

Espero que o artigo ajude a responder sua questão. O melhor mesmo é ler o livro que coloquei como referência no final do artigo.

Comment: A pergunta vale para qualquer linguagem e a resposta vai ser a mesma. Agora, para evitar dar tiros no pé com Javascript, eu recomendo o livro *Javascript: the good parts*.

Comment: Relacionadas: [O que torna um código fonte um código de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186346/91) e [O que é “expressão idiomática” na programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/91)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe um livro que é algo como a Bíblia Sagrada sobre esse assunto. Eu já o tomei por verdade sacrossanta e enxergo qualquer desvio de seus ensinamentos como heresia.

Meu evangelho se chama **Código Limpo - Habilidades Práticas Do Agile Software**,
e foi escrito por São Roberto Martinho (do original em Inglês, Robert C. Martin). Seguem duas gravuras que são a codificação que recebemos da doutrina.

A métrica canônica para medida de bom código:

[image: WTF's por minuto]

E o caminho da verdade e da justiça para a escrita de bom código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todo o resto são só diferentes interpretações mais ou menos ortodoxas da verdade.

Answer (score 1):

Tive um pouco de dificuldade de entender a imagem postada pelo nosso amigo **Renan**. Depois de um bom tempo digitando cada trecho no Google Tradutor, me ocorreu a ideia de postar aqui a imagem com os trechos em português para facilitar o entendimento da mesma por parte da comunidade que não entende inglês assim como eu.

[image: Good Code]

The whole rest is different alone interpretations more or less orthodox of the truth   :)