# Métodos individuais ou parametros em consultas MySQL?

Tags: php

Em determinadas partes de meu sistema, ocorrem alguns filtros de de seleção, um exemplo, é ao selecionar a área de colaboradores do setor geral, posso selecionar:

Colaboradores (todos)
Colaboradores ativos (status = true)
Colaboradores inativos (status = false)

Posso fazer isso de duas formas.

Via parâmetro no método:

```
public static function get_collaborators(string $filter = 'all')
{
  if($filter == 'all'){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators';
  } elseif($filter == 'active'){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators WHERE status = 1';
  } elseif($filter == 'inactive'){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators WHERE status = 0';
  }        
  $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
  return $rs['data'];
}
```

Ou, 
Via métodos separados:

```
public static function get_all_collaborators()
{
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators';
  $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
  return $rs['data'];
}

public static function get_active_collaborators()
{
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators WHERE status = "1"';
  $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
  return $rs['data'];
}

public static function get_inactive_collaborators()
{
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators WHERE status = "0"';
  $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
  return $rs['data'];
}
```

Pelo que eu entendo, o primeiro modo (com parâmetros) teria menos desempenho por possuir verificações, logo, vários métodos separados seria melhor.

A dúvida é:

> Existe diferença na execução de um para outro ? (mesmo que irrisória)
>   Se sim, qual seria melhor ? Se não, qual segue o 'padrão correto' seguido pela maioria ?
>
> Se houver um outro modo, qual seria ?

Comment: Com certeza o melhor e usar um unico metodo que receba parametros, a diferenca de desempenho e imperceptivel entao o que acaba pesando mais e a questao da organizacao entao use apenas um metodo com parametros.

Comment: Ao utilizar PHP, não faz muito sentido se preocupar com questões ínfimas de desempenho, pois o PHP em si não foi concebido para ter desempenho. Neste caso, você deve optar pela forma que mantenha a semântica e atomicidade do seu código. Ao meu ver, sendo o objetivo das três consultas buscar uma lista de colaboradores, um método com parâmetros é o melhor a se fazer.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss disse tudo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu estou tentando ganhar um pouco de desempenho em praticamente todos os recursos mais básicos, pra ter uma margem um pouco maior em funções que consomem mais, pois estou com uma queda muito grande nas áreas operacionais com muitos dados, mas a diferença é tão mínima que o intervalo entre uma e outra chamada pode ser o desempenho da máquina, realmente, acho que não vai fazer muita diferença.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existe diferença na execução de um para outro?

Sim, mas depende de muitos fatores, pelo menos quando considerado o tempo de resposta. Se está tendo problemas com performance na sua aplicação. com certeza não é o `if` o problema. Devem existir outros gargalos de performance em outras partes do código ou o próprio banco de dados.

> Se sim, qual seria melhor?

Aquele que não fere a semântica e atomicidade do seu código, não necessariamente o mais rápido. Como eu comentei na pergunta, a própria linguagem PHP não foi concebida para ter grande performance, então é desnecessário se preocupar com detalhes tão pequenos assim.

Entre as duas maneiras apresentadas, julgo nenhuma delas ser a melhor, pois na primeira você repete a consulta SQL para cada condição - se está escrevendo 3 vezes a mesma coisa, tem coisa errada; já na segunda você teria três métodos exatamente com o mesmo objetivo (semântico), o que fere o princípio da atomicidade.

[O que são "unidades de código"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878)

[O que define um código limpo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33702/5878)

[O que torna um código fonte um código de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186346/5878)

[Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/5878)

[O que é codificação elegante?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173216/5878)

Particularmente acho que escrever apenas um método que retorna de acordo com o valor do parâmetro - essa é a função dele, não é? - faz muito mais sentido, deixa o código mais limpo e muito mais fácil de entender e dar manutenção.

```
public static function get_collaborators(string $filter = NULL)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_collaborators";

    if ($filter) {
        $status = ($filter == "active") ? 1 : 0;
        $sql .= " WHERE status = {$status}";
    }

    $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
    return $rs['data'];
}
```

Ainda, não sei em qual classe isso está sendo executado, mas considerando que há uma classe apenas para trabalhar com a tabela `data_collaborators`, poderia ser feito algo assim:

```
class Collaborators
{
    const INACTIVE = 0;
    const ACTIVE = 1;
    const ALL = 3;

    public static function get(int $filter = self::ALL)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_collaborators";

        if ($filter !== self::ALL)
        {
            $sql .= " WHERE status = " . $filter;
        }

        $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
        return $rs['data'];
    }
}
```

Assim, você poderia utilizar:

- `Collaborators::get()`, ou `Collaborators::get(Collaborators::ALL)` para todos os colaboradores;
- `Collaborators::get(Collaborators::ACTIVE)` para todos os colaboradores ativos; e
- `Collaborators::get(Collaborators::INACTIVE)` para todos os colaboradores inativos.

Ou, inclusive, definir métodos auxiliares:

```
public static function actives()
{
    return self::get(self::ACTIVE);
}

public static function inactives()
{
    return self::get(self::INACTIVE);
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/yYDtoV).

E assim utilizar `Collaborators::actives()` e `Collaborators::inactives()` para obter os colaboradores ativos e inativo, respectivamente. Perceba que, diferente da sua implementação, isso não fere o princípio da atomicidade, pois toda a responsabilidade está concentrada no método `get`; os outros dois métodos não possuem responsabilidade e existem apenas como um *sugar-syntax*.

Answer (score 4):

Nesse caso, criar três métodos fragmenta sua lógica sem necessidade então deixar a lógica em um lugar só parece a melhor alternativa. Pode trocar esse if por array pois está basicamente escolhendo uma consulta.

```
public static function get_collaborators(string $filter = 'all'){
    $baseQuery = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators ';
    $queries = array('all' => $baseQuery, 'active' => $baseQuery .'WHERE status = 1' , 'inactive' => $baseQuery .'WHERE status = 1');
    $sql = isset($queries[$filter]) ? $queries[$filter] : $baseQuery;
    $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string();
    return $rs['data'];
}
```

Comment: Nem passou pela minha cabeça essa forma, mesmo sem ser a mais atraente visualmente, mina a necessidade de ifs e de se ter mais de um método, perfeito.

Answer (score 2):

Isso não é uma resposta simplória, mas em termos de performance o ganho é irrisório.

Não existe uma receita de bolo, mas você pode usar uma função apenas e usar um filtro com a clausula in ().

Segue um exemplo retirado do [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php)

```
$ids    = array(0,1);
$params = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($ids), "?"));
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM data_collaborators WHERE status IN ($params)";
$stmt   = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bindparams'), $ids);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

No caso tu pode mudar o parametro para nao precisar fazer aquelas verficacoes com o if ao inves de filter use status como parametro:

```
public static function get_collaborators($status = null)
{

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_collaborators'.$status?' WHERE status = '.$status:null;     

    $rs = \MySQL\MySQLSelector::select_by_query_string($sql);
    return $rs['data'];
}
```

Comment: Um operador ternário dentro de uma *string*? Tem certeza que isso funciona?

Comment: absoluta. Perceba que esta dentro de chaves. Dentro de chaves voce pode colocar qualquer expressao que ele vai retornar o resultado daquilo para a string.

Comment: Não se é uma boa ideia fazer deste modo, vou testar aqui, mas achei meio estranha essa query, acho que tem alguma coisa errada.

Comment: Corrigido, mas com chaves funciona tambem.

Comment: Mas para isso a *string* precisa ser definida com aspas duplas. O PHP não analisa o conteúdo de *string* com aspas simples. E eu fiz um teste e não funcionou executar o operador dentro da *string* (https://ideone.com/fnCrCE).

Comment: Realmente, não vou usar exatamente isso, mas essa me deu uma solução com um único método sem precisar de ifs, acredito que é a melhor opção, usar o parametro direto como argumento de status.

Comment: e que faz um tempo que larguei o php, entao nao me lembro muito bem como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, há diferença na execução por mais mínima que possa ser. Isso acontece pelo motivo que ao **`get_collaborators()` ser executada, terá 3 avaliações diferentes a serem executadas: `if`, `elseif` e mais um `elseif`.**

Em suma:
*Se o filtro for para todos... Faça...*
*Se o filtro não for para todos e for para ativo faça...*
*Se o filtro não for para todos e não for para todos mas for para inativo... Faça...*

E um outro "empaca-desempenho" é que você está realizando uma consulta `SELECT *`, qual sempre é um problema. Mesmo que você queira selecionar todas as colunas, coloque especificamente o nome delas na sua *query*.

### Sobre o comentário do **mito do `SELECT *`**..

Já está mais comprovado que a `sintaxe *` pode ser mais lenta pelas seguintes razões:

- Nem todos os campos são indexados e a consulta usa varredura de tabela completa.
- Retornar campos de saída de uma tabela que contém colunas de comprimento variável pode resultar em uma pequena sobrecarga de pesquisa: para retornar o campo 20, o 19 anterior deve ser examinado e os valores compensados são calculados.
- Apenas mais dados precisam ser devolvidos (passado pela conexão).
  Como você precisa de quase todos os campos, o último motivo é provavelmente o mais importante. Digamos que o campo TEXT da descrição pode ser apenas 1 dos 50 campos não utilizados na página, mas pode ocupar 10 vezes mais espaço que todos os outros campos em conjunto.

---

**tl;dr**

Execute funções separadas e não utilize `SELECT *`.

Comment: O _select *_ é um mito que já não é mais verdadeiro faz um tempo.

Comment: Nesse caso especifico eu preciso de todos os dados, por isso o '*' no select, e geralmente também é feito com PDO as consultas, somente nesse caso e outros poucos é via string pois foram as primeiras coisas feitas antes de estruturar bem o projeto, a minha dúvida é na questão da chamada dos métodos mesmo.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR Leia minha nova edição. Novamente... Não utilize `SELECT *`. Não é e nunca será uma boa prática.

Comment: E sobre a chamada dos métodos... Foi exatamente o que eu respondi. Não há nenhum sentido minha resposta ter sido negativada.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing não foi essa minha pergunta, eu perguntei acerca da chamada dos métodos, não da seleção, obs: não foi eu quem negativou.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR Você realmente leu a minha resposta? `Sim, há diferença na execução por mais mínima que possa ser. Isso acontece pelo motivo que ao get_collaborators() ser executada, terá 3 avaliações diferentes a serem executadas: if, elseif e mais um elseif.`. Qual responde de forma clara e objetiva a sua pergunta `Existe diferença na execução de um para outro ? (mesmo que irrisória) Se sim, qual seria melhor ? Se não, qual segue o 'padrão correto' seguido pela maioria ?`

Comment: Essa resposta eu entendi, mas acabei pensando em outra coisa que talvez renda mais pois não haveria verificação, e os métodos seriam mais curtos, será que haveria diferença se usar de métodos cadenciados ? : EX: filterAll()->get_collaborators_data(), ou filterActive()->get_colalborators_data(), e construir as consultas com base na primeira chamada.

Comment: Haveria a diferença de código desnecessário. Mantenha sua ideia de `métodos separados`.

Comment: Se lhe ajudei, sanei a dúvida baseada na pergunta explícita na *quote* que você escreveu... Aceite a resposta como correta.

Comment: Eu acho que o foco não é o select *, uma vez que sua afirmação carece de fontes. Isso é, e sempre foi, um argumento passado que nunca foi devidamente comprovado, as pessoas apenas falavam e pronto. Hoje todos os SGBDs de mercado são otimizados o suficiente para isso.

Agora se você tiver uma fonte que comprove o que está dizendo, por favor.

Comment: [Veja aqui](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/09/select-all-columns-to-be-good-or-bad-in-database-system/), ou [aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234657/why-is-select-from-table-considered-bad-practice), ou se estiver interessado em ler  *um livro sobre alta performance no MySQL, etc*, [acesse](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=select+all+is+a+bad+mysql&source=bl&ots=CQPMzwqA1O&sig=oIALE3ZD72s4VGa1iRzJtAG2m3A&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiujojSx_LVAhUEaRQKHTb4BR8Q6AEIcjAJ)

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-08/its-not-about-the-star-stupid

Comment: Esse é o único site, em 4 páginas do Google onde diz que é um mito. Encerrando essa discussão sem necessidade por aqui. Passar bem.