# Qual a diferença entre SELECT * E SELECT campo1,...?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Se eu preciso de todos campos da tabela, tem diferença de performance entre usar o coringa "*" (`SELECT * FROM ...`) e especificar todos os campos da tabela (`SELECT campo1, campo2... FROM ...`)?

Além de performance, qual é a boa prática?

Comment: A resposta já esta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232219/m%C3%A9todos-individuais-ou-parametros-em-consultas-mysql

Comment: @DiegoMarques Verifique a minha resposta no link que o 13dev postou. Ela trata exatamente disso.

Comment: A minha dúvida se restringe exatamente na situação da necessidade de trazer todos os campos da tabela, pelo que entendi nesta resposta, é para quando vou precisar de apenas alguns campos, então especifico eles.

Comment: [Por que usar “SELECT * FROM tabela” é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/91)

Comment: esta que o @rray mencionou abrange tudo que necessitas

Comment: depende também de como sua aplicação trata "todos os campos" , se for de forma automática pode-se usar o * mas se tiver de ter alguma manutenção caso algum novo campo seja criar melhor listar os campos