# Foreach ou lambda em listas

Tags: c#, .net, linq, desempenho, expressões-lambda

Qual eu obtenho a melhor performance para pegar o valor de um dado em uma lista? Faço `foreach` ou lambda(quando for possível, é claro)? Posso ter isso:

```
foreach(var i in lista)
{
  var teste = i.NmCampo;
}
```

Ou isso:

```
var teste = lista.Select(campo => campo.NmCampo).FirstOrDefault(c => c == "MeuNome");
```

Que caminho eu seguiria nesse caso. Claro que passei um exemplo com uma linha apenas, mas eu tenho casos aqui de vários `ifs` dentro do `foreach` e isso eu estou trocando por *lambda*.

Comment: Atenção que a variável `teste` tem valores diferentes em cada um dos casos. No primeiro, a variável `teste` vai ficar com o valor `NmCampo` em cada iteração do `foreach`. No segundo caso `teste` fica com o valor da primeira linha que devolver resultados (por exemplo, em 100 linhas de resultados, a variável vai ficar apenas com o valor da 1ª linha)

Comment: @CesarMiguel, isso acontece devido ao FirstOrDefaul, mas posso suprimir caso necessito obter uma coleção. O exemplo é hipotético apenas para ilustrar o que tem a melhor performance. Claro que cada situação deverá ser estudada criteriosamente.

Comment: certo. Só achei estranho dois exemplos que faziam coisas diferentes :P Qual tem melhor performance? Não tenho a certeza, mas penso lamba. Mas não tenho fundamentos para provar isso

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste tópico http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044236/nested-foreach-vs-lambda-linq-query-performancelinq-to-objects creio que será útil

Comment: @CesarMiguel Se tiver que varrer tudo o `foreach` sempre é mais rápido. A performance depende do algoritmo interno e conjunto de dados. Se a expressão LINQ tivesse só o `Select` ela certamente seria mais lenta.

Comment: Pelo link do Renilson e agora pelo bigown, realmente a performance com Foreach na maioria dos casos é melhor, claro que pode haver situações onde o emprego do LINQ seria conveniente, mas a varredura com foreach parece apresentar melhor desempenho.

Comment: @pnet coloquei um teste real para mostrar a diferença

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@pnet, `LINQ` tende a ser mais lento que um loop convencional, pelo simples motivo que o linq adiciona um overhead ao seu codigo. Este overhead é basicamente a conversão do seu `LINQ` em um loop tradicional.

Mesmo se tratando de um loop convencional, ainda temos diferença de desempenho entre o `for` e o `foreach`, o `for` pode ser até 2x mais rapido que o `foreach`.

Por fim ainda podemos analizar o elemento que será percorrido, o `for` pode ser até 2x mais rapido ao percorrer um `Array` do que uma `List<T>`. No final das contas um `for` com `Array`, pode ser até 4x ou 5x mais rapido que um `foreach` com `List<T>`.

Mas lembre-se que tudo é uma questão do preço que está disposto a pagar, um `foreach` é uma estrutura bem mais elegante que um `for`, tornando explicito a intenção de percorrer aquele objeto. Além de que um List adiciona uma serie de facilidades, tais como busca e manipulação.

Agora voltando ao `LINQ`, este apesar de ser mais lento que o `for`/`foreach`, ele é mais legível que o loop.

Então o bloco abaixo será mais rapido que o seu equivalente em `LINQ`

```
var teste = default(String);
for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{
    if (lista[i].NmCampo == "MeuNome")
    {
        teste = lista[i].NmCampo;
        break;
    }
}
```

porém o `LINQ` é bem mais legivel:

```
var teste = lista.Select(campo => campo.NmCampo).FirstOrDefault(c => c == "MeuNome");
```

Via de regra, eu costumo trocar um pouco de desempenho por legibilidade do código.

Answer (score 17):

A única forma de saber ao certo é testando e isso pode mudar de acordo com o conjunto de dados e do algoritmo a ser executado em cada item.

Primeiro vamos notar que os dois algoritmos mostrados não são equivalentes. Um pega um dado incondicionalmente e o outro pega condicionalmente. Quando você comprar coisas que fazem tarefas diferentes não dá para escolher o que faz mais rápido, tem que escolher o que faz o que você quer que faça na situação.

Então vamos comparar coisas iguais, entre:

```
foreach(var i in lista) {
    if (i.NmCampo == "MeuNome") { 
        var teste = i.NmCampo;
        break;
    }
}

var teste = lista.Select(campo => campo.NmCampo).FirstOrDefault(c => c == "MeuNome");
```

A primeira é claramente mais rápida porque tem menos abstração, menos indireção, menos código real para ser executado.

A segunda forma pode ser útil mas ela é mais complicada internamente. Se ela deve ser usada assim mesmo é uma questão de gosto. Algumas pessoas só escolheriam a primeira se realmente a performance fizer a diferença, e outras só escolheriam o LINQ se ele se mostrar algo mais vantajoso.

Mas a primeira fica grande demais, tem uma lógica mais complicada. Pode ser que por legibilidade seja melhor escolher a segunda. Mas ainda é questão de gosto. Eu já falei sobre o assunto em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101).

Outro ponto importante a se notar é que é fácil a pessoa esquecer que o `break` deve estar ali dentro do `if` para encerrá-lo quando achar o que quer e se comportar exatamente como no `FirstOrDefault` e aí a execução do `foreach` seria mais lenta na maioria dos caso porque teria que varrer toda a lista e com a expressão LINQ. Mas de novo, o algoritmo seria outro. É importante salientar que nem todo mundo domino todo comportamento dos métodos disponíveis para uso com LINQ e todas suas implicações. Nem sempre esconder uma lógica é uma boa ideia. Pode dificultar o entendimento de quem está usado aquilo se ela não conhece bem o que está escrito ali. Códigos explícitos podem ser melhores para quem não conhece as abstrações existentes.

Eu fiz um teste para ver a diferença, não adianta falar em teorias de performance porque elas podem se mostrar falsas na prática ou podem ser parcialmente verdadeiras. No mínimo elas não fornecem informações suficientes para tomar uma decisão consciente:

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/t7JsDn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EScTKC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/ForEachXLambda.cs). Um dos resultados:

> ```
> Resultado do for: MeuNome
> 17497
> Resultado do foreach: MeuNome
> 16669
> Resultado do LINQ: MeuNome
> 57009
> Agora acha no primeiro
> Resultado do for: MeuNome
> 12
> Resultado do foreach: MeuNome
> 3
> Resultado do LINQ: MeuNome
> 6599
> ```

Podemos ver que o `for` e o `foreach` são quase equivalente e não é possível ver diferença expressiva. E ao contrário da crença popular, o `foreach` pode ser mais rápido que o `for` em algumas situações (em alguns testes que eu rodei ele foi mais rápido apesar de diferença irrisória). Notamos também que o LINQ é bem mais lento. Não é uma diferença trivial. Se quer performance mesmo, se ela é necessária, fuja do LINQ.

Quando uma expressão LINQ será usada ela deve ser compilada e isto toma muito tempo, por isso para achar o primeiro elemento na lista é brutalmente (em média 1000 vezes) mais lento que fazer um laço com um filtro dentro. Claro que ter 7000 *ticks* é nada mas numericamente falando a diferença é enorme.

Claro que isto depende da situação como já disse antes e precisa analisar se vai fazer diferença real.

Comment: realmente eu havia me baseado em uma informação que tinha por volta de 2008~2010, muita coisa mudou desde de então.
Acabei de refazer o Micro-benchmark encontrado em: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/, e a diferença entre o `for` e `foreach` hoje é bem pequena. 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAKnL4

Comment: Por isso que comparação de performance é complicada. O que vale num dia não vale no outro. Mas é parecido neste caso, pode não ser em outros casos, testes de performance só valem para o caso específico. Há uma quantidade imensa de fatores que podem afetar a performance para cima ou para baixo e maioria não são controláveis ou facilmente perceptíveis pelo programador. Mas mesmo com essa informação errada, você conseguiu a aceitação e mais votos, eu não entendo esse pessoal :)

Comment: acredito que seja um fenomeno semelhante ao encontrado no mercado de smartphones, o lider não é aquele que tem o melhor produto e sim aquele que apresentou alguma coisa primeira. vide Samsung e a sua linha Galaxy e Motorola e a linha Moto (G).