# Var dentro do FOR quando começa em 0(zero) o Count deve ser Count-1?

Tags: c#, .net, for

Peguei um sistema na empresa em que trabalho de outro colega. Observo que o todos os FOR's são assim:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lista.count; i++)
{
  //meu código
}
```

Aprendi que quando uma variável dentro do FOR inicia com zero, meu `COUNT` deve ser sempre `Count - 1`, a menos que haja uma regra específica para isso ocorrer. Estou certo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, você está certo, é matemática básica. Se você tem 10 elementos, e começa contar vai do 0 ao 9: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

O `Count` diz quantos elementos tem na lista. Então deve contar até o elemento anterior à contagem usando `Count - 1`.

A não ser que tenha algum motivo para usar de forma diferente mas geralmente não tem porque e mesmo que tenha, teria que ser uma valor menor ainda. Certamente se tentar acessar um elemento de número **igual** à contagem vai gerar uma exceção.

Note o destaque do "igual" ali em cima. Isto vale se você estiver usando o operador de comparação `<=`.

No seu exemplo está usando o `<`, então não tem necessidade de fazer o `-1`. Por que ele já vai parar um elemento antes de chegar ao fim.

Veja este código demonstrado a diferença:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) lista.Add(i);
        for (var i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++) WriteLine(lista[i]);
        for (var i = 0; i <= lista.Count - 1; i++) WriteLine(lista[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MApRBD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xMImtJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/ForCount.cs).

Quando você usa o `<=` um elemento a mais é pego por causa do igual. O `<` pega todos que forem menor, mas o `<=` pega todos que forem menor mais o elemento que é igual.

Em geral eu prefiro o primeiro, tem uma operação matemática a menos para fazer. Não que isto signifique necessariamente que é mais rápido, só que é mais simples. Como demonstrei [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53857/101), o que todo mundo espera pode ser falso e só testando para afirmar qual é mais rápido. **Pode** ser que fazer um "menor ou igual" seja mais lento que fazer um "menor" e uma "subtração".

Outro detalhe que pode ser apenas um erro de digitação é que a propriedade que mostra o número de elementos da lista é `Count`. Não é `COUNT` e não é `count`.

Certamente eu **usaria um `foreach` neste caso** e não me preocuparia com isto. Já demonstrei na resposta *linkada* acima que ele é igual ou melhor que o `for` em performance e é mais simples. Além de ser semanticamente mais correto. O `for` acima está dizendo para pegar todos os elementos, que é exatamente o motivo para o `foreach` existir. E ele garante que tudo estará correto no processo. Ele é mais simples em todos os sentidos. O `for` só seria útil se é importante você ter um número índice do elemento na lista.