# Qual melhor forma de inserir um array no banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de inserir um array em uma tabela do banco de dados. Poderia utilizar um foreach mas gostaria de algo performático pois trabalharei com grande número de dados.

```
    foreach (var item in registros)
        {
            string CPF = String.Empty;
            string nome = String.Empty;
            string apto = String.Empty;

            CPF = item.Split('|')[0];
            nome = item.Split('|')[1];
            apto = item.Split('|')[2];
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DATABASE.DBO.TABLE (CPF, NOME, APTO) VALUES (" + CPF + "," + nome + "," + apto + ")");
        }
```

Comment: Depende. Como está o banco de dados? Como os dados devem ser gravados? Mas já posso adiantar que não existe comando mágicos de que tornam operações enormes e coisas rápidas.

Comment: Será uma tabela com três colunas simples (CPF, NOME, STATUS). Gostaria da forma mais performática, acredito que não seja o foreach.

Comment: Só com estas informações fica muito difícil te ajudar. Mas já posso te dizer que se você não está fazendo da forma mais rápida, está fazendo tão rápida quanto possível. Ou seja, a diferença se usar um `for` simples será mínima (eu acho até que será pior). Reforço que não existe solução mágica. Se você mostrasse porque precisa de mais performance, o contexto geral, talvez até pudesse sugerir algo diferente mas só com estas informações, só posso dizer que é isto ou o `for` simples, teste ambos e veja qual é mais rápido. Provavelmente o ganho não valerá o esforço.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53857/101 olha como não faz muita diferença e que o `foreach` pode até ser o mais rápido.

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido. Necessitava salvar na faixa de 100 mil registros em meu BD. Utilizando a forma que você demonstrou, estava demorando cerca de 5 minutos. Daí, ao invés de salvar direto, eu utilizei o foreach para salvar os dados em uma lista, e utilizei o BulkInsert, para inserir os dados. A tarefa mudou de 5 minutos para cerca de 15 segundos. Caso precise, avise que elaboro uma resposta mais tarde.

Comment: @Randrade exatamente, se ele fornecer mais informações de todo o processo dá para achar outra soluções, só com este trecho não dá para ajudar muito. O laço será necessário para montar os dados mas ele não precisa ser usado para gravar os dados.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates, muito importante: não concatene os valores da consulta desta maneira, você fica vulnerável a SQL Injection! Use *parametrized queries*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JeanGustavoPrates, você pode realizar a inserção somente depois de montar todos os INSERTs com `SqlBulkCopy` ou da maneira abaixo:

```
string stmt = "INSERT INTO DATABASE.DBO.TABLE (CPF, NOME, APTO) VALUES (@cpf, @nome, @apto)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, _connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@cpf", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nome", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@apto", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < registros.count i++)
{
    var item = registros[i];
    string CPF = item.Split('|')[0];
    string nome = item.Split('|')[1];
    string apto = item.Split('|')[2];
    cmd.Parameters["@cpf"].Value = CPF;
    cmd.Parameters["@nome"].Value = nome;
    cmd.Parameters["@apto"].Value = apto;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Mas, de qualquer forma, acredito que do `for` para recuperar as informações de CPF, nome e apto você não vai conseguir fugir.

**Muito importante**: não concatene os valores da consulta desta maneira, você fica vulnerável a SQL Injection! Use *parametrized queries*, como demonstrei acima.

Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218932/2387977

Answer (score 2):

O que está a tentar fazer é um "bulk insert", ou seja, um insert com um largo número de linhas de uma só vez. À partida, a melhor forma de o fazer, seria mesmo com um `BULK INSERT`, mas também pode ir pelo método mais simples e fazer uma instrução `INSERT`. Esta instrução será construída dentro do `for` e executada uma vez apenas, após o mesmo. Pegando no seu código:

```
string CPF = String.Empty;
string nome = String.Empty;
string apto = String.Empty;
string valuesString = String.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i < registros.count; i++) { 
    var item = registros[i];
    CPF = item.Split('|')[0];
    nome = item.Split('|')[1];
    apto = item.Split('|')[2];
    values += "(" + CPF + "," + nome + "," + apto + ")";
    if (i < registros.count-1) 
       values += ",";
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(valuesString)) {
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DATABASE.DBO.TABLE (CPF, NOME, APTO) VALUES " + valuesString;
    ...
}
```