# Forma mais rápida de acessar propriedades em uma lista C#

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, lista, loop

Tenho um projeto que trabalha com um grande volume de dados, e preciso otimiza-lo para trazer resultados de alguns cálculos em um tempo consideravelmente pequeno. Sei que tenho diversos aspectos para levar em consideração, como a estrutura em que os dados foram salvos no Banco de Dados, a forma como estou realizando o acesso a eles, como estou realizando os cálculos entre outros, mas desconsiderando todos estes itens, gostaria que fosse levado em consideração apenas a questão colocada abaixo.

Minha dúvida é mais conceitual que um problema em meu código. Mas algo específico...

Considere a seguinte lista:

```
var minhaLista = new List<MeuObjeto>
{
   // Objetos...
};
```

`meuObjeto` possui as seguintes propriedades:

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
  public int Prop1 {get; set;}
  public string Prop2 {get; set;}
  public decimal Prop3 {get; set;}
  public bool Prop4 {get; set;}
}
```

Preciso acessar cada uma das propriedades em um laço de repetição com `n` itens da forma mais rápida possível e econômica em relação a memória. Mas se tiver de escolher entre velocidade e memória, devo escolher velocidade.

Cada milissegundo é muito importante, por isso estou levando em consideração alguns aspectos como o `for` ser mais rápido que o `foreach`, ou ainda declarar uma constante com `0` e usa-la para instanciar a variável de controle do laço ser melhor que instanciar diretamente com `0`.

Por isso, considere `INICIO` da seguinte forma:

```
private const int INICIO = 0;
```

Considere `OutroObjeto` como um objeto semelhante a `MeuObjeto` apenas para exemplo.

**Forma 1:**

```
var outraLista = new List<OutroObjeto>();

for (int i = INICIO; i < minhaLista.Count; i++)
{
   var outroObjeto = new OutroObjeto
   {
      Prop1 = minhaLista[i].Prop1,
      Prop2 = minhaLista[i].Prop2,
      Prop3 = minhaLista[i].Prop3,
      Prop4 = minhaLista[i].Prop4
   };
   outraLista.Add(outroObjeto );
}
```

> Neste caso, **para cada propriedade** é feita uma busca na lista pelo
>   objeto na posição `i`?

**Forma 2:**

```
var outraLista = new List<OutroObjeto>();

for (int i = INICIO; i < minhaLista.Count; i++)
{
   var meuObjetoI = minhaLista[i];

   var outroObjeto = new OutroObjeto
   {
      Prop1 = meuObjetoI.Prop1,
      Prop2 = meuObjetoI.Prop2,
      Prop3 = meuObjetoI.Prop3,
      Prop4 = meuObjetoI.Prop4
   };
   outraLista.Add(outroObjeto );
}
```

> Aparentemente este trecho trabalha de forma semelhante ao `foreach`,
>   mas o acesso a **cada propriedade** do objeto na posição `i` da lista
>   será mais rápido que na **Forma 1**?
>
> Tecnicamente `meuObjetoI` apenas aponta para o objeto da lista na
>   posição `i` que já está alocado na memória, correto?

> Qual seria a forma mais indicada levando em consideração o tempo e o
>   consumo de memória?
>  Ou existe uma terceira opção que seja melhor?

Comment: Como você está obtendo a `minhaLista` ?

Comment: @Randrade muito obrigado pelo interesse em ajudar, mas gostaria que considerasse `minhaLista` como uma lista comum de `n` `MeuObjeto`, e levasse em consideração apenas o acesso a eles nas formas apresentadas. Isso é possível ou você realmente precisa muito desse detalhe para formular uma resposta?

Comment: É que geralmente a melhor forma de fazer isso poderia ser na origem, onde você está obtendo os dados originalmente.

Comment: Jovem, [instale isso](http://miniprofiler.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Pré-compute o que for possível

Zero é uma constante, então não precisa se preocupar com ela. Mas `.Count` será reavaliado em cada interação, caso o compilador não consiga "provar" que `minhaLista` é uma  variável estritamente local. Como não há considerações sobre isso, então então primeira otimização é usar `for` para diminuir pressão sobre o *garbage collector*, e pré-computar `.Count`:

```
var count = minhaLista.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Essa otimização assume que a lista tem tamanho constante.

#### Diminuir as indireções 1

Como comentado, cada indireção a resolver é um processamento a mais, pelo menos *em teoria*. Isso pode ser uma otimização burra, mas novamente, se `minhaLista` não for estritamente local, dentro do `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    var item = minhaLista[ i ];
    var outroObjeto = new OutroObjeto
    {
        Prop1 = item.Prop1,
        Prop2 = item.Prop2,
        Prop3 = item.Prop3,
        Prop4 = item.Prop4
    };
    outraLista.Add(outroObjeto );
}
```

Isso corta os repetidos acessos tipo `minhaLista[i].Obj`.

#### Diminuindo indireções 2

Propriedades simples, ou propriedades com ascensores simples (`{get;set;}`) tem código extremamente otimizado, então o código acima, embora pareça verborrágico, talvez já seja o mais rápido possível. No entanto uma cópia assim talvez viole o princípio do [DRY](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), então criar um construtor de `OutroObjeto` que aceite `MeuObjeto` é interessante pois:

1. Melhora a expressividade do seu código
2. Diminui a indireção, pois metade das propriedades serão acessos locais de um dos objetos.

Uma alternativa é pendurar um método `.ToOutro()` em `MeuObjeto`, fazendo algo parecido ao conteúdo do `for`, acima.

```
var minhaLista = new List<MeuObjeto>();
...

var outraLista = new List<OutroObjeto>();
var count = minhaLista.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    outraLista.Add( minhaLista[ i ].ToOutro() );
}
```

Depende um tanto do gosto pessoal. Se achar preferível um `.To` da vida mas feio misturar domínios da aplicação, um método de extensão é o caminho de ter um código que liga os objetos, sem *estar* em nenhum dos objetos.

#### Readonly collection

O maquinário de [List<>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) é complicado. Tem de ser. Mas tentar substituir essa funcionalidade por uma implementação caseira não tem lá o melhor dos prognósticos. No entanto "tudo" o que o seu código acima faz é copiar uma lista de objetos em outra. Dai a pergunta, nova lista **tem** de ser dinâmica?

Se a resposta for na negativa, especificamente se a nova lista criada não é depois modificada em termos de *quantidade de registros*, então:

```
var minhaLista = new List<MeuObjeto>();
...
var count = minhaLista.Count;
var outraLista = new OutroObjeto[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    outraLista[ i ] = minhaLista[ i ].ToOutro();
```

#### Readonly object

Essa é uma proposta radical, mas que é de fato utilizada em lugares onde a performance é absolutamente prioritária: objetos somente leitura, e se forem pequenos o suficiente, structs em vez de objetos.

Não é uma transição que deve ser feita sem muito estudo. Sair de classes mutantes para struct é difícil, e propenso a erros. Se esses objetos vem de banco de dados, daí a sugestão é de *não* ir por esse caminho.

Mas se esses objetos forem de alguma forma dados efêmeros, carregados para serem descartados ou produtos de cálculos, utilizar classes/structs somente leitura te dá a *garantia* que esses dados não serão alterados em hipótese nenhuma, que talvez evite esse tipo de conversão, e abre algumas otimizações em nível de compilador, que podem acelerar bem a execução do código.

Answer (score 4):

> Neste caso, para cada propriedade é feita uma busca na lista pelo objeto na posição i?

Busca não é exatamente a palavra, acho que ela implica em um processamento longo. É feito um acesso direto ao elemento de acordo com o índice. É um acesso a um ponto da memória como qualquer variável.

Essencialmente não faz diferença se está acessando a variável como um elemento ou como um objeto todo. Se no final terá que acessar todos elementos isto pouco muda. Claro que depende do que vai fazer, o que pode ser melhor em um contexto pode ser pior em outro.

Eu não arriscaria dizer com toda certeza qual seria mais rápido sem testar em condições apropriadas, o que nem sempre sabemos fazer. Ainda assim o resultado do teste em operação simples pode ser irrelevante dentro de outro contexto. Já vi diversas vezes a pessoa testar em condições controladas para obter o resultado mais preciso e depois quando usa em produção acontece outra coisa.

> Aparentemente este trecho trabalha de forma semelhante ao `foreach`, mas o acesso a cada propriedade do objeto na posição i da lista será mais rápido que na Forma 1?

Não tem nada parecido com o `foreach`. O `foreach` trabalha com um objeto enumerador, acessa outros métodos, tem mais dificuldade de otimização e principalmente tem uma proposta bem diferente da apresentada.

> Tecnicamente `meuObjetoI` apenas aponta para o objeto da lista na posição i que já está alocado na memória, correto?

Correto, neste caso. Você receberá o valor armazenado no elemento da lista. Como é um objeto [por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101), receberá a referência (ou [ponteiro se preferir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)) para o objeto e não o objeto em si. Se o tipo fosse por valor receberia ele.

> Qual seria a forma mais indicada levando em consideração o tempo e o consumo de memória? Ou existe uma terceira opção que seja melhor?

Não vejo motivos para a segunda forma. ela é pior. Tenho sérias dúvidas se realmente precisa fazer isto. O que posso dizer é que sem contexto tudo pode ser certo ou errado. Eu acho que dá pra fazer melhor, mas depende do contexto.

## Conclusão

No geral eu não sei se cada milissegundo é tão importante assim. Principalmente sem contexto. Vejo pessoas muito experientes fazer tudo errado tentando otimizar. Otimizar certo é mais difícil do que parece.

Não acho que seja o caso mas muitas vezes escolher não se preocupar com a memória é escolher ter pior velocidade. Pra ver como é complexo.

Não sei se é tão verdade que o `foreach` é mais lento que o `for`. Eu [já mostrei aqui no SOpt que não é bem assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53857/101). Este é um dos motivos que as pessoas erram tentando otimizar, acreditam em verdades falsas.

Espero que esta resposta sirva mais até para desmistificar a ideia da otimização do que até responder o caso específico que nem parece ser relevante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: espetacular resposta! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

As duas formas crescem linearmente com o tamanho da sua lista, então a diferença é pequena.

Mas a segunda forma é um pouco pior em questão de performance e memória porque apesar de ser apenas um ponteiro, você precisa alocar o endereço e memória pra ele apontar para o objeto da minhaLista[i] todas as vezes e este é um passo extra e desnecessário.

Como perguntou de outra forma, você poderia passar para o construtor do OutroObjeto e deixar ele tratar internamente as propriedades necessárias, sem precisar alocar variáveis temporárias, já que você adiciona a referência na sua outraLista.

**Forma 3:**

```
for (int i = INICIO; i < minhaLista.Count; i++)
{
    outraLista.Add(new OutroObjeto(minhaLista[i]));
}
```

Comment: Ótima resposta @Rodrigo-Guiotti e também muito obrigado pela proposta da **Forma 3**. Me ajudou muito e com certeza irei implementar! Gostaria apenas de pedir, se for possível para você, abordar um pouco mais sobre as dúvidas destacadas na pergunta...